# Minor improvements to accessibility of info regarding code formatting

Tags: feature-request, editor, editing-help

Questions seeking help for formatting code blocks, like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251356/ugly-formatting-and-bad-webdesign-make-me-reconsider-stack-exchange) (poor approach, granted), have popped up before and are likely to come up again.

It's easy enough to hover over the tool buttons in the editor to get the tool tips, or just politely ask first. However, I think there are a couple of improvements that could be made here. This post is a double request.

First:  <strike>The post [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/) was moved to MSE in the split. However, it's a reasonable question for a new user to ask on MSO, given that SO is a code-related site (Programmers and Code Review as well). Because it was moved, it is difficult to find when travelling from SO to the nearest meta (MSO). For example, here are the new MSO search results for ["indent code"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=indent%20code). Very sparse indeed.</strike>

To that end, I'd like to see that question moved back here, or somehow linked here. What I'd really like to do is post a canonical question here on MSO and have it marked as a duplicate, but of course, there are no cross-site duplicates. Not sure what the best approach here is, but that information really does need to be present on MSO.

Update: I have duplicate the FAQ as a proposed one [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) (see comments below).

Second: Neither the `?` quick help button on the editor, nor the [advanced help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section describe the tool bar button or the use of Ctrl+K. For some users, it's not immediately obvious what to do here, and the help is a bit lacking. I propose adding this information to both of these areas. In fact, I'd simply like to see the entire first section of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/230261) be placed directly into both the quick help and expanded advanced help section.

I think these two things will make it very straightforward for users to find this information, and prevent rants like the first one I linked to above as well.

Comment: I think we lost editor-related tags in the split.

Comment: FAQs like the 'how to format' post can simply be *recreated* here; they have a place on both MSE and here. I did the same for the orphan tags FAQ page, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I could duplicate that question and answer here; I'll do it right now if there are no objections.

Comment: Follow the [proposed FAQ procedure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow); flag it for CW ication

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Our [tag:faq-proposed] went missing, too, heh.

Comment: This is a brand new meta; it's a frontier town with loads of opportunities to create new pages! :-)