# How do I format my code blocks?

Tags: support, faq, code-formatting, markdown, code

How do I post text so that it is formatted as code?

What do I need to do so that my code shows up properly—not escaped or removed—when posted? And how do I get the correct syntax highlighting?

> For more information, see "[How do I format my posts in HTML or Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: On MSE: [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/289905).

Answer (score 324, accepted):

For **inline code** (that does not hold newlines), any of the following will work:

- Enclose with backticks: `` `<html>` ``.
- Embed within `<code>` tags, and manually encode HTML entities: `<code>&lt;html&gt;</code>`
- Select the partial text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on OS X) or click the `{}` button above the editor (pictured below)

For **blocks of code**, to preserve newlines, use one of the following methods:

- Use the `{}` button above the editor (pictured below)
- Paste your code, select the full lines, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on OS X)
- Use [fenced code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000) by surrounding your code with ```` ``` ```` or with `~~~`

  - Opening and closing fence have to be on their own line, and can be indented with up to three spaces
  - More than three backticks or tildes can be used, as long as the closing fence uses the same character and is at least as long as the opening fence
- Indent everything four (4) spaces or one (1) tab

  - Ensure there is a blank line between the top of the block and other text
- Encase in `<pre>` or `<pre><code>` tags (in that order; [using `<code><pre>` is invalid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128477/display-error-when-nesting-pre-in-code-elements/128480#128480)), and encode HTML entities (like `&lt;` for `<`) yourself

  - In `<pre>` blocks, HTML tags are applied rather than rendered as text. But in `<pre><code>` blocks with *Syntax highlighting* (see below), all HTML tags are stripped out. A `lang-none` language hint (see below) prevents syntax highlighting and keeps HTML tags.
    (Code highlighting is disabled by default on meta sites.)

Code copy/pasted from an IDE is often already tabbed. When rendering, tabs are replaced with spaces.

(click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZRo3.png) to find the button in the Ask Question Wizard)

[image: gif demonstration]

### Code within a blockquote

To include code within a blockquote, make sure to include the space after the `>` as well as the four spaces before the code.

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

>     for(;;) 
        echo 'badger ';
```

Or, put the blockquote character (and its following space) at the beginning of every blank line, including the one immediately before the code.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
> 
    for(;;) 
        echo 'badger ';
```

You can also use fenced code blocks within quotes:

````
> Text before code
> ```
> for (;;;)
>   echo 'badger';
> ```
> Text after code
````

### Code within a numbered or bulleted list

If your code appears inside a list, you must indent an *additional* four spaces for each level of nesting.

```
- First bullet (is the deepest)

        for(;;) 
          echo 'ow ';

- Second bullet
```

If you want a block of code to follow a list but *not* be nested under the final list item, you can use an HTML comment as a "breakpoint". If you do this, the code block only needs to be indented with the normal four spaces:

```
- First bullet
- Second bullet

<!-- -->

    for(;;) 
      echo 'ow ';
```

### Syntax highlighting

[Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) is used to add colour to the code, but [only if](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question) the language can be uniquely determined given the tags of the question, or if manual hints have been provided.

For any code block, you can use these HTML comments to specify the language:

````
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

```
code goes here
```

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

~~~
code goes here
~~~
````

You can also specify the syntax for *all* codeblocks in your post with the `language-all` hint:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

More text not in code blocks

    code goes here
```

Alternatively, if you use fenced code blocks, you can specify the language right after the first fence:

````
```lang-or-tag-here
code goes here
```

~~~lang-or-tag-here
code goes here
~~~
````

This goes for fenced code blocks elsewhere as well:

````
> ```javascript
> for (;;;) {
>   console.log('badger');
> }
> ```
````

See [the full specification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and [list of languages hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Note that:

- The HTML comments must *not* be indented
- The blank line between `<!-- language: ... -->` and the indented code block *is required*
- The space between `language:` and the language is required
- When using a tag to specify language, the tag name is *case-sensitive*
- If you combine the fenced style with the HTML comments, the HTML comments are ignored

If no language is defined then no highlighting occurs at all. But in the preview, or if multiple language tags define very different languages and no manual definition is used, a default highlighting is used in which Prettify makes a best guess.

There is a delay before the preview text highlighting is applied after you stop editing your markdown source, of around 5 seconds.

### Stack Snippets – Executable JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippets

[Stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) can group a JavaScript, HTML and CSS code snippet and make them runnable. This feature can be accessed by the icon that looks like a page with a `<>` on it. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> on OS X).

[image: Toolbar button to access Stack Snippets]

The code snippet tool allows you to **format code automatically** using the <kbd>Tidy</kbd> button on the left. You can use this option to take care of replacing tabs by spaces, correct code indentation, and general improvement of readability

Once you save your snippet, you’ll get something like this in the editor:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    // JavaScript code

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    /* CSS code */

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    HTML code

<!-- end snippet -->
```

If you delete the `begin snippet` and `end snippet` comments, you’re left with three adjacent code snippets that are not executable. You may also keep a single block of code which will have the correct formatting and indentation.

### Using mobile devices

- One sometimes needs to [press and hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone) the regular single quote to get the backtick.

### Backticks in text

- To include a backtick without accidentally starting some inline code, escape it: `` \` ``

  - `` like \` so `` yields: like ` so
  - `` <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>\`</kbd> gets `|` `` yields: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> gets `|`

### Backticks within backticks

- To use literal backticks within a code span, [use any *unique* number of multiple backticks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) as the opening and closing delimiters: both ``` ``literal backtick (`) here`` ``` and, for example, ``````` ``````literal backtick (`) here`````` ``````` yield `` literal backtick (`) here ``. This [works in comments too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oAaC.png).
- To use literal backticks at the start and/or end, add *one* space to both the opening and closing delimiters:  ``` `` `<html>` `` ``` yields `` `<html>` ``, and ``` `` $` `` ``` yields the Perl `` $` `` operator. In comments, the additional space in the delimiters is not supported. Instead, escape the backtick: ``` `\`<html>\`` ``` and ``` `$\`` ``` to get `` `<html>` `` or `` $` `` [in a comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msVOx.png).

Comment: If something looks like a html-tag and is not in a markdown code-block (indented), it is either interpreted as HTML (a very limited subset is allowed) or silently dropped. [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)

Comment: In chat only ctrl-k works on OS X, not cmd-k. OS X 10.12.6, Chrome 66.0.3359.181.

Comment: It would be nice to know how to do a code backslash in a comment. Update: apparently that is backtick backtick backslash backtick backtick.

Comment: @animuson: `Prettify is used to add colour to the code` ... I assume, this is outdated?

Comment: Is it possible to syntax-highlight a code in case it's in quote?

Comment: @Faither Apologies for the late reply, but you can use code fences (with language hint) inside a quote (see updated answer).

Comment: [Code fences > indented blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/414866/12442137).

Comment: @rene that image is a good addition to have (prompted by the recent duplicate question), but I feel like there should be an expanded explanation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah, I'm pondering on the best edit, given the standard editor and ask wizard editor are different in their feature set. it is not only confusing / mismatching toolbar images.

Comment: So how do you enter code-formatted double-backslashes in a comment?

Comment: @Wyck ``\\`` two backslashes surrounded by DOUBLE backticks