# Code block bug when following numbered list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, markdown

Not sure if there is a SO bug reporting page and if so I'll delete this... but it came to light with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23732355/1324033)

It appears if you try to have a code block immediately follow a list then the first line of the code isn't formatted..

1. list item
2. list item

   public void Code()
   {

---

In order for a temporary fix I introduced a character on a new line..

1. list item
2. list item

'

```
public void Code()
{
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item

Comment: This is also addressed in the code formatting FAQ: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Code block inside the list:

1. list item
2. list item

   ```
   public void Code()
   {
   ```

---

Code block outside the list:

1. list item
2. list item

```
public void Code()
{
```

---

The corresponding markdown:

```
Code block inside the list:

1. list item
2. list item


        public void Code()
        {

---

Code block outside the list:

1. list item
2. list item

<!-- -->

    public void Code()
    {
```

Comment: Ah nice. Half expected this to be a duplicate

Comment: @Sayse - it is, but with a question in Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChrisF - yes i upvoted mat's comment under question. Think my comment on this answer was misread.

Comment: Hah -- I used this just the other day to separate two code blocks with a blank line. I must've thought, "oh well, everybody must already be doing it this way."

Comment: It would be nice if this were included in the formatting help. I've just wasted hours on this and ended up with a hack in which I replaced my list numbers by (1), (2) etc.

Comment: That HTML comment thing is still totally a Kludge! I wish there was a non-janky way to do this...