# Highlighting parts of code

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to highlight or emphasize a part of code that's inside `backticks` or:

```
a code block
```

?

Would be useful for pointing to what's changed, but the [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: Why not turn to code (backticks) what you wan't as code, and format differently the part you want highlighted? For example: `1st half`,<br />highlighted part,<br />`2nd half.`

Comment: Has a feature-request for this.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333694/highlight-specific-lines-of-code-snippet

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's possible with HTML

1) A code block

```
Emphasis on this
```

```
<pre><code>Emphasis on <b>this</b>
</code></pre>
```

---

2) Inline code: `Emphasis on this`

```
Inline code: <code>Emphasis on <b>this</b></code>
```

<sub>Depending on the code, you'd need HTML entities to render it ok.</sub>

Comment: Hey, that's great! It even seems to work with syntax highlighting.

Comment: The workaround works well for small code blocks but not (anymore?) for multiple lines of (PowerShell) code. I get a red comment: ***Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.*** and I am not able to submit it due to: ***Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.***

Comment: ...unless of cause I *also* keep the code formatting which consequently causes redundant indents and an empty line at the top.

Comment: Although this may have worked in the past, it doesn't appear to work today.

Comment: @Grismar, I'm seeing it all right (¿?)

Comment: In that case, maybe it's dependent on theme settings or something of the sort. When I do it, the code formatting seems to override the bold, and it all shows as normal.

Answer (score 13):

No you can't do that. If you use backticks or four spaces to show code then exactly what you type gets rendered.

So if you try to bold something:

> I want **this** bold

you'd actually get this:

```
I want **this** bold
```

The only way to emphasise something would be to use comments to point out what's at fault as this won't mess with the syntax highlighting:

```cs
if (parameter == null) then
{
    parameter.Method(); // <-- It's this that goes wrong
}
```

Comment: And put it in a comment in case it messes with the syntax highlighting (because it's obviously a syntax error).

Comment: for small errors I've occasionally put a comment line underneath with `//      ^^^` pointing to the specific characters

Comment: @OGHaza - that would work too. I just wanted a simple illustration.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Too bad, but I suppose using a comment works all right.

Answer (score 5):

If you build on @ChrisF's solution you can have a full code block if you format something like this

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<pre><code>&lt;div&gt;
    &lt;input name="someInput" value=<b>"highlight"</b>&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Which would produce:

```html
<div>
    <input name="someInput" value="highlight">
</div>
```

More information can be found in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score -1):

Though this is not completely answering the question still it is possible at least to *`emphasize`* or **`make bold`** the whole text inside of `backticks` without the need for HTML markup simply by surrounding the `backticks` by `*` or `**`. Check the code of this answer to get the picture.