# Is "Please post a picture" a non-constructive comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, images

I have been actively discouraging the <s>lazy-ass</s> expedient-but-useless practise of linking or embedding a screenshot of sample data and/or code into a question. Typically, I leave a link to [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and the OP often obliges by editing their question to include sample data and/or code. That's fine; they are usually one-reppers who didn't understand the problems generated by their actions and once the detriments were pointed out they took corrective measures. Good for them!

What is currently burnin' my biscuits is an increase in low-to-medium level users who primarily sit on the answerers' side of the fence asking in Comments for the OP to post an image of sample data. Not just sample data but specifically an *image*, *picture* or *screenshot* of sample data.

I don't for a second believe that a supplemental image to show a wider scope of a large problem is not useful. In fact, I've posted hundreds of images myself to justify my answers but every image I post is accompanied by the code in a code box to facilitate a quick copy & paste operation. Images are a great supplemental resource but should <s>never</s> almost never¹ be the sole non-narrative resource for the reasons cited in that linked answer above.

Is there any recourse? Should there be any recourse? I cannot down-vote a comment and I have no wish to start racking up a large number of rejected flags (got enough already) by tagging them non-constructive. I don't want to start a discussion in the comment section about the pros and cons of posting images in lieu of sample data and code.

---

¹<sub>Never say never. See [Cody Gray's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945/is-please-post-a-picture-a-non-constructive-comment#comment309089_316945) below.</sub>

Comment: Sounds very much like not constructive to me, since an image of data does absolutely nothing for search indexing, readability or answerability. Asking for a picture specifically is like asking for OP to make formatting worse on purpose.

Comment: It is only useful when posting a question about a GUI problem. It is invaluable for answering "my custom-drawn button has a white glow around the edges, what is causing this?" *What* white glow?

Comment: That's a fair point @CodyGray but I would hope that the image was only a supplement to the relevant section of code. I would suppose that I should have added that the requests I am referring to come when there is no code/data to begin with.

Comment: Yes, relevant code is always good. But at the same time, you don't need to embark on a campaign against images. Sure, I gnash my teeth and leave snarky comments when people post *images* of code or *images* of exception traces; that's definitely stupid. But there are real cases where an image is sufficient, like in GUI questions. Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483599/transparent-background-of-xp-themed-control) I answered a long time ago. I *immediately* recognized the problem after seeing the screenshot. I realize I'm picking nits here, but this is Meta after all

Comment: Have you tried educating the commenters why having copy-and-pastable code or data is more valuable?  Ask them if they're going to retype the image contents themselves as part of working out their answer.  They may or may not learn, but simply flagging their comment without explaining to them why it's a problem will not teach them anything.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom  -Yes to the first and been-there-done-that to the second. Maybe this is a bit of a [rant] but if it helps to widen the audience to community feedback on the subject then I'm content.

Comment: I'm in perfect agreement about code images, but obviously they are useful in GUI questions.  I wish that more OP's provided them with questions in the gnuplot tag as well (how do I know why your plot looks wrong, when I can't see your plot?).  It wouldn't help with links, but I wonder if images added with the add image button shouldn't prompt something along the lines of "Are you providing code, data, or something else that users would like to copy and paste?  Please consider typing or pasting that into your answer."

Comment: Pictures always help when the question is about anything graphic including how a chart should look like. It is also often easier to check data at a glance when seeing them in a screenshot than in a quoted text block. It all depends imo. A screenshot of a datagridview is alomst always better than posting the raw data. And without knowing something about the data what good will the code do? Usually we need both.

Comment: Code/spreadsheet images, I completely agree but IMO there are some instances where the output of something is plotted and the code to replicate would make the question too bloated. Eg [Calculate how humans perceive similarity between different colours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774152/calculate-how-humans-perceive-similarity-between-different-colours)

Comment: Can't you post a screenshot of the real issue you have with pictures?

Comment: Of course images can be useful, even vital, for GUI & graphic output questions. When I see questions with code &/or data text posted as images I post a polite comment explaining why we need the text as actual text. But I must admit that a couple of times I've been tempted to post an answer with my code as an image, preferably with a crazy font & bad JPEG artifacting to make OCRing difficult. :)

Comment: I kind of didn't believe your claims that people were actually asking for this kind of stuff. I thought it was just stupid askers who posted images of their code or images of their exception traces. But [I see that I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433507/c-sharp-system-invalidoperationexception-in-mscorlib-dll#comment58565071_35433507).

Comment: @CodyGray: :facepalm: I'm almost inclined to flag that person's comment as not constructive.

Comment: The only other exception to this would be visual programming languages where there is no text code to place in the question. (That's come up a couple of times on Meta.) I think flagging a comment that tells a new user to do something that's going to attract down votes should be OK but I'm not a mod.

Comment: [Hmm…](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822725/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi automatically OCR for code, imo!

Comment: @CodyGray "It is only useful when posting a question about a GUI problem." Not only that. See tag [image processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) for another example of a legitimate use of pictures. In this question, the definition of "sample data" is a bit unclear.

Comment: [So here is one that is completely useless!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786330/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-after-an-attempt-to-get-allure-report-for-child-p) have fun!

Comment: @PM2Ring - I won't admit to having done that and you have no proof. Besides, I made sure to go back and put the code into a code box a few days later.

Comment: @Trilarion not sure why we are getting hung up on pictures in posts the OP is speaking specifically about code images *(screenshots of the code instead of copy and pasting to a formatted code block)*. All this talk about legitimate use of pictures is out of scope.

Comment: @Bergi: It looks like some people don't appreciate your sense of humour. Oh well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to battle it out in the comments now that you have a handy meta post to link to. If you see someone asking the OP for a screenshot of code, @comment them, add something like "don't add screenshots of code. add code." and link to this or your favorite Meta post on the subject. If users want to have a debate after that, direct them back to Meta: "Debates about what should/should not be posted on SO belong in Meta."

As to flagging... I wouldn't bother. Direct your comments to the OP and warn them not to follow the others' advice. That should be enough. We've had these kinds of issues for years, especially over where users should go to get their off-topic questions answered (Code Review, etc). If every such comment was flagged, the flag queue would be miles long and there'd be no hope of ever getting through it all.

Comment: There *is* a hope of getting through the flag queue! who knew ;)

Comment: @MichaelB - OK. There'd be even less hope of ever getting through it all.

Comment: The length of the queue is irrelevant to whether a comment should be flagged or not.

Comment: @Mast - Agreed. But if the queue is clogged with trivial flags, than the more important flags will be missed. I think this is relatively trivial and a response in the comments is sufficient to handle it.

Answer (score 35):

Posting a picture is helpful exactly when the question is about some visual effect--for example, when asking about GUI alignment issues or "what does this Eclipse marker mean?" If the picture would serve to clarify what the poster is experiencing or trying to achieve, then asking for it may be constructive. Of course, the question should also explain in text as clearly as is possible ("I see a red triangle on my XML files in Package Explorer").

Most of the time, though, these comments are random "me too!" submissions that are unhelpful or flat-out counterproductive. (I recall a number of comments made on algorithm or packaging questions demanding that the OP "post the code" when it's irrelevant to the question.) These comments are not constructive, should be counter-commented on, and are reasonable to flag.

Comment: It's at times like that when I wish we could down-vote comments.

Comment: Not sure about the flagging part.

Comment: We seem to be missing the point the OP is talking specifically about code being posted as an image and requests for that. They aren't saying we shouldn't post images full stop they just want clarification on whether comments asking for code to be posted as a screen shot should be flagged as non-constructive.

Comment: @Lankymart Actually, we aren't missing that point at all. chrylis is just going a step further, also saying in which situations a picture is actually a good idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator absolutely they are taking it out of the context. The OP already explained they know that images can be useful and was talking about a specific case, this just muddies things.

Answer (score 3):

I actually had a topic yesterday where I was asked to post a screenshot of my database tables.  I found this acceptable because I already had all of my code pasted in, but the user that was helping me wanted to see the database as well.  I didn't see a problem with this.  In a case such as mine, I don't have any issues.  But I can understand that posting a picture instead of actual code can be an issue.

Comment: In that case the correct thing to ask for is the schema definition (the CREATE TABLE statements, etc) *as text*.

Comment: @zwol that makes perfect sense, and now you probably see why I needed help with a database... Haha

Comment: @zwol while I agree I still don't see how that example pertains to images of source code. We seem to be going off topic a bit here.

Comment: @Lankymart How is a database schema definition not source code?

Comment: @zwol honestly you're splitting hairs, it depends if it is database scheme they wanted or just a visual representation of the database structure.

Comment: @Lankymart I don't see why wanting to see a visual db representation would be a bad thing.  I don't think it would hurt to have an image for that.

Comment: @huSh I never said it was?? My point was asking for a visual representation of the database structure is not the same as asking for an image of source code which is what this question is about. Feel like I've gone full circle here...

Comment: @Lankymart I was agreeing with you, and reiterating the point.

Comment: @hush sorry went a bit defensive on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of more angles to this, which I'd like to express. As a background, I am a very new user of SO. So, am still getting my head around what is ok and what is not ok to do on this online society. My experience is limited to Excel/formula queries, and relevance over sharing actual code is none. For me, code is the excel-formula-logic that I share across.

1: Elaboration in screenshots - When I write a solution, I do feel the need to make it as structured and format it as code (Excel formulae). It is then easy to try out. But as I noticed over the small while that I am here, the more experienced users do also state (when someone asks a Qn) that this site is not for asking questions that give you ready made/spoon fed answers. In one of the comments over the last few days (can't find it), an experienced user was asking for more info in a screenshot - and as a person watching the ongoing conversation, I did feel that (s)he was verifying that (s)he wasn't doing the homework for someone else. Which I thought was pretty valid too.

2: Language - (probably since I am new) I try and check where an OP is from. If you see their profile some of them don't seem to be from English speaking countries. When I read their posts (not wanting to say this with a bias), but I do wonder if they are asking exactly what they meant to say (not to rule out that an English speaking person can too, sometimes not formulate/structure the problem as well). (For me, English is the 3rd most fluent language, and I need to rethink everytime I phrase something to write, so that someone else doesn't misinterpret). In cases like these, I do feel a screenshot/visual representation of the data goes a long way.

I have refrained from asking it as I was caught up in @Jeeped's crossfire :P a couple of days ago (his approach was very [supportive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413006/how-to-increment-row-value-in-excel-index-formula-using-fill-handle/35413481#35413481), but) it has made me rethink about asking for a screenshot, as this is an online society after all and there is an order to the chaos. And all in all, despite the above 2 points I mention which seem pro-screenshots, I do see value in getting code there - specially when it is not just Excel formulae (which are small in size and seem to have a relatively easier syntax).

Comment: tbh, I usually discard narrative to look at the sample data and code first.Not everyone speaks EN-US but everyone speaks sample data and code, If I cannot understand the sample data and code then I will look at the narrative.

Comment: Ok, maybe the language point is not as relevant. I'm probably more conscious of it as a non-native speaker.

Comment: If I could localize this point to the [XL] forum(s) I would say that supplying an image of sample data gets 2-20 people retyping the original data and that is not a productive use of talent. Let me leave this with a quote from the second to last bullet poin\t in my original link. [You're asking us to volunteer our time for free to solve your problem, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Yeah absolutely, hence I say I see value in getting the code. I would say that an additional image apart from the code helps as well at times.

Comment: *'I don't for a second believe that a supplemental image to show a wider scope of a large problem is not useful. '* Sorry if I'm looking like a hard-ass but pictures of sample data with no C&D information is just *wrong**. An OP supplying a link to an image is wrong but it is from naievety; asking for an image of data or code is VERY wrong. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think that your language comment is very valid.  When someone asks a question and its in "broken" English, and they have not provided any example of the data they ae dealing with, I believe an image of the spreadsheet of what they have and what they are trying to achieve is a very valid thing. besides, isn't a picture worth a thousand words?  Now maybe I am missing something but  when I ask a question how am I supposed to paste the layout of how you want the excel data I am working with and how I want it to look after I am done manipulation?

Comment: I agree with Jeeped that its time consuming to retype chunks of example data, but I personally dont know show to do it without an image.  Is there a way to insert a table into you the question block like there is for code, images, or quotes?  Maybe the problem is the interface with how people ask questions does not allow them to post a mini spreadsheet.  may it does let you do that but people are not aware of it.

Comment: so after reading all this, it has left me confused about one of my [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098397/extract-data-from-a-web-page-that-may-not-be-formatted-as-a-table) and whether my use of images was good or bad in it.