# Feature request for table import tool for questions

Tags: feature-request

Speaking from personal experience and noting some of the issues that are caused by questions asked using screenshots of data instead of providing sample data.

I am wondering if a TABLE import tool button could be added to the top of the question editing window.  I recently just did a test between MS Excel and MS Word.  When I paste the selected cells into word, word automatically puts it into a nicely formatted table.

I am very aware that people can treat their sample data as code and use that space bar to generate a sample table like so:

```
    (A)  |  (B)  |  (C)
(1)      |       |
(2)      |       |
(3)      |       |
```

and when the example data is small this is a great option.  However to the uninitiated that are not familiar with all the rules or ways of doing things(heck I am still not), they are not necessarily aware of this option, or it is an intimidating process for them when they are asking their first question.

Instead of posting data like above they may:

- post no data at all, which leads to many questions by potential respondents
- post a screen shot, which leads to many respondents generating sample data of their own. ([There is a whole post on screenshots here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945/is-please-post-a-picture-a-non-constructive-comment/))

I also know that you can copy and paste into the question box.  I have tried this a few times and it can get pretty ugly.  As a result I can understand again why people dont copy and paste their data.

Take a look at this screen shot of data:

[image]

Not as nicely colour coded as to the original version from the question it came from, but it does have information layed out in a table.  When I copy and paste this data into this question, it gets ugly fast! as seen below in the raw format:

---

Fruit   Vegetable   Protein Source  Carb    Snack   Remainder   Eat out     Search  Result
Banana  Cabbage Mince Free Mutton   Porridge    Greek Yogurt Dressing   Milk    Restaurant      Chicken Protein Source
    Celery  Chicken Noodles Granola Bars    Soya Milk           Carrots Vegetable
    Carrots Tuna Chunks Rice    Rice Cakes  Pepper          Soya Milk   MULTIPLE ENTRIES
    Paprika Cottage Cheese  Potatoes        Tomato Puree            Brains  NOT FOUND
    Chopped Eggs    Baked Beans     Oil
        Pink Salmon Bread       Soya Milk
        Cook Ham    Sweet Potatoes

---

or if I place it in to a block quote

> Fruit Vegetable   Protein Source  Carb    Snack   Remainder   Eat
>   out       Search  Result Banana   Cabbage Mince Free Mutton   Porridge    Greek
>   Yogurt Dressing   Milk    Restaurant      Chicken Protein Source
>     Celery  Chicken Noodles Granola Bars    Soya Milk           Carrots Vegetable
>     Carrots Tuna Chunks Rice    Rice Cakes  Pepper          Soya Milk   MULTIPLE
>   ENTRIES   Paprika Cottage Cheese  Potatoes        Tomato Puree            Brains  NOT
>   FOUND     Chopped Eggs    Baked Beans     Oil                     Pink Salmon Bread       Soya
>   Milk                      Cook Ham    Sweet Potatoes

Or a code sample:

```
Fruit   Vegetable   Protein Source  Carb    Snack   Remainder   Eat out     Search  Result
Banana  Cabbage Mince Free Mutton   Porridge    Greek Yogurt Dressing   Milk    Restaurant      Chicken Protein Source
    Celery  Chicken Noodles Granola Bars    Soya Milk           Carrots Vegetable
    Carrots Tuna Chunks Rice    Rice Cakes  Pepper          Soya Milk   MULTIPLE ENTRIES
    Paprika Cottage Cheese  Potatoes        Tomato Puree            Brains  NOT FOUND
    Chopped Eggs    Baked Beans     Oil             
        Pink Salmon Bread       Soya Milk               
        Cook Ham    Sweet Potatoes
```

Now its my understanding that we are trying o be helpful people.  We would rather spend our time responding to or maybe asking questions than time editing/reformatting questions.  The simpler a site is to use the more people will use it?  Yes I realize there are a lot of 1 rep people that ask questions, never upvote or accept answers, and a lot that may have forgot they even asked the question and have moved on to other things.  I think while they may benefit from this tool, they will not be the only ones.  I think everyone that has some table type data to post could see potential benefit from a tool I am requesting.

I spend most of my time in the Excel section of this site to answer questions, so it may come across as a bit selfish/biased, but it is my understanding that such a feature would also be applicable to any area where you are dealing with how to manipulate structured data.  Therefore it is not just a request for Excel spreadsheet data but any data in a table format that could also be used in SQL, Access, R, etc.

What I am envisioning is your press a button. similar to the insert picture button, and a window pops up where you can paste your table.  You then press ok, and the pasted data is "magically reformatted" similar to how MS word does it, and places it in your question nicely formatted for readability and to allow others to copy and paste the data onto their on computers once the question is posted.

Heck if we could identify a commonly asked data structure type question, we could even provide a small sample list of data for people that are worried about presenting their own data because it has confidential information or the like and they have not thought about replacing it with dummy data.

Comment: As someone who spends most of my time in the Excel tags, I would love for this to be a feature, or even to allow HTML tables at the very least. I know this was [`status-declined` on meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables), but this is quite specific to SO.

Comment: I am guessing here, but isn't the "question box" the same throughout the entire stack site?  so if you add it here its going to be on English language, acadamia, car repair, etc, sites as well?  Where I am sure if they have a question in table format they could make use of it as well!  Thinking of all those roleplaying game tables!

Comment: @MacroMan when that question was asked, MSE was MSO.  MSE as a standalone site has only existed for 2 years.

Comment: @psubsee2003 in that case. Balls.

Comment: You may be interested in this post on WebApps [Is there a webapp to create ASCII art tables?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables)