# Should the MCVE page advise against pictures of text?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, minimal-reproducible-example

I tend to see a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085812/sas-get-rid-of-duplicate-variables) where askers post or link to pictures of text rather than providing directly usable test data. This is lazy and creates tedious extra work for anyone attempting to answer the question.

To guide people away from this behaviour, I propose adding an extra sentence to the 'Complete' section on the MCVE page:

> Complete
>
> Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is
>   included. **Text that people can copy and paste from your answer is far more helpful than pictures of text.**
>
> - Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try
>     them to test the answer they're about to post.
> - The problem might not
>     be in the part you suspect it is, but another part entirely.
>
> If the problem requires some server-side code as well as an XML-based
>   configuration file, include them both. If a web page problem requires
>   HTML, some JavaScript and a stylesheet, include all three.

Should we generally be advising against posting pictures of text?

Adding 'Picture of text' to the Vote to Close description feels rather reactive - I would rather we find a place to tell people to avoid doing this before then, ideally while the question is still open, or, better yet, while they're still composing it. Another idea would be to display a 'no pictures of text please' message the first few times the insert image button is used.

Is there any more appropriate place where we could advise people not to do this?

Comment: We shouldn't HAVE to do it, IMHO....But users being what they are... It does feel warranted

Comment: If anything, I would strengthen the language used even more, although I'm not entirely sure how. Pictures of text are basically *always* terrible. (Pictures of a graphical programming language aren't so bad, of course.)

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that if an image of a problem does not explain something that sample data, code or an error message cannot then images are to be discouraged. See [Is “Please post a picture” a non-constructive comment?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316945). In  my own experience, the necessary use of an image is few and far between and generally non-constructive to a question.

Comment: Suggested edit: in your first paragraph, **anyone** should be changed to **everyone**. You might also want to mention that images do nothing to improve search results for future users looking for a solution to a problem but that is likely beyond the grasp of the one-repper looking for an expedient answer to their own issue.

Comment: @Jeeped: "anyone" is fine.

Comment: @BoltClock - but it isn't *anyone*. It is one person with a problem that expects multiple people (anyone interested in helping them resolve said problem) to each retype the basics of the problem in order to test a solution. To me that is a sad distribution of resources.

Comment: Based on a lot of recent experience in the review queues, I would also include that sample data should be included in text (not image) form.  It's also helpful when error messages are text, as well, as all too often, the image of the error message has clipped off some important bit.

Comment: jftr, [this is a recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091790/international-internal-sheet-name) when an image works better (crossed regional language VBA).

Comment: @Jeeped it isn't quite as bad as you suggest unless everyone tries to answer the question at exactly the same time - usually one answerer gives in and transcribes the data, and then everyone else can copy them. It's still annoying, though, and it makes people less likely to want to contribute the first answer.

Comment: @user667489 - uh... yeah. *'gives in'*... that made me lol for a couple of seconds before I started to cry. No wonder I habitually down-vote every question that relies on an image for pertinent information that could not be disclosed in a narrative. I agree with you; there should be a stronger verbage. I will also say that it must be easier for the user to create said image on their computer recently as I've seen a large upswing in its usage within hte last year. Perhaps another discussion should be about allowing first time questioners to post links at all.

Comment: Yes! Especially screenshots of sourcecode! I would also disallow link descriptions to be `enter image description here`

Comment: ...because users always read and follow all the instructions on the MCVE page. I'm not opposed to updating it but it will not stem the tide of code images or "can i haz teh codez" questions, etc. Something more fundamental needs to change. New users should be trained before allowed to post, etc.

Comment: What about putting picture based questions that don't have supporting text on hold with the "needs to be in text form" for a reason? ooops... I am assuming the OP can edit the post if it is on hold? Can they?

Comment: @Rodger They can. But thats basically a new close reason (and you should post that as new question)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer [hehehe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295509/792066)

Comment: Wow, adding a sentence to some page no-one ever reads should really solve the problem. I don't know whether to upvote the question for identifying a pretty big problem, or downvote it for such a week-kneed solution.

Comment: Don't forget screenshots of error messages.  And add that people who do it should be beaten with a dead goat.

Comment: @torazaburo Feel free to post an answer with some other ideas. I've already added one myself.

Comment: [Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/128421) an image of the code is necessary.

Comment: After editing the proposed change so that it includes the paragraph and bullets that exist in the current page content, I think it's apparent that while the information would be useful there _somewhere_, the proposed sentence would probably fit better as part of the final paragraph of that section rather than before the bullet points.

Comment: @JeffC: _"it will not stem the tide of code images"_ -- so true. But that's not the only reason to care about documenting the policy. Even if it doesn't stop someone from doing it in the first place, having an official page to point to can help when you try to advise the person about their mistake and they insist that they did nothing wrong.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree but I feel like the vast majority of people don't care whether it's documented or not. I see so many questions where people ask the most ridiculous questions that if they had spent 30s googling the question, they would have found their answer. Rather than marking a question as a dup, people answer it. People can't be bothered to indent their code, format their code as code, even provide their code, or a relevant error message, and the list goes on. If 99% of the people answering questions don't care if people follow the rules, what's the point of having rules at all?

Comment: @Will There aren't enough dead goats in the world...

Comment: @JeffC: _"what's the point of having rules at all"_ -- just imagine how awful SO would be _without_ the rules. In any case, while all of what you said is true, none of that is relevant to the point I was trying to make. I.e. the scenario I'm talking about is _after_ a conscientious SO citizen has pointed out the error of someone's ways and that someone argues the point. Posting a link to a clear rule is an effective and easy way for the conscientious SO citizen to end the discussion; even if the argumentative person insists on continuing to argue, there's no need to pursue it further.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yep... understood the point you were making. I agree that we need rules, I was just bemoaning the fact that more people don't care about keeping SO clean (by following the rules). Pointing someone to a clear rule theoretically ends the discussion but if you can't get enough people to agree with your close reason, etc. then the post is left to linger anyway. There are so many bad questions left open or even getting answered each day... it's overwhelming.

Comment: FWIW, sometimes when people post an image of code in their question it gets answered with an image of code. Of course, such answers soon get deleted, but i always have a chuckle when I see it. :)

Answer (score 35):

Probably worth noting here that anyone with <= 15 reputation who tries to post an image sees this warning:

[image: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.]

Not saying anyone bothers reading it, but... At least we tried. If they aren't reading that, they're probably not reading MCVE either.

#### See also: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors/307500#307500)

Comment: Can we make that warning appear for users with <=15k rep? ;) Many, many people need that reminder. But seriously... I would suggest upping that to 1k. I still see too many pics of HTML, etc. on the tags I hang out on.

Comment: We can make that number ANYTHING WE WANT! As long as it fits in an integer variable.

Comment: It's a little bit ironic... I leave this comment and what's in the first question I look at? A pic of HTML... and the user has 76 rep.

Comment: I wonder sometimes if it's actually quite intentional.

Comment: I had no idea this warning existed...I didn't ever try to post an image until well past 15 rep. Probably holds true for many people. I agree with @JeffC that we should raise the rep limit significant from 15. Frankly, given that it's just a warning message, I'm not sure why there needs to be a rep limit at all...just show that message to everyone. It's the only content you _know_ will be shown to the user posting an image, even if they should be reading the other pages too.

Comment: My impression is that people with less than 15 rep don't tend to post actual pictures, they just put a link to a picture at some off-site picture hosting site. (Which is even worse.) I agree that a higher minimum would be good, but as Peter Duniho said it doesn't really hurt to have the warning appear for everybody.

Comment: `if (currentUser.rep <= JonSkeet.rep - 1)`? ;)

Comment: And yes, I know that can be simplified, but shut up. :P

Comment: So I went back and checked the data we used to pick that threshold, @Peter. 15 was a threshold at which code-less image-having posts started to fall off pretty significantly. Looking back, it appears as though the warning may have had a *small* impact, but it certainly isn't dramatic; I could see bumping the threshold up to maybe 100 as a way to give a few more people a chance to see it, but probably not gonna have any value past that.

Comment: _"15 was a threshold at which code-less image-having posts started to fall off pretty significantly"_ -- that's certainly interesting data. But represents only part of the problem, and arguably the most obvious error someone can make (i.e. the easiest, most likely to avoid). People also use images to show stack traces, error messages, input and even sometimes output data. Have you or anyone else looked at the degree of incidence of these other types of inappropriate images?

Comment: We did some manual review of a sample of posts with images last year before implementing the warning, with maybe 20% being inappropriate in some way, @Peter.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, no...the MCVE page isn't the right place for this information, at least not primarily. The MCVE page really should remain focused on the *code*:

> …you will get much better answers if you provide **code** people can use to reproduce the problem

[Emphasis mine]

That said, of course it's important that relevant information be provided as text, not images. But I think the guidance for that belongs in the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

For example, one might add a new section between "Help others reproduce the problem" and "Include all relevant tags":

> #### Ensure your question is accessible and searchable
>
> Images (pictures) may be helpful to illustrate graphical output, and to provide other optional details that may be useful. But the important details of your question should be provided in **textual format**. This includes the problem description, all code, error messages, input and output data, and anything else that is representable as text.
>
> Doing so makes it easy for others to reproduce your problem by copy/pasting the code and data, but also will ensure that posts can be translated by automated translation tools, read out loud by text-to-speech software or displayed in more readable fonts and colors for people with vision difficulties, and of course that the important content can be indexed by search engines so that the post can be found later.

Wording to be refined as necessary, of course.

While this guidance is important for all aspects of information in a question, because it's also specifically relevant to code and data, I agree it would be worthwhile to include similar direction on the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. But this is a broader issue than just code or data, and so deserves prominent placement in the broader help article.

Comment: I would put it in both places. On the MCVE page to attempt to prevent people from posting pics of their code and on the good question page to keep people from posting pics of just about anything text related... code, HTML, and so on.

Comment: @JeffC: IME, screenshots of code are much less common than other misuses of images. But I admit, inasmuch as users can be expected to read the "mcve" or "ask" pages at all, it might be worthwhile to provide similar guidance there as well, perhaps in abbreviated form. I'll update my answer to acknowledge that.