# Are **edits** which `decorate` the post with > markdown good?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I've been noticing a number of suggested edits proposing markdown that I consider to be either irrelevant or harmful. However, I've [been seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17017139) these [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17017104) actually [get approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16971953). Is there something about these edits that is actually helpful? Am I wrong to think that these shouldn't have been approved?

Comment: Dear God, those edits are horrible...It may be best to just use a custom flag and point a moderator in this direction.

Comment: Users that propose edits in general know what kind of edits get approved by the people that review.  Edit turds are the fairly inevitable outcome.

Comment: Funny you should ask/post this. I've been noticing this (new trend) in the past few weeks where either OP's use the `>` character to highlight filenames, or suggestive edits do it, and I either reject the edits, or edit those out myself; I feel I'm fighting a losing battle. This isn't nor should it be used for personal formatting preferences. TBH, I was going to post on meta about this, but decided not to, so you basically beat me to it/did it for me. So to answer this: no.

Comment: The first and third suggestions are vile and disgusting, and their approvers should be review-banned. The second one is actually not that bad; it adds some dubiously-necessary bolding but most if not all of the (inline) code formatting is actually warranted.

Comment: I've seen quote formatting misused but this is ridiculous.

Comment: @Makoto: I wouldn't say *all* of them are horrible. Outside of some pointless bold-face, the second one seems defensible.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Unnecessary bolding, not correcting any of the sentence flow, leaving "thanks" in the edit...I'm not sure what I see to defend.

Comment: It's pretty easy to find other examples similar to the third by this specific user who suggested the edits. However, those were approved by the OP. Shouldn't have been approved, but that they were OP approved may matter

Comment: I just saw two of these practically in a row. What is going on? Do bad editors actually get together to decide as a group what to do wrong?

Comment: @BSMP From my memory when I was <50 rep, formatting is low-effort editing. It's really easy to just add bold, backticks, quotes, etc. And you also see some of the things that other people suggested that got approved, and copy it. If just one bad suggestion gets approved, it can spread and other people think it's a good idea

Comment: *"putted your note in double qote (it's important to do this at next times)"* Wow, absolutely not. Like @Fred, I've been seeing a trend of inappropriate use of blockquote formatting as well. I don't know what causes this. It's like people discovered formatting for the first time and decided to format their post like it were a ransom letter. No, these edits are not good and they should be rejected. If you see an ongoing pattern, raise a moderator flag so we can deal with both parties.

Comment: @CodyGray Would adding a comment under a post (question/answer) such as: *"Please remove the custom formatting. The (improper) use of the `>` character has been discussed in (link to this question)"* be considered as acceptable? And if they fail to remove it, what action should be taken? I.e.: Just edit/rollback, or flag for moderation? This issue seems to possibly take up a lot of people's time where and as I mentioned in an above comment, that I/we are probably fighting a (new) battle and stand at losing. I for one am eventually going to run out of steam, *as it were*.

Comment: I feel you on the uphill battle aspect, @Fred. For what it's worth, just yesterday I reached out to a serial offender and he got the message and went back and fixed his old posts. On the other hand, it's true that our words often fall on deaf ears. I don't see anything wrong with a single comment, but just don't let yourself get sucked into an argument in the comments. Sometimes it's easier/faster/better just to edit it out, especially if you have full editing privileges. Obviously don't get into a rollback war; flag a mod to stop in.

Comment: @CodyGray I won't get into an edit/argument/rollback war; it'll just take up (more of) my energy where it could have been spent on in a positive way. If I see (a)(unnecessary) rollback(s), I'll just flag it; thanks.

Comment: *capitalizes App for no reason, leaves python lowercase.* I wish I could give them -2 reputation for that edit.

Comment: People like misusing the block quote markup because it looks like a banner, a big highlighted region Really would like to go back in time and revise that formatting decision.

Comment: @Josh And what would you change the formatting to? There isn't really a good option that wouldn't cause this problem. It used to be indistinguishable from a code block, which I didn't care for for other reasons. Anything that properly distinguishes a quotation from surrounding text will be vulnerable to "banner" abuse.

Comment: I've always believed that improving the formatting of a post would go a long way towards improving its readability, but somerhing tells me this guy thinks he can rep farm his way to glory with these hack edits.

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of edits being approved by the OP of the post after they were rejected...

Comment: @CodyGray Here's my [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355274/change-quote-formatting-to-show-double-quote-marks) for changing the "quote" formatting.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd favor what I usually see in printed text: just inset the paragraph with larger than normal line breaks between the surrounding paragraphs. Another option might be a simple vertical line along the leading margin. (The display already has this, but it also has a filled rectangle behind the text.) I really think that 99% of the problem is the background, and I also don't think that it's very good for readability even when it's being used properly.

Comment: You know what else is terrible about these "edits"? When done to closed questions (most of which are closed because they're terrible), they push said question into the Reopen queue. Where someone has to look at said question, determine that yes, it's still f**king terrible, and mark "Leave closed". End result is that the Reopen queue, instead of containing mostly questions that have been improved and may actually be worth reopening, now contains mostly questions that should DIAF, which completely buggers the usefulness of said queue... plus I'm pretty sure it's also being used for rep farming.

Comment: I just came about a new question today where the OP used the `>` where they really were not needed and they failed to update their post after my asking them nicely. I flagged for moderation and personally think that "zero tolerance" should be used, no exceptions.

Comment: Let's just add an auto-format checkbox when posting questions and answers that automatically neats up the stuff.

Comment: @IanKemp The other thing about pointless edits to closed questions is that if the OP _does_ subsequently repair the question it _won't_ go back into the Reopen queue, which drastically reduces its odds of being re-opened. SO when close-voting potentially salvageable questions it's a good idea to deal with any pending edit suggestions before the final close-vote is cast.

Comment: Please also consider that new members will often go for the easiest way to get 50 rep in order to comment. Thus, we (that includes me) opted for an editing battle to gain some reps.

Comment: [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits)

Comment: I've since given up on this matter. It's getting out of control and flagging/commenting seems to make things worse and no longer amounting to anything.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are right in thinking that these edits shouldn't have been approved. They shouldn't have been suggested either.

Rolling back the changes is good, but don't get involved in an edit war.

Under certain circumstances moderators can also reject edits if they've been erroneously accepted, removing the reputation gain. To do this there has to be no subsequent edits to the post and it has to be done fairly soon after the edit was approved. So if you see any particularly egregious examples, don't roll back just flag it and we'll (hopefully) be able to reject the approval and remove the reputation gain.

Comment: And hopefully review-ban the offenders.

Answer (score 26):

Acceptable formatting edits:

- Adding code formatting to *source code* or other kinds of text that would benefit from the "Courier New" font. Program output, compiler messages, formulas etc. Sometimes it also adds clarity to paths and file names.

  Note that source code also includes language keywords and identifiers, particularly when they can be mistaken for text.
- Adding quote formatting to quotes or cited text.
- Adding emphasis through *italics* can sometimes make parts of the question easier to read. But use this with care.
- Table formatting in case it increases readability.

Bad formatting edits:

- Adding bold text pretty much anywhere. It only makes sense as headlines in very long, detailed posts, if at all.
- Adding emphasis where it doesn't make any sense.
- Using bold text, code formatting or quotes for emphasis.

---

Your edit example 1:

- Superfluous change of capitalization from iOS to IOS - doesn't add anything.
- Incorrect emphasis with bold text.
- Incorrect use of quotes. This one is pretty bad and reason enough to reject.

  The original question was pretty clear and there is no apparent need to edit. *None* of the edits added anything of value. This should have been rejected as "no improvement whatsoever".

Your edit example 2:

- Incorrect emphasis with bold text.
- Valid code formatting edits that do increase readability.
- Superfluous text "image 1", "image 2" added (with wrong capitalization). When editing links to images you should preferably make it so that the picture appears directly on SO rather than through a link.
- However, the editor does not reflect over the OP posting "pictures of code". This is something that we should always point out and prompt the OP to fix. Questions containing pictures of code should often be closed.

  The OP of the original question should have been prompted to replace the "pictures of code" with the actual code before anything else. Apart from that, an edit fixing code formatting and/or the images would have been ok.

  This edit does improve some things, namely the code formatting. However, it also adds some clutter. The most appropriate action is either "improve edit" (remove clutter but acknowledge the edit as useful) or "reject and edit", depending on your mood. It would also be somewhat ok to accept the edit as-is, since the result is clearer than the original, despite the clutter.

Your example 3:

- Incorrect emphasis with bold text (mixed with italics). This is just taken completely out of nowhere, no need for emphasis.
- Adds incorrect capitalization.
- Adds incorrect quote formatting.
- File names could have been changed to code formatting. Not to bold text.

  There was no reason to edit this post. The edit in this case is quite horrible, on the border to vandalism. This should have been rejected as "no improvement whatsoever".

Unfortunately some of these were approved by the OP which makes the edit accepted without review. Meaning that the OP can often be as dull as the rep-hunting editor. What we can do upon encountering crap edits approved by the OP is to rollback.

In addition, you can pick one of the posts with the most horrible edit, flag the post for diamond mod attention. Yes, this is fine, the flag is not necessarily directed to the OP of the post. Type down that you think the edit shouldn't have been approved, then post a link to the suggested edit.

Diamond mods may remove edit privileges of the editor, but also the people who approved of the edit ("robo reviewing") may have their review privileges removed.

Comment: Changing `iOS` to `IOS` isn't even "not an improvement" -- it's outright _wrong_. The Apple operating system is always styled as "iOS". "IOS" is typically used to refer to the operating system on Cisco routers.

Comment: Without reference to OP's specific question and their edits, I would disagree with your general point that bold is comparatively evil (I may be paraphrasing you here).  I think bold inline can be used appropriately to call attention to the most important ideas in an answer, which can help with scanability of the text.  Of course, bold can (but shouldn't) be over used, but I think that it's dramatically overstating the point to say "Add(ing) bold pretty much anywhere" is bad formatting.

Comment: @JoelBrown Bold isn't evil, but why would an editor know better than the OP what the OP wants to emphasize? If the OP didn't consider it worthwhile to emphasize something, why change it? If you think a certain part is important, write a comment about it.

Comment: @AndrewMyers: The site's aim is to have good questions with good answers, not just to satisfy OPs. Some people are not good at knowing which parts of their own question/answer benefit from emphasis (in particular, they often understand very well the issue they want to get across, and thus do not realise which points need flagging up for the benefit of other people). So I see nothing wrong in principle with other people adding it. That said, I'm pretty sure I've never done so myself, and I've certainly removed lots of superfluous boldface that was detracting significantly from readability...

Comment: It's so annoying when some "helpful" editor converts links to actual images of text. I deal with questions containing images of text (or links to such images) by posting this canned comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @duskwuff To be picky, IOS is a name, so it is correct to use upper case (OS being capital since it is an abbreviation). Similarly, the correct spelling of other Apple products is Iphone, Imac etc. Changing case to iOS is just a marketing trick by Apple, it is not correct use of English. However, changing from Applish to English is very minor changes and not reason enough to edit.

Answer (score 10):

I believe [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17017104) of the approved suggested edit is somehow *correct* (I might be wrong or edit can be a bit better). This edit actually improves formatting and makes the question more readable. Other [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17017139) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16971953) are just point less and doesn't improve anything. So the first one is bit better and the two other edits must be rejected for doing no *reasonable* improvement.

<strike>Just noticed that [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) approved one of such [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17017139), I am not sure about this but we may look for what went wrong there.</strike>

Comment: Community♦ approval happens when a user with full edit privileges clicks on "Improve Edit". You can see in the edit history you linked that Pravitha V did exactly that. Their action is listed there as "Edit". The bots haven't run amok yet. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray I see.. Thanks for the info. Is it kind of auto approval by the community isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. Community has moderator privileges, so it does the instant approval. Also happens when the OP approves an edit to one of their posts.