# Is it wrong to target edit a single user's posts?

Tags: discussion, edits, serial-editing

There are times when I find a post in need of an edit, and after, decide to check out the author's profile and other posts. More than once, I've come across a user with multiple posts that have a pattern of misspelled words, incorrect grammar, unclear formatting, as well as a plethora of unneeded greetings and salutations.

For example, I just came across one user that has over 800 answers. I opened the first few answers, and noticed that every single post contained something like:

> Hiya this might help...
> hey try this please
> Hope it helps, CHeers!
> Hope it helps, cheers!
> Hope this helps, `:)`
> Rest feel free to play around with demo,
> Hope it helps, lemme know if I missed anything.
> Please lemme know if I missed anything, cheers!
> Also if you can provide jsfiddle I might take a look. Cheerios

In addition to the unneeded fluff in the posts, the posts were disorganized and hard to read.

I'm not talking about garbage posts that deserve to be deleted. I'm talking about posts that have helpful content and many times have multiple upvotes, yet are just in need of improvement.

Sometimes, English is not a user's first language or a user does not have a solid grasp of how to write a well-organized post, and that is why their posts consistently need editing. Other times, the user is simply lazy and doesn't bother with grammar rules. Regardless, many times a post with problems is an indication of more problem posts to follow.

When I find a bad post, is it wrong to go through the author's list of posts and edit all the posts in need of editing?

**Con:** A big reason why I see not to do this, is that the user might not like if another user suddenly changes all their posts. They also may think the editor is serial-editing for the wrong reason.

**Pro:** The main reason I would think this is a good idea, is that this would be improving the content on the site. This can be a way to easily find and fix a list of bad posts.

---

#### Update

It looks like one user took this idea to heart and just edited [four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45084555/4660897) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45337451/4660897) [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464662/4660897) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45686029/4660897). I can now say that on the receiving end of such targeted editing, I don't mind it at all. True, some of the edits were extremely minor and I normally would not recommend them. (I have a feeling the user was just trying to make a point here.) Regardless, I see these edits as improvements, and it does not bother me that they all came from the same user within a short amount of time.

Comment: I don't like targeting users but I fail to see a bad side to this as long as your just editing.  If the post genuinely needs improvement then I don't see any harm in improving them.  Doing it in batches might be warranted though as you will be bumping their posts which will put extra attention on their content.

Comment: Maybe ask the user first, whether they agree. I remember a case where a high rep user insisted in keeping their signature and rolled back all edits which removed them.

Comment: @honk That's a case where you flag for a mod, because they're the one doing something inappropriate.

Comment: @Servy: All users are equal. But some users are more equal, you know. As far as I remember, nothing was done, because TPTB didn't want to scare off a valuable contributer.

Comment: To avoid the problems in the con, be sure to be extra clear about why the edits are happening.

Comment: Side note: According to the tag description, what you're talking about isn't serial editing. Serial-editing would be if you ran through a bunch of posts just to remove "Thanks" at the end and nothing else (regardless of whose posts they were). Not sure if the tag should be updated to include this scenario or not.

Comment: @honk Last I checked having a lot of rep doesn't give you permission to violate the rules.  I'd be pretty surprised for any mod to give that as an explanation, and if they did, just call *them* on that, because that's not at all okay for them to do.

Comment: @BSMP "Serial editing" is sometimes used as a shorthand for "serial minor edits" or "serial low quality edits", with the problem being implied from context, but there is still such a thing as "serial good edits" (which can still have some problems, by the way, although obviously no nearly to the same level as serial bad edits).

Comment: @BSMP I was thinking along the same line as Servy, and was not referring to bad serial-edits. I thought this question can fall into the category of "making a lot of the same kind of edits/suggestions to many posts in a relatively short time frame," since all of the user's posts likely have the same kind of problems.

Comment: Ha! I say knock yourself out. I volunteer all of my posts. Feel free to edit as you please.

Comment: You can but you don't need to target a user specifically. Searching for ["Cheerios"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Cheerios%22) is better than searching for ["Cheerios" user:1210059](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Cheerios%22+user%3A1210059).

Comment: @honk I've taken your advice and left a comment under one of the answers I edited, explaining the reason for the edits, and asking the user if the many edits bother them. I don't know if it always makes sense to leave a comment in such a situation, but I've decided to try this time. I'm hoping this will help the user understand the edits are for the good, and at the same time learn what to avoid when writing new answers in the future.

Comment: @Cœur Although I asked this question after editing one user's posts, this question is not specifically about that user. I've come across other users like this before, and didn't single out anyone on purpose. And the problem isn't just specific keywords. Many times posts are just consistently not formatted or written well. (Once you mention searching for "Cheerios" though, I will point out that [[cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cheerio/info)] is a valid tag, so you would want to [refine your search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Cheerios%22+-%5Bcheerio%5D) to exclude that tag.)

Comment: Feel free to target me.  I am always happy when someone reformats posts and makes them look decent.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**No, there is absolutely nothing wrong with going through a user's posts and correcting recurring problems.** This is not "targeting" in any negative sense; it doesn't harm the user in any way to have their posts improved. In fact, it helps them, and not uniquely them, but the entire site.

That said, you need to fix *all* the problems with the post, not just one or two things. This is a basic rule of edits, though, so I suspect you just omitted it because it is so obvious. Still, it's worth emphasizing. There was recently a concern raised on Meta about the [misuse of formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355183/are-edits-which-decorate-the-post-with-markdown-good). I would encourage you to go through and fix offending posts, whether they come from the same user or not, but I would also encourage you to make your edits *count*. So, don't just go through and mass-fix blockquote formatting. Consider and edit the post as a whole.

The real "con" to this is one that you didn't mention—a bunch of edits in a short time can be very disruptive. Edits "bump" the post, putting the associated question in the "interesting" queue, which many of our answerers use to find questions to answer. If you bump a bunch of old, answered questions by editing them, it can make it more difficult for them to find questions to answer. This is another good reason to make your edits count (see above), and also a reason why you should spread them out over a bit larger period of time (which will naturally occur if you're making each of them count).

As for your stated con:

> **Con:** A big reason why I see not to do this, is that the user might not like if another user suddenly changes all their posts. They also may think the editor is serial-editing for the wrong reason.

This isn't really a problem. Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited, so other users are *encouraged* to clean up posts, provided that they respect the intent of the original author. Fixing formatting, spelling, and grammar mistakes is not violating the intent of the author, so this is fair game. If someone has a problem with this, point them to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

You're right that you might get accused of editing for the wrong reasons, but this is, again, spurious. If you're doing as I advised and making your edits count, then you are absolutely *not* editing for the "wrong reasons"—you are editing for the *right* reasons. Yes, as long as you have [<2k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you are getting credit for your edits, but (A) your edits are subject to review by the community and will be rejected if they're invalid, and (B) you *deserve* credit for your edits if your edits are actually useful. That's why we award it in the first place.

As ever, leaving a quality edit summary can help to alleviate problems. First of all, if your edits are subject to peer review, it can help your edits get approved. Even if you have full editing privileges, these serve an instructional purpose to the original author, explaining to them *why* you saw fit to make the edit. It doesn't always happen, but sometimes people really do learn from this and stop making the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to editing all problems. Like by the example I gave in my question, "In addition to the unneeded fluff in the posts, the posts were disorganized and hard to read." I was planning on fixing all of the mentioned issues. And don't you mean <2k rep users get credit for edits, not <3k?

Comment: I wrote the answer "for the ages", not just for you, @Tot. And yes, you're right. Editing privileges are gained at 2k rep. I can never remember all those darn numbers.

Comment: The benefits of being closer to the 2k mark :) And yes, I agree that your point adds a sense of completeness to the answer and actually liked that you included it. I just added my comment to clarify in case my intentions weren't completely clear from my question.

Comment: It always seems strange and surprising that high-rep users don't always remember the points where privileges are gained (and even more surprisingly when they forget some actions are rep-restricted, like close-voting or directly editing!), but you have to remember that it might have been many years since high-rep users gained those privileges, and they may have been on the site early enough in its life to not have even noticed that they gained them.

Comment: @Clonkex Yep, it's been approximately 6 - 8 weeks since Cody Gray last earned a new privilege. :-)

Comment: @Clonkex Many users aren't interested in moderating the site at first.  Many of the people that spend a lot of time and effort moderating the site *now* started out focusing on answering, not moderating (which is by design).  For many users by the time they've developed an interest in moderation they've already earned many, or even all, of the privileges for moderation.  So it may not even be that it's been a long time since they were without the permissions, but rather that there was never a time where they were interested in using those features and didn't have them.

Comment: @CodyGray Great answer +1 and and good post @Tot  I am guilty at times, of many times of this, `:)` I have replied to @TotZam here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396913/how-to-show-russian-text-in-jquery-dialog-title/10396966?noredirect=1#comment78533619_10396966 working on it, but again, great answer. It will be great if we keep my comments so people from similar thoughts learn, or possibly understand the point of view. SO is amazing, and like any community a very inclusive. Working on it and will gradually convince myself to be less saluting.

Comment: What's wrong with atomic edits that only target target one of several problems with a post?

Answer (score -4):

Personally, I do feel there's something wrong with targeting a user. In real life, you also wouldn't single someone out for criticism, even when they legitimately and honestly asked for it.

You correct/criticize/feedback people, take a break, give them time to breathe and then they can incorporate what was said.

This stuff needs to be dosed.

Comment: I don't know if I would consider improving all of a user's posts at once the same as singling them out for criticism. It's more that someone for some reason decided to spend time specifically helping them. Some users might find that annoying, but based on the comments above, it seems like many will just be thankful for the help. Also, I have a feeling that just leaving feedback for a user will majority of the time just be ignored. They might learn from it and use the ideas when writing posts in the future, but they very likely will not go back and fix all their old posts.

Comment: This would be true if you were leaving comments consisting of constructive criticism—a little goes a long way. I don't think it's true when you're doing the work yourself to improve their answers.

Comment: @CodyGray but how do you know that person perceives it as improving their answers? That's an extremely positive way of looking at it, and I don't think everybody (or even most people) would feel it like that.

Comment: I suppose you're right. I have a hard time imagining why someone would *not* view this as a positive thing, though. It is part and parcel of how the site is designed. But I'm willing to admit I am very biased.

Comment: @CodyGray OK imagine the following. I'm a software developer and I'm a minority. All posts of the last month are edited. How do I feel?

Comment: @BartvanKuik What does being a minority have to do with someone helping to improve your posts?

Answer (score -7):

I would like to drop in an opinion as a person that over the years have written dozens of "hope that helps" in the answers, and has just received an edit like the author posted.

**I would find it scaring and offensive** if someone would go over all my posts and edit them. For me it looks like "it was Ok the whole time, now suddenly I am wrong and they are going to chase me for what I was doing and was sure I was doing the right thing".

I understand that times change, so do policies, and I really like that StackOverflow is "polished" by editors (fixed grammar is easier to read, same for decent code formatting, it is so important). When I started contributing, there were often not so good answers, many of them not being really in-depth and trying to solve the issue of the poster. So I took it as a habit to end the answer with "hope that helps", which would remind me that I always try to give as complete answer as possible and fit it to the original question as much as possible.

I can see how it is redundant, and future SO will be better off without such "personal touch".

Just before you go and touch (I wanted to write "butcher", but this would have been too radical for such an edit) years of contributions of a user, I propose that you give that person a notice. Do the first edit, saying "this is better than  that because X, I noticed you have more posts like this, I will be editing them in the following days, please don't worry".

P.S. It is also funny that I have never encountered such edits, looks like it was a good practice to remove such post endings in 2017 already, when this question was asked.

Comment: It was *never* OK. Since the very beginning of Stack Overflow, the kind of thing you describe has been inappropriate. Unfortunately, there's no way we can stop everyone from breaking the rules. There simply aren't enough moderators or quality-minded users to achieve 100% enforcement. But when we do find a problem, we generally do go about fixing it, so you should definitely expect a large number of your answers to be edited. Just like when you clean up a spill, you wipe the rest of the counter, too. There's never a reason to *discuss* edits; that's just more noise, which we also discourage.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok thanks for letting me know. I completely missed this. May you link some guideline page, so I could inform myself?

Comment: @CodyGray I think I understand what SO wants to achieve here. But it is like to set rules to forces of nature, like water. It was never Ok for water to flood villages, but water cannot be stopped, villages should be built accordingly. People build dams and use the power of water, but no-one can tell water what to do. Same with the flood of people's answers etc. I am thankful for the community for letting me know, I wish I knew this before. (Responses even looked rude to me because of that actually. My own impression but still.)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings." There are also numerous Meta posts about this precise issue, but I don't feel like searching for and linking all of them here. I don't know if you're saying that trying to set rules for the behavior of users is like trying to stop the flow of water, but I have to disagree with that. As you've seen, Stack Overflow gives users the tool for enforcement of these rules, which is simply editing the unwanted portion out of posts. It's a very practical solution, with no mess or fuss.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, spot on!