# Is it bad form to edit multiple questions from another user's page for reputation?

Tags: discussion, edits, serial-editing

A few days ago, I read a question I was interested in, and I noticed it could be edited for clarity. Then I noticed that person had responded to their own question, and I was able to provide meaningful edits, too.

Now my question is: this person was likely a non-native speaker with a good amount of reputation, which seemed well earned. So it occurred to me that maybe I could look into their old questions and edit them for reputation.

There are some obvious downsides. This person may feel followed or worse. They may get sick of the edits. And it's a pretty obvious potential reputation grab. Not a huge one, with the limits on reputation for edits, but enough, even though I want to make sure they are substantial.

On the other hand, they (and others who read their questions) may appreciate someone cleaning up the stuff that might just be a time sink to get perfect.

I've had good experiences helping proofread useful documentation for software packages written by people whose first language was not English. It helps me learn more than if I'd waste time elsewhere, and the other person gets some help. This is clearly win-win.

But editing even two of someone's posts this feels potentially like walking into someone's house. And yet there's the possibility it could be helpful, so I wanted to pose the questions.

Comment: It's usually better not to target users in any way. But if the edits are undisputedly good, I see no harm.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with trying to make things better.  Just be aware that new users often see edits to their content as hostile, and may sometimes react accordingly.

Comment: I think fixing all the posts on a page is fair game, even if a user has more than one post on that page. You came by those posts organically and it's easy for someone to see that you just edited what you saw on that page. Going through a specific user's posts has the potential to make them upset. (Some users would welcome this but there's no way to know unless you ask in chat.) If the user is no longer active on the site you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Personally, I would be against it. The user could experience this as you specifically picking on/making fun of his English. Moderating specific users is risky business.

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355232/is-it-wrong-to-target-edit-a-single-users-posts), although this is a bit different, as the question here is if rep-farming is a bad motivation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the community is divided on serial editing in general. If you do it, I would say space your edits out on a user so they do not have to review much in one go, and do it for quality and not for rep. I can't speak for mods, but I think there is an official tolerance for serial editing, as long as it is of good quality, and in edge cases - if a user really lashes out - the editor is willing to reduce their focus on one user upon mod request.

Comment: @BSMP your comment looks like a valid answer to me.

Comment: My personal take: new content rolls in that needs editing constantly, you don't need to resort to serial editing to grab your reputation points. If you don't have another reason to do this then don't do it.

Comment: If in doubt, you could always ask the user in a comment on one of their posts **before** starting the series. E.g. "*Hi @aschultz, do you mind if I [fix this mistake|improve English grammar] in your other posts as well?*".

Comment: I think it's fine to do it on *new* questions/answers or unanswered questions, if the edit is valid (not just adding unnecessary code formatting or alike)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can fix all the problems with a question and its answers in one go, that's fine, even if it involves editing multiple posts from the same user (as it just makes sense and also minimizes bumping). There is no ethical problem with "serial editing" a single user's posts, even for reputation. Do you really think you're raking in the rep when it's only +2 for each approved edit (with a max of +1000)? People take issue with people who do terrible edits.

However, there can be another problem: each and every edit you make will notify the owner of the post. In this case, the author will be notified that there was a suggested edit in case they want to review it. If the review was completed by others, they are still shown the notification in case they want to dispute the decision. Some people won't be bothered by many edit notifications, but others will.

In general, that's why I consider it better form (or at least it's easier) to edit based off something other than who owns the post. (For example, many of the edits I've been making lately have been to fix links.) There really is no shortage of stuff that could use an edit.

Answer (score 7):

No, I don't think this is bad behavior. [Serial up/downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) is bad because it unfairly increases/decreases the author's reputation, and you're voting based on who wrote the post rather than how good or bad it actually is (and that rarely comes with a positive outcome).

Serial edit-suggesting someone doesn't come with either of those problems. You're not increasing the post author's reputation at all, and editing doesn't change the score, which is often what people look to when determining the quality of a post. Additionally, suggesting good edits is actively helpful to the site on pretty much any post.

So yeah, I think it's fine to serial edit someone's posts.

Comment: I'm mainly on the careful-serial-editing side of the fence, but I wonder if this does not take account of the OP's specific question, which is serial editing for reputation?

Comment: @halfer in this case I don't think it really matters if it's being done for the reputation or to improve the site. As long as the edits are good, then it should be fine.

Comment: I've certainly seen people editing for rep in general (e.g. adding inappropriate code formatting on proper nouns). Certainly, the rep did not cause the lack of editing ability `:-)` but it might have encouraged someone to be an editor when they are not suited to the task. I don't feel strongly about it, but I wonder if there is a parallel with serial-editing for rep also.