# Change quote formatting to show double-quote marks

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering

Quote markdown currently renders as a kind of banner:

> Like this, and with a yellow background on the main site.

This has led posters and editors to use it for emphasis. People don't seem to realize that it has a specific meaning—that it means "quoted text".

If posters and editors don't realize this, then we can safely assume that casual visitors don't know this, either.

I propose that we add explicit double-quote marks to this formatting. Like this:

[image: " ... "]

...but perhaps with the double-quote marks inside the gray box.

([Source](https://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-quotation-marks.htm) of picture, found via Google search for "opening double quote".)

With big double quotes in or around the banner, it should be more clear that something is a quote.

For the record, I am aware that Stack Exchange did not create markdown and that they are just using it. This feature request would probably require some customizations.

Comment: I don't think it would require any changes to markdown. The syntax would remain the same; all that we would be changing is the rendering.

Comment: I think people _do_ realise it has a specific meaning. They just choose to use it for other reasons. Does it really matter?

Comment: @Turnip If the meaning of the formatting isn't clear, then it does matter. Some posters and editors might deliberately abuse formatting. But I think many of them do it out of ignorance.

Comment: If you want a new quote markdown ask for that, you don't want to make changes to the current quote markdown that then makes all the old posts that use it "incorrectly" actually use it incorrectly. If I'm using it for emphasis and this change comes in it then looks like I'm quoting when I'm not, it needs to be a a new addition not retroactively.

Comment: I don't like nor design, nor the idea. We have limited amount of formatting options to compose good looking question/answer and there are always individuals, trying to look differently (when I was young I was replaying with red cursive text in my emails). The proposal will not change that, nor I like design (mentioned it early), so why bother? Did I mentioned I don't like design?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't think the many are doing it out of ignorance I think they're _deliberately abusing formatting_ (as you put it, not that I believe this to be an issue), as `>` is pretty universally known as markdown for a quote and if they use the button on the text editor to add them, it's quite literally a quotation symbol.

Comment: @Sinatr `The proposal will not change anything, so why bother?`: If you don't ask, you don't get...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: *"If I'm using it for emphasis and this change comes in it then looks like I'm quoting when I'm not,"* It **already** looks like that. (But I'm not in favor of this change either.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know it does but some people think it looks like a heading or just anything to emphasise a bit of text. Was just a point against changing something that will have consequences on old uses.

Comment: Just so all of the commentators are clear, using blockquote formatting for things that are not quotations is an abuse of the formatting options and is not allowed, even if you think it "looks good". That holds true whether we change the rendering or not. It has the *semantic* meaning of quotation, and should thus be reserved only for when you are actually quoting something. That could be an external resource, or it could be an error message, but **blockquote formatting should *not* be used for emphasis** under any circumstances. Use bold for that, and headings for headings.

Comment: @CodyGray, that may be so and I'm mostly in agreement with you there; but error messages between quotation marks would look silly to me.

Answer (score 11):

How would quotations from complex documents be handled? For example:

> ### §3.2 Foo syntax rules
>
> When *foo* is used with *bar*<sup>(123</sup>, you must:
>
> 1. fsdf dsf
> 2. fkkdsf  födslkföds
>
> <sub>(123 If *bar* not *baz*, then sdaflksdajfldsj.</sub>

For this kind of quotations, extra marks may lead to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: This could easily be solved by adding just 1 (semi transparant) quote to the top right of said block.

Answer (score 6):

If we want `<blockquote>` to be used correctly, something like this is necessary. Until this morning, I had no idea that anybody cared.

However, I think the design could be improved.

Using the example text from [user694733's](/users/694733/user694733) [answer](/a/355287/5764553):

[image]

The inner blockquotes could even lose the quotation marks (since it's on the outer one already.

[image]

Here it is live:

```css
/* #override is being used to override all the standard styling */

#override blockquote {
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
  position: relative;
}

#override blockquote:before {
  content: '\0201C';
  font-size: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.8rem;
  top: -1rem;
  color: #c8ccd0;
}

#override blockquote.alt blockquote {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#override blockquote.alt blockquote:before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="override" class="post-text" itemprop="text">
  <p>Here is some text from <a href="/users/694733/user694733">user694733's</a> <a href="/a/355287/5764553">answer</a>:</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>How would quotations from complex documents be handled? For example:</p>

    <blockquote>
      <h2>§3.2 Foo syntax rules</h2>

      <p>When <em>foo</em> is used with <em>bar</em><sup>(123</sup>, you must:</p>

      <ol>
        <li>fsdf dsf</li>
        <li>fkkdsf födslkföds </li>
      </ol>

      <p><sub>(123 If <em>bar</em> not <em>baz</em>, then sdaflksdajfldsj. </sub></p>
    </blockquote>

    <p>For this kind of quotations, extra marks may lead to unnecessary confusion.</p>
  </blockquote>
  
  <p>The inner blockquotes could even lose the quotation marks (since it's on the outer one already.</p>
  
  <blockquote class="alt">
    <p>My old friend Howland had a saying:</p>
    <blockquote>
      <p>Stop quoting me or I'll...</p>
      <p><sub>&mdash;Howland, <em>The Complete Works of Howland</em></sub></p>
    </blockquote>
  </blockquote>

  <p>And just for good measure, a one-liner:</p>

  <blockquote><p>Hey, where's my attribution?</p></blockquote>
</div>

<style>
/********************************************************\
 * The following CSS was created and is owned by
 * Stack Overflow. I am using it here only to
 * show an example of changing that formatting.
\********************************************************/
  
  body {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #242729;
  }
  
  div,
  h2,
  p,
  blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  
  .post-text {
    width: 660px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }
  
  p {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  blockquote {
    background-color: #eff0f1;
    border-left: 2px solid #c8ccd0;
  }
  
  blockquote {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  ol,
  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
  }
  
  ol {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  
  .post-text h2 {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .post-text ol li {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
  }
  
  sub,
  sup {
    font-size: 80%;
    vertical-align: sub;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  
  sup,
  sub {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  
  i,
  em {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  sup {
    vertical-align: super;
  }
  
  blockquote *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #3b4045;
    color: #C91D2E;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  a:hover, a:active {
    color: #9c1724;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
```

Note that this is using a pseudo `::before` element to add the quotes. This means that they will **not** be selectable if somebody tries to copy the quoted material.

---

As an addendum, it might be good to consider extending markdown to have an `<aside>` or `<p class="highlight">`. I think a lot of people abused the `<blockquote>` because they needed something that would display that way. Of course, this would be a lot more work than merely altering some CSS.