# Why was my flag for the use of "blockquote" declined from a repeat offender?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

The flag in question:

> I asked the OP to remove the blockquote quite some time ago and they failed to update their post to remove it.

For the following post was declined:

- [How to create a simple star rating with span or ul li using css and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637728/how-to-create-a-simple-star-rating-with-span-or-ul-li-using-css-and-jquery)

Where the OP used a blockquote for "I do not want to use javascript I want it in jquery.".

as:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I flagged many similar posts like this where they were all found as being helpful **and edited by moderators**. So why was this one declined?

The use of blockquote has been discussed on meta:

- [Are **edits** which `decorate` the post with > markdown good?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355183/1415724)

Am I/we to no longer flag those or am I left it to chance?

---

**Edit:**

For the record, I also flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46645978/1415724) (10k+) by the same person and I also posted the same comment under it to remove the blockquote. I need to note that the note that I left for it, was borrowed from a moderator's reply to one of my past flags.

That flag was found helpful probably because they deleted the post before moderator intervention happened, so that's where the confusion lies here.

**The OP was a repeating offender** and clearly **ignored my comment** under their [still existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46637728/1415724).

The timestamps prove it:

Deleted post: "asked Oct 9 at 12:01".
Not deleted/existing post (flagged): "asked Oct 9 at 1:35".

Comment: Just curious, you have 2k+ rep, so you could have edited that out yourself. Why didn't you?

Comment: @NisargShah that isn't the point and isn't my/our job.

Comment: I mean, you could have converted it into normal text - rather than blockquote. It is definitely an improvement, so I suppose you are allowed to do that.

Comment: It isn't the moderator's job either. If you want it changed, change it, if it's not important enough to you to change it then nobody's going to make you, nor are they going to do it for you.

Comment: @RobertLongson moderators are supposed to "moderate"  and to me that means to either inform the OP or to enforce in the discouragement in using blockquote. This question isn't getting the right audience here.

Comment: I didn't handle that flag but reading it here I don't get from your description of: *I asked the OP to remove the blockquote quite some time ago and they failed to update their post to remove it.* - what you'd expect me to do that you couldn't from that if I'd come across it in the queue...

Comment: Pretty sure blockquotes are not either [evil, nor are they particularly weird](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: @JonClements I used practically the same description for the other flagged posts. That's what I don't get. Obviously, moderation is of many colours so it seems and not just "black or white".

Comment: @Fred-ii- if it was entirely black and white we could program the system to do it :p

Comment: My understanding of mods is that they are error-handlers: there to handle what the normal system can't handle by default. The normal edit system would have been more than enough here, so there was no value in flagging a mod. I do get the confusion that stems from this if, in the past, such flags were successful though :/....

Comment: @JonClements Thing is Jon, this matter is gaining momentum and is getting more problematic and I've seen other posts lately where I posted that same comment and they removed it; great. Those are the good guys. The matter was brought up on meta, so what am I to do then? Ok, I may be able to answer that. Either ask them (politely) as I have, edit it, or downvote it. So, I won't flag those anymore and just leave it to others to do their dirty work. I should probably be posting this comment as my own answer.

Comment: so scrap that meta post then https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355183/1415724 right?

Comment: This strikes me as exactly the petty thing that normal users should be handling themselves. I'm not senior on the site, but I don't think I'd want mods wasting their time on stuff like this. I think the inconsistency and the fact that the others were accepted is more surprising than this one being denied.

Comment: @JonClements I think you moderators should all sit down together and talk about this one. I'm sure you'll find a few that agree with me on this one.

Comment: Asking someone else to edit something you think needs editing is as rude as asking for teh codez.

Comment: *"is as rude"* - @Will huh??

Comment: I fail to understand why you actually flagged to have the post edited as you don't seem to have trouble [editing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Am I missing some loops in your reasoning that are obvious to others or do you assume we all have prior knowledge that only evades me at the moment? Care to fill me in on the gaps I'm missing?

Comment: @rene *"I fail to understand why you actually flagged to have the post edited"* - Did my flag say: *"I want you moderators to edit that out (please)"*. **A: No.**

Comment: "I can easily do this thing, but I want you to do it for me instead." People actually do tend to think that attitude is rude.  In case you don't understand that's what we see when we read that flag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm really totally lost in your question then. Be happy I discarded my answer. What did you expect as the outcome? What should the mod do/have done. The fact that the mod edited the post based on your flag was a fortunate side-effect?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Like others I don't understand either why you flagged that post. Does it have something to do because you think the guys who edited their posts as per your suggestion are good guys and the other are bad? If yes, that is incorrect logic. The person might not understand the intent behind your comment, the person might have missed your comment, the person might have been busy when they read your comment...Why attribute something to bad intent while it could easily have been a mistake?

Comment: *"What should the mod do/have done. The fact that the mod edited the post based on your flag was a fortunate side-effect?"* - I expected a moderator who should discourage the use of blockquoting to at the very least advise the offending OP and marking the flag as helpful, which in turn would have at least kind of let me know that something was done about it. Moderators can leave an added note in flags, as other mods have done before for the same type of problem/flag. That's what I don't get here.

Comment: I see. I would personally never use a flag to achieve what you managed to get passed through the mod-queue before. But it needs the mod who declined your flag to respond. We can only guess why they did so and give advice on how we would handle the situation you faced and flagged which seemed odd to me. Sorry for the interrogation.

Comment: @rene Right and that is the person for whom I am waiting for and should be answering to. No need to be sorry, you needed to ask questions for clarification and I've given it; least I hope I have.

Comment: I would never do anything other than edit and post a comment asking the OP to stop. If they continue to repeatedly do this, then maybe eventually a flag is in order.

Comment: @Pekka웃 *"If they continue to repeatedly do this"* - To which they were a repeat offender https://stackoverflow.com/q/46645978/1415724 (10k+). The flagged question `asked Oct 9 at 1:35` the one I posted here in the link `asked Oct 9 at 12:01` which the post was deleted and completely ignored that comment "also".

Comment: @Fred-ii- So first, and most importantly, if you're flagging something because you've noticed a pattern of behavior, and it's the larger pattern you want the mod to deal with, not the one instance *you need to say that in the flag*.  When you flag just says that this one post needs to be edited, the mod isn't going to read your mind and realize you're concerned about a pattern of behavior.  Next, this is a super minor issue, and I wouldn't even say a pattern of *this particular* behavior merits moderator intervention.  Finally, even if it *would*, it'd need more of a pattern than just twice.

Comment: Like Servy, I'm not sure I would flag *this* particular pattern, but there sure are related patterns where folks need their butts kicked (like mass editing posts to turn abbreviations, product names etc. into `block quotes`). Those absolutely need flagging.

Comment: For the record, if a user was editing *someone else's* posts and injecting improper formatting I'd be much more concerned than the author simply not formatting their own post incorrectly from the start.  I'd probably just fix it the first time I saw it, but if it happened again, or they rolled back the fix, *that* would be the kind of thing that would merit moderator action.

Comment: @Servy would you consider to convert your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358740/why-was-my-flag-for-the-use-of-blockquote-declined-from-a-repeat-offender#comment528098_358740) to answer as it actually provide proper course of action that should been taken in this case.

Comment: The key here is that there's nothing a moderator can really do to *escalate* this that you cannot do as a normal user. You have the same editing privileges and commenting privileges that we do. As annoying as this is, misuse of formatting is honestly not something that we'd suspend a user for. The only *possible* thing a mod can do that you can't is leave a comment with a diamond attached. In my experience, users don't give a hoot. Many of my diamond-adorned comments are ignored and/or disputed by the users I'm trying to correct. Also, what @Servy said—that'd be an appropriate case for a flag.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The proper course of action here is to either edit the post, or to do nothing, and there are already three answers saying that, we don't need a fourth.

Answer (score 35):

You're given the power to edit.  If you feel like edits should happen, feel empowered to take that action.

If you don't want to do it, you definitely don't have to.  No one is going to force you to edit content if you vehemently don't want to do it.

Moderators are only meant to step in when we *can't*.  Editing content like this is *well* under our control, so moderators would not see any reason to intervene.

Answer (score 34):

I declined that flag, for the reasons stated by many people above. There was no need for direct moderator intervention, because you could have edited that post yourself.

This also illustrates why being generous and marking flags as helpful can sometimes send the wrong signal. Another moderator marked your earlier flags as helpful, probably to try to be friendly, and that led you to flag more posts like this rather than editing them yourself. By trying to be generous with the flags, it encouraged the wrong kind of behavior. Declining this most recent flag was intended to nudge you in the direction of handling these edits yourself.

If more abusive behavior was involved, such as a rollback war around formatting, or someone spamming suggested edits that inject this kind of formatting, that's when a moderator flag would make sense. We don't need to intervene in the case of a lone poorly-formatted question, and we leave that to the community to handle. There aren't enough of moderators to edit everything the community does every day.

Comment: Please see my edit Brad.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use flags for this. As stated in comments, you are a 2Ker and can edit it yourself probably faster than you could raise that flag.

Additionally, previous flags being helpful do NOT justify it. Rules change, moderators change, and focus can waver or rise. I've had a similar experience flagging verbatim duplicate answers. They were "helpful" for a while. Then one was declined with a reason. I stopped flagging them.

Comment: Even if you *don't* have 2k rep, you can *still* suggest an edit to the post, and that's the appropriate way of indicating that you think an edit (like this) should be made, not flagging the post.

Comment: @Servy though it's worth noting that a trivial edit like the one mentioned in the question wouldn't meet the 6-character requirement.

Comment: There are plenty of things that merit editing in that post.  You'd have no problem constructing an appropriate suggested edit for it.

Comment: Verbatim duplicate answers get auto-flagged by the system (at least when they're by the same user), so there's no reason for you to flag them.

Comment: @CodyGray exactly, and I didn't know that until one of my flags was declined.

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't decline a flag for that reason. The flag was raised in good faith, and was correct/helpful, so I'd go ahead and mark it as "helpful". I'd just fill in a custom message indicating that the flag is superfluous and the system auto-flags these things for us. Although, the problem with that is users don't usually *read* these flag disposition messages unless the system forces them to do so, and that only happens when you have a flag declined. I guess that echoes right back to what your answer says.