# Is it wrong to add images in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, images

I bumped into a question where [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128523/2828434) was downvoted and a comment was written by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) as "Please, No Images". When I opened the profile of that user, it was written "SOreadytohelp", and this user has quite a high reputation. This means it wasn't an abrupt downvote nor a careless comment.

This drew me to ask here whether it is really incorrect to add images in answer?

Comment: Pure text is a **lot** better.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: @paper1111 It surely can, but can that become a candidate for downvote or an explicit comment? *I feel that an image in answer limits OP's tendency of copy pasting code and use it directly esp if it is one line mysql query*

Comment: @Pang Thanks, but just to clarify, *that* link ask about images in **questions**

Comment: Well we can't explain downvotes. They are anonymous, and you can downvote a perfectly good answer if you have enough rep.

Comment: The items in Pang's shared answer applies to answers too.

Comment: If it is strictly discouraged, then isn't it better to not allow option to add image in **Answers** altogether?

Comment: @KaranDesai you may want to post screenshots of UI, for example see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903810/7347933)

Comment: Some additional info can be found here http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 12):

Images of code or other text are bad. Text should be included as plain text—no exceptions.

Other images that serve to illustrate your point are fine.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not incorrect to add images but only if these images support the answer. That is, just like it is with links to off-site resources, the answer itself should contain all the content to be considered an answer to the question.

The commenter is in their right to show their non appreciation of these images. It might also explain the down vote.

In that specific answer I really wonder if it was easier for the OP to make the screenshot, clip it to the right size and upload it to Imgur as opposed to simply select the resultset in their terminal, paste it in the answer, select it and hit Ctrl+K to format it.

Comment: Probably one of the motivations is SO's refusal to provide proper support for presenting tabular data. The workaround is to use something like this https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ but that doesn't work correctly when displayed on mobile.