# Review suspension for using "requires editing" after edit has been made

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

I got a review suspension because I voted for "Requires Editing" on *triage/26950302*.

**Conclusion:**

Thanks for the answer. I now understand it is really "forbidden" and not just discouraged to post pictures of code/console output/errors. I also understand that the escalation is not "look ok" -> "requires editing" -> "unsalvageable" as the LTR order indicates but "unsalvageable" -> "requires editing" -> "looks ok" to be more rigid to low quality posts.

**Question (you can stop reading here - resolved):**

When the post was created you can see from history it looked like this:

[image]

In my opinion, this clearly needs editing to correctly inline the image, remove unneeded punctuation, and so on as it matched these criteria:

> The "Requires Editing" action should only be used when other community
> users (like yourself) are able to improve an answerable question with
> editing or formatting.

I voted on this 6 hours ago:

[image]

2 hours ago it WAS edited by someone (obviously I was not that wrong with my assumption):

[image]

And now, 1 hour ago I got review suspended again for using "requires editing" wrong.

After my latest suspension, I'm totally aware that requires editing should be used when the post can be improved by someone editing it (which obviously was done).

But why am I again suspended?! The reason why I voted for requires editing was clearly not given at the time I got suspended because it has been edited in the meantime. If one only gets banned from using "requires editing" just remove the option because it's useless if you get banned AFTER the post has been already changed.

I'd really like to understand why I'm been suspended again and why voting the way I did was wrong in the opinion of the moderator. Unfortunately, getting banned does not help the slightest in understanding the reason.

EDIT:

To be clear, I did not vote on "requires editing" because I think someone should transcribe the image (as some commenters think). This should clearly be done by the creator but because there are other problems with the post. From the link @BDL gave me, points 1,2 & 4 apply under these circumstances. From the general perspective, the output itself as an image is "ok-ish" in my opinion and just the code needs to be added "as code" which OP could do after being asked to do it as a comment.

If any picture containing "Text" is forbidden and the question therefore by default faulty, this should be mentioned for the "requires editing" button.

Comment: The question was edited, but “requires editing” was the wrong choice for that question. Remember: that option is for posts that are otherwise fine, but could use some polish.

Comment: "This should clearly be done by the creator but because there are other problems with the post." - Which means the question cannot be salvaged.  You selected the wrong option based on your own explanation.  **The question was beyond any hope of the community polishing the question into something that could be salvaged.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Requires editing" may only be chosen when the question needs editing **but is already on-topic**. When the question needs editing but is still close worthy after the edit, then you should have voted to close.

Even with the edit applied, this specific post is off-topic because it contains the code and errors only as image instead of text. [Transcribing text from images is something the original author should do, not some random editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code).

About whether the question should be closed: As others have pointed out, there are two pages which talk about posting images of code instead of text:

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which states:

> **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**

and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12695027)

Comment: I did not vote to edited because I think someone should transcribe the image. This should clearly be done by the creator but because there are other problems with the post. From the link you gave, points 1,2 & 4 apply under this circumstances. From the general perspective, the output itself as the image is "ok-ish" in my opinion and just the code needs to be added "as code" which OP could do after being asked to do it as a comment.

Comment: @Alex: "just the code needs to be added" is already enough to close the question. See it as escalation levels: 1. Is it unsalvagable? Only if the answer is no, then 2. Does it need editing. It doesn't make sense to let people edit questions which will be closed anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I see. So it is really "forbidden" and not just discouraged to post pictures of code. I understand this now.

Comment: @Alex: Yeah, sorry, I should have explained this in first place. Though the confusion came from having two option which apply (unsalvageable and requires edit).