# Question sabotage?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

My question keeps getting closed, again and again:
*[Firebase Notifications targeting Android phone fail to show in system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390937/firebase-notifications-targeting-android-phone-fail-to-show-in-system-tray)*

I believe it's a pretty valid question and other community members couldn't tell me *why* this is happening.

Comment: [As far as I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63390937/revisions) it was closed *once*. If you mean you posted the same question several times and each time it got closed, it's not clear why you'd expect otherwise.

Comment: It was only closed once, and never reopened. What do you mean "again and again"?

Comment: I mean I edited it again and over. Same result.

Comment: @user1001895 right, but then the correct language is: *I’ve edited it several times but it hasn’t been reopened*. Your post was already closed, editing it doesn’t reopen it automatically.

Answer (score 42):

Perhaps English is not your native language, but calling it "sabotage" when one of your questions is closed comes across as extreme hyperbole. Please don’t use that term. Users on Stack Overflow are encouraged to close questions that they believe to be off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for this site as part of content moderation.

Furthermore, as others have said, your claim that your question "keeps getting closed, again and again" is also incorrect. That is the only question you have asked—deleted or not—that has ever been closed, and [it was only closed once, not multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63390937/revisions).

Getting down to specifics, [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390937/firebase-notifications-targeting-android-phone-fail-to-show-in-system-tray) was correctly closed. [The original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63390937/1) did not even come *close* to meeting our basic requirements for a question. In particular, you are asking for help debugging a problem with some code, yet you have failed to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem in the body of the question itself.

The big blue banner that appears above your question when closed tells you clearly what the problem with the question is, so you have, in fact, been told why this is happening.

You have since edited your question to include one tiny snippet of code from the manifest, but no other code that would be necessary to reproduce the problem. You have also included a *giant* screenshot, but [screenshots of text are inappropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

You should continue making edits to your question that will bring it into compliance with [our minimum requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Once this goal is achieved, your question will be eligible to be re-opened and answered.