# Recommendation on extracting tabular data from images embedded in questions?

Tags: discussion

I have come across few questions having a snapshot of database query output or excel data attached to the question. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Close as needs details or Needs debugging details

Comment: Vote to close as no MCVE if the data is essential to the question and is not presented in text format. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Sure, sometimes questions are so good, do we need ask to convert into text format and re-post? Just a thought !

Comment: The OP should do the conversion and we should close the question till they do said conversion.

Comment: use paperport or any other ocr, but the quality of the image are often bad, so that you have to edit data manually, if there are too may images close the questiosn asking for Details

Comment: I am currently using `https://extracttable.com/`

Comment: @HereticMonkey,my question is - not to upload text-data as image, it is difficult to get the textual content for any replication required in the query/code !

Comment: Right... and the answers to that question explain exactly what the comments here explain, that the OP must edit their question to provide the data/code/errors in text format. Other people should not do it, because they are liable to screw something up in the translation. The OP, who has direct access to the data in question, should be able to directly copy, from the source, the data in question and paste it into the post.

Comment: @HereticMonkey we have in mysql sometimes users that are not able to give actual text data. but simple tablea re extratcted as i already wrote in my comment

Comment: @nbk I struggle to understand how a user can take a screenshot of data, but be unable to copy and paste the same data as text... Or even if we let that slide, how is it they are unable to use the same software or services to extract the data themselves? Or, horror of horrors, type the data in manually?

Comment: most nnewbies are unfamiliar with the software or follow some tutorial that doesn't expalin the basecs, but simple screenshots can take anyone. a comment is not the place to explain to the user how to extract data from their output or programm. as i said  a screenshot is easy and so the the first choice. But we need to input data into the appropriate programm and don't want to have to extra work load of getting the data in a good manner, so they are closed and get asked for details