# Feature Test: Ask Wizard for New Users (trial has completed)

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, ask-question-wizard

##### This experiment [was live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416735/51) from 2022-03-21 14:20 UTC until 2022-04-06 12:00 UTC.

Initial data from the test looks to be positive. We plan on doing some bigger data analysis on the results and will post it on Meta Stack Overflow when this is completed.

---

We will soon be turning on an experiment on Stack Overflow which will test out a new Ask Wizard. The experiment will only target users asking their first questions on the site (to be more specific, questions that would qualify for inclusion in the First questions queue).

The new wizard draws inspiration from the earlier iteration of the [Ask Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live) that ran on the site in 2019, as well as the [New Ask Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network) that succeeded the old Ask Wizard network-wide.

This new wizard is intended to serve as the first step in a new user onboarding system that we right now have in discovery (for which many more details will be shared in the coming weeks). We are releasing this new wizard as a separate test in order to be able to measure how it will affect the quality of questions from new users, as a standalone feature. Metrics that we will be looking at in judging the success of this experiment include percent close rate, average question score, and potentially the number of positive answers received and return engagement from the new user. If you have thoughts on what might be good metrics to track here, we are happy to hear them below.

### How will it work?

The wizard will be split into the following steps, each of which will be accompanied by additional instructive text that will appear in the right sidebar (on a wide screen) or above the section (on a narrow screen):

1. **Guidance and Title**. We are trying to introduce the user to the process that will be taking place on the page, and give initial guidance about on-topic rules.

   [image: Screenshot of the first step. Guidance: Writing a good question. You’re ready to ask your first programming-related question and this form will help guide you through the process. Looking to ask a non-programming question? See the topics here to find a relevant site. Steps: 1) Summarize your problem in an a one-line title. 2) Describe your problem in more detail. 3) Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen. 4) Add “tags” which help surface your question to members of the community. 5) Review your question and post it to the site. Title sidebar guidance: Your title should summarize your problem. You might find that you have a better idea of your title after writing out the rest of the question.]

   The text will link to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help center articles, as well as the [list of Technology sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic) on the Stack Exchange site.
2. **Duplicate question detection**, based on the title. This will use the same duplicate detection that is used today, and will require user confirmation that there are no matches in order to proceed.

   [image: Screenshot of the duplicate detection stage. Summarize the problem by expanding on what you put in the title. Sidebar guidance: Stack Overflow is a huge database of knowledge. Please make sure your question isn't already answered before posting, or your question might be closed as a duplicate.]

   In the future, we are considering adding a second duplicate detection step at the end of the wizard that will take into account the body text and tags, but that won't make it into this stage of testing.
3. Describe the **details of the problem**.

   [image: Screenshot of details entry. Sidebar guidance: Explain how you encountered the problem you’re trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.]
4. Describe **what was tried and what results were expected**.

   [image: What was tried and what results were expected section screenshot. Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted. Sidebar guidance: Show what you’ve tried, tell us what happened, and explain why it didn’t meet your needs. Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a minimal, reproducible example.]
5. **Tag Entry**

   [image: Tag entry section. Normal tag entry input. Sidebar instructions: Tags help ensure that your question will get attention from the right people. Tag things in more than one way so people can find them more easily. Add tags for product lines, projects, teams, and the specific technologies or languages used.]
6. The **two sections of the question are merged, and presented for review**

   [image: Merged body screenshot. The body of your question contains your problem details and results. Sidebar guidance: Now that you're ready to ask your question, read through it from start to finish. Does it make sense? Add any details you missed and read through it again. Now is a good time to make sure that your title still describes the problem! Popover on editor: Your two parts were merged to make the “body” of your question. Please review and edit to make sure that the question in its entirely makes sense. When creating questions in the future, there will be only one body field, but for best results remember to include both a description of your problem and what you’ve tried.]

   We are deliberately including a merge step here in order to replicate the review step that exists in the normal Ask experience, to instruct the users on how the different parts of the question form a whole, and to give them a chance to review the question as a whole before it is submitted.

### FAQs

**When will the experiment begin and how long will it run for?**

It will begin sometime in the next two weeks, and should run for a period up to one month. We will update this post when the status of the experiment changes and plan on sharing results after the experiment has concluded.

**On what sites will the experiment be run?**

Only on Stack Overflow.

**I notice that the wizard is using the new Stacks Editor. Why is this being used here, since it is not being used anywhere else on Stack Overflow yet? Does this mean that the Stacks Editor is going to be released soon on Stack Overflow?**

We are deliberately using the new editor here, even though it is not yet used on Stack Overflow, and is not yet used for question-asking anywhere.

The reasons why we are using it:

- We are splitting the question up over multiple fields. The old editor with the preview beneath it will not work in this context (two active editors on the screen), and we feel that the inclusion of a preview is very important for new users.
- It is being shown only to brand new users. So we are not as concerned with confusion between the editor and the old one (if anything, the new editor is much closer to what many users are used to from elsewhere on the Internet).
- We are planning on moving forward very soon with fixing outstanding issues with the Stacks Editor, with the goal of getting it ready for wider use. Using it here will be a new area for testing, and additional impetus to make sure we fix things. That said, this does not mean that we are as of yet committed to opening up the Stacks Editor for wider use on Stack Overflow or other sites on the network.
- This initial release is a Minimum Viable Product (MVP)/test. It is not replacing the existing ask-question function. So we are more open to testing things in this context as well.

**I am an experienced user. How will I be able to try it out (and give feedback)?**

Once the experiment is live, instructions will be posted that will allow any user to access and use the live wizard (without having your interactions included in test analysis). We are especially interested in hearing from experienced users about their experiences with the tool (while trying to experience the new tool from the viewpoint of a new user), since the main target audience (brand new users on the site) are not very likely to give feedback through traditional channels.

**I am a new user who was included in the experiment for my first question on Stack Overflow. Is there a way that I can opt out?**

There will be no way for users sampled into the experiment to opt out. However, they will only see the new wizard while they are on the first question (or questions if the first one or two don’t do well).

**Will this be offered on other sites in the future?**

If the experiment is successful and the feature graduates, we hope to be able to adapt this to be an option for first-time askers on other sites. At that time we will try to determine what adaptations and customizations will be needed to allow the instructions to be relevant across different sites on the network.

---

We will be happy to address below any questions, comments, or concerns that you may have.

Comment: *Obligatory reference*:  We're off to see the wizard... the wonder wizard of Qs...

Comment: well I kind of need to see those more details about the onboarding system before I really have any comments about this wizard. My main concern is not the questions, it is more that people have a deeply rooted belief that the primary use of Stack Overflow is to ask ALL their questions, with question bans and rocky meta posts driven by frustration and even desperation as a result. The wizard is kind of "step 2" in my opinion.

Comment: I do wonder if offering the user the option to come back to writing their question title is worth it. Some users write titles that really aren't helpful: *"My code is failing on Line 6"* or *"Why does my code fail when I know it's right?"*. I, also, personally find that often it's easier to put my title in *after* I've written my question, as I've actually articulated my question (when asking on my sock puppet account), and then i can make the title be actually meaningful about what I end up asking.

Comment: Does this mean Stack Overflow is only for debugging questions now?

Comment: @Larnu the title will be editable throughout, even after the user has passed that step. Even more - the user will not be forced to enter a title at the outset (they will be able to proceed to step 2 with an empty title) and the sidebar also suggests as an option holding off on writing the title until after the question is written.

Comment: Thanks @YaakovEllis . In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hus1w.png) the [Next] button looked deactivated (compared to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz7zS.png)), so it made it appear that the Title was compulsory to progress.

Comment: *It is being shown only to brand new users. So we are not as concerned with confusion between the editor and the old one* - isn't it possibly going to cause confusion for brand new users that ask a second question and suddenly nothing's like it was the first time?

Comment: @ayhan The intention isn't to change the site scope and we tried to leave the guidance open enough so that it wouldn't feel like that. I'm curious what about the current UX seems to make you feel that way - could you explain in more detail in an answer?

Comment: @JonClements I think the modal during the review step ([pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRhwn.png)) is intended to indicate "This is what question asking will look like for future questions" - is there a way we could help clarify that? I know the text is difficult to read in the question but maybe that helps? If not, feel free to talk about your concerns in an answer so that we can branch that discussion off a bit. :)

Comment: @Gimby The 2019 Wizard had an introductory step that captured things like "is this a hardware or software question?" and then pointed people to other SE sites like HW/SW recs, Super User, Server Fault, etc. They were sort of like honeypots... this is a simplification of that using only the links in the blue box in the first screenshot. Are you saying that you think we need to find a way to do something similar to prevent completely off-topic questions? I think it'd be helpful to have a bit more clarity - do you mind writing an answer about your concerns?

Comment: "*return engagement from the new user*" What is this? How is this measured and is this considered a positive or a negative?

Comment: @Catija I will try, but it might take a while to get the story straight :)

Comment: It is great to see that this is being worked on.

Comment: Your statement that the current editor doesn't work with multiple instances on a single page appears false. Over time, I have, on many occasions, had multiple instances of the editor active on a single question page, editing questions and answers at the same time (sometimes editing the question and *all* answers, so *several* instances of the editor active at the same time on the same page). While I haven't actually used it to post a self-answered Q&A pair, the use of at least two instances of the current editor on the same page has been baked into the site for many years.

Comment: Super happy to see this, though I do prefer [some prior implementation recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard)... most importantly I have to say ***please ask for the title last, not first***.

Comment: The Duplicate question detection seems to still suffer the same issue the current Duplicate question detection does, it results too many irrelevant candidates because the tags are ignored.

Comment: lean on them hard to say what the language is, its amazing how many questions just say 'array' or 'list'

Comment: This is a great idea; if folks "read the instructions" when using this approach, and *use* those instructions, the "First Questions" queue and reviewer's interactions with them, will shrink dramatically.  In practice, the workload on reviewers (and answerers) should noticeably shrink

Comment: Is the bigger data analysis already completed?

Answer (score 104):

> YE: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
> This has been completed. The warning now shows up in the upload menu on the Stacks Editor for new users, same visual as the old one. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425382/51) for more details

---

A known issue for new users is posting images. More precisely, images of code (see [Where are new users supposed to learn that they should show code and error messages as text, not as images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415324/6045800) and [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415324/where-are-new-users-supposed-to-learn-that-they-should-show-code-and-error-messa/415347#415347) to it). As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71306308/1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306015/powershell-output-of-python-script-not-as-expected-with-no-reason#comment126040935_71306015), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291877/could-you-tell-me-about-name-gray-is-not-defined-in-pythoncv#comment126016027_71291877) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285381/i-cant-import-plotly-express-in-jupyter-notebook#comment126004302_71285381) (and those are just from the last 3 days).

It might not be so obvious to all (especially new users) that it makes much more sense to post code directly as text in the question itself. Hence, they find it easy and fast to take a screenshot including their code and post that (that's if we're lucky. Sometimes they actually [take a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riw7y.jpg) [of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHQdE.jpg)...). Even worse, for new users that image will only be posted as a link and not even as an inline image.

Please, let's use this chance and have better onboarding regarding images. I am not sure what is the best route here. One option that comes to mind is completely blocking new users from posting images (as in, *"If I can't post an image, I guess I'll just copy-paste the code..."*). But that of course, feels a bit too harsh and not really viable. There are still some cases where an image is actually in place (like image processing, IDEs, etc.), not to mention that it might just have [worse implications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/upcoming-feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users/416327#comment897554_416327)....

I think that at least a more visible pop-up with a warning should be activated when new users try to add images [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). I mean, one that you actually have to ***actively dismiss*** in order to continue (similar to the new duplicate suggestion approval presented here) as opposed to [the light warning we currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dTf7.png). Something like:

> Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question, and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Images in general shouldn't be used for text. Only post images if you must. For more information, read about [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6045800)

---

> If you have thoughts on what might be good metrics to track here, we are happy to hear them below

In that regard it would be nice to see a metric of how many questions are posted with images of code/closed for debugging details due to an image. Assuming some onboarding is implemented, we would want to see a decrease in images of code posted, following a potential decrease in closed first questions.

Comment: Worth pointing out that adding images and text at the same time using the new stacks editor is really annoying...

Comment: The only thing that will work (no pun intended) is if posting images requires more work (incl. mental energy) than using text. Like solving 20 (relatively easy) [reCAPTCHAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) (or some appropriate number). ([OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) for detection of code as images will probably never be implemented.)

Comment: "One option that comes to mind is completely blocking new users from posting images", I can tell you from experience with another discussion forum, that only leads to new users posting links to 3rd party image hosts.  Block those, and they just find sketchier ones.

Comment: I recall starting on this network and being confused by the icons across the top of the editor, being unfamiliar with it. Hovering over gave info, but that wasn't immediately obvious. Below was a list "Links Images ..." - was this rules, was it help? For a new interface (to your new user), I think you need to make it as clear as possible. It could be as simple as adding "Help: " at the start of the formatting tips line, or adding a text description next to each icon.

Comment: And ensure the help is there to guide them on formatting code entered.

Comment: @AnonCoward Just to make it clear (in case it was misunderstood): I don't really think that's a viable solution (as the sentence goes on to say *"but that of course, feels a bit too harsh"*). I just mentioned it (not sure now why) as the easiest solution that *might* "force" them to just post the code as text. i.e. *"Oh, I can't post an image. What would I do? Maybe I'll just copy-paste the code here..."*

Comment: _some (marginal[?]) cases where an image is actually in place_: questions about image processing and image generation, for example. :-)

Comment: @PabloH That's less my field so yeah, it wasn't on my mind but I guess you're right. I was thinking more of IDE-related questions where an image of the environment and the window itself might actually help

Comment: (@PabloH Anyway, agreed and edited)

Comment: @AnonCoward probably shouldn't have any hard limits on users at all, when I tried to provide research on an early question of mine I hit the "new user" link limit, which just meant that I, well, put the other links in backticks.

Comment: [I asked for this ~2 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401208/283366). Hope it makes it in

Comment: "The only thing that will work (no pun intended) is if posting images requires more work (incl. mental energy) than using text." Agreed. What if they had to explicitly petition for permission, i.e., checking off a box that says "I would like to attach an image to this comment for [fill in a blank reason]"?

Comment: We are [now blocking new users from being able to post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421462/51) using the Ask Wizard, the same as on the old editor.

Answer (score 45):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

I don't see anything telling the users what not to put in the question. For example, tags in the title or greetings and gratitude in the question body. Can this be made abundantly clear?

I understand that there are some automatic removals of greetings, but they are not working so great. This often results in broken sentences, uncapitalized first words or the asker using synonyms to forcefully post their greeting. I feel like a majority of the questions from new users contains some form of "any help will be appreciated" or "thanks in advance". Can something be done to address this issue?

Comment: A big challenge with this is giving instructions without giving too much instruction. The more text that is given, the less chance that it will be read. So if there is a concise way (a line or two) to instruct on this, we could consider adding it. But we have to be choosy about copy, otherwise we run the risk of just lowering the effectiveness of the instructions on a whole.

Comment: @YaakovEllis The help section has a nice concise sentence: [Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Re *"they are not working so great"*: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583269/php8-502-bad-gateway-where-is-php-fpm-on-macos-with-brew-installation) ("Hella all,")

Comment: I'm thinking the other way round: A line of greetings or two hurts *much less* than improperly-formatted code, long paragraphs without a single line break, or images altogether. I'd consider this a rather low-priority thing to take care of, especially it's outright rare that greetings takes too much space to the extent of being intrusive

Comment: @YaakovEllis: There's also the possibility of being reactive here, simple checks for a first short sentence containing "hello" or "hi", or a last short sentence containing "thanks", "regards" or the username would probably detect quite a few greetings/thanks/signatures and only then trigger the warning.

Comment: @Matthieu “Hello” and similar phrases are already automatically removed, though no regex is perfect (on non-regular languages) and it does sometimes leave the content of the post in a strange state, e.g. starting with _“all!”_ as the first entire paragraph. Related: [Taglines and salutations canonical post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/289905), [Automatically remove “thanks”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169858/289905), etc. There are a few linked posts there in which users complain about this automatic removal (“not welcoming”). Not sure if a warning is better. Worth a try?

Comment: @SebastianSimon: Auto-removal with regex is a clbuttic mistake... It seems better to highlight it to the user, give them the guideline, and ask them whether to remove or not (with a pre-selected remove button). If someone is writing a "Hello, World!" example, you don't want to remove Hello...

Answer (score 41):

Some usage guidance that seems to be missing (perhaps it's just not shown in the provided screenshots) is about tag usage. We frequently get questions that use tags in an unambiguously incorrect way that stem from a misunderstanding of what the tag means.

For example, using the tag [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) for "beginner" questions instead of for questions about BASIC (Beginner’s All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code) or [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) (nondeterministic polynomial) instead of [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) (the python library).

---

I know that total usage guidance would not be possible, especially the cases where the asker does not understand or know what tags would be good to use.

However, it might be nice to have a confirmation screen, in line with the "None of these answer my question" duplicate confirmation step, for question tags.

For example a question tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) might have a confirmation like:

> From the tags you've chosen your question is about:
>
> - [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) - Python is a multi-paradigm, dynamically typed, multi-purpose programming language. It is designed to be quick to
>   learn, understand, and use, and enforces a clean and uniform syntax.
>   Please note that Python 2 is officially out of support as of
>   2020-01-01. For version-specific Python questions, add the
>   [python-2.7] or [python-3.x] tag. When using a Python variant (e.g.
>   Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in
>   the tags.
> - [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) - NP ("nondeterministic polynomial") is a complexity class of decision problems that can be solved by a nondeterministic Turing
>   machine in polynomial time. Equivalently, it is the set of decision
>   problems for which an answer can be verified in polynomial time by a
>   deterministic Turing machine.
>
> These tags are correct ☐

(Both text blocks were populated from their respective tag wiki excerpts)

This may help to address some of the "if only they read the tag wiki" type issues, but it also helps the asker. When questions are missing crucial tags the people who are active answerers can miss it completely.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the tags section.

Comment: I feel it would be good to emphasise as well that the tag should be about the question being asked, not the technologies the OP is using. For example, I frequently see questions tagged with [[tag:sql-server]], [[tag:c#]] and then perhaps an IDE like [[tag:visual-studio]] but the question is purely about why the are getting an overflow error in their C# code. The fact that the OP is using SQL Server as a database back end for their application and that they are developing said application in Visual Studio is completely unrelated to the question and attracts attention of users that can't help.

Comment: Yes please! Another good example are questions tagged with [Java and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+javascript)

Comment: Yet another example - a large number of people use the [distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distribution) tag when they should be using [software-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-distribution).

Comment: Speaking of _“if only they read the tag wiki”_, I wish [tag wikis were way more discoverable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/279450/289905). Every larger tag has some really good guidance on how to ask good questions in that tag, a FAQ, etc. Too bad nobody is reading it because nobody ever discovers it!

Comment: @Larnu so many questions tagged with [tag:phpmyadmin]. I don't think I've ever seen one that actually had anything to do with that software

Comment: @Phil I wasn't so much as looking for examples as just giving one. There's are countless examples of incorrect tag usage; I'm just suggesting that we make the meaning behind the tags a little more prominent: Tag what you are **asking about** *not* what you're using.

Answer (score 36):

#### Ask for the title at the end

This workflow doesn't match how I write questions. Just because titles are displayed first doesn't mean they should be written first. I always write the body first, then I go back and fill in the title. The wizard should prompt for the body first then the title, not the other way around.

I suspect asking for the title before the body is why so many questions have terrible titles. People haven't yet spilled their thoughts out onto paper and so the title ends up being the first sentence of their writeup. It's why we get so many quasi-greetings as titles, ones like "Hi I have a problem I don't understand" or "I'm a beginner to Python can anyone help?"

Prompt for the body first and it'll reduce people's natural tendency to put the first sentence they think of into the title.

Comment: I also see a lot of times where a key part of the question isn't posted in the body of the question; it's only in the title.  This impacts how I _read_ questions, since I end up confused before I realize I'm missing some necessary context in a place I don't expect to see it.  Putting the title at the end also addresses this, since it forces them to include all necessary context in the body.

Comment: @M.Justin More importantly, it is easier to think up a good, descriptive title when you've already had to describe your question in long-form first.

Comment: I support this in theory, but it has the problem of chicken/egging with the duplicate help, as I have pointed out in the past [regarding tag recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384710/duplicate-questions-display-experiment/384716#comment695557_384716).

Comment: Dupe detection would still work, it'd just be delayed. A delay isn't necessarily a bad thing: dupe detection might be work better if people end up writing better titles. Also, it'd be nice to use the entire post used for dupe detection rather than just the title.

Comment: If people write out their question first. They will be more successful to find the necessary keyboard for finding a dupe

Answer (score 27):

One of the problems with current workflow and finding duplicates is that you are offering duplicates based on the title while question does not yet have tags. That causes showing zillion duplicates that are absolutely not related to the question user is trying to ask.

I would change this workflow. Before anything else question needs to have tags. Then filtering duplicates will be more successful and helpful.

Specifying tags first also opens opportunity to warn about potentially off topic questions if user uses tags that are commonly misused. Preventing asking questions that don't belong to the site has more chances to succeed if the question is not written yet.

Comment: This is addressed in the post: "In the future, we are considering adding a second duplicate detection step at the end of the wizard that will take into account the body text and tags, but that won't make it into this stage of testing." But no plans right now to change the order of steps here.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I missed that part. However, I still think order is important. Once the question is written, the chances that it will be posted are greater than if appropriate duplicate is immediately located.

Comment: Yes, order is important. On [Codidact](https://forum.codidact.org/t/what-are-we-trying-to-build/27/109), the title field is after the body field (in those views). The fields for a new question are (in that order): *"Body"*, *"Summarize your post with a title"*, *"Tags (at least one):"*, and *"License"* (3 different vers. 4.0 [CC BY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Four_rights) ones)

Comment: Agreed; in [my 2017 suggestion/demo for an 'asking wizard'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard), tags were the _first_ thing a user had to include, for good reason.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Oh neat; does putting the title below the body help discourage useless garbage titles like "please help me" or "problem with code"?  Or is it hard to tell given the different user-base?

Answer (score 20):

I *really* like this overall! It's really exciting to finally see some changes to the first-time asking experience, because I really think the first question is where we gain or lose a lot of folks, and where we show them how our site is different than what they might be used to.

Some highlights that particularly stood out to me:

- **Hard stops between steps**

  - By only showing a single step at a time, it *forces* askers to be more methodical with the composition of their question.
  - Inexperienced users won't be able to plow through writing their first question as quickly, and will be (hopefully) forced to stop and consider the provided guidance and how it applies to them, even just a *little* bit more than they were before.
- **Separately requesting problem details and attempt details**

  - Splitting these into different steps and then combining them is awesome! Both components are really important to questions, and the latter feels like one of the most common misses for new users; asking them directly for what they've tried is a huge step towards helping avoid this issue.
- **Forcing the user to acknowledge that they've looked through the duplicate finder prompt**

That said, I do have a couple nits as well.

- Biggest one: **using the Stacks Editor**

  - It's no secret that this editor [has many flaws](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033), and is actively avoided by many/ most avid users.
  - If this project gives the internal push necessary to finally make it broadly usable, then great!
  - If it doesn't, however, then you will be forcing a broken experience onto new users that can be really frustrating in many cases.
- **No improvements to tag entry**

  - No love appears to have been given to adding tags in the new wizard, even though this is an area where mistakes are commonly made by new users.
  - I feel like we might be able to do more to lead users to applicable tags, even if that's just new guidance over the existing tag selector UI.

All in all, keep up the awesome work, this has a ton of promise in it! I think that good onboarding is a pretty large gap that exists on Stack Overflow, and anything that helps address that will have returns that go far beyond making new users happy.

Comment: Looks like we are going to be able to get restarted now with Stacks Editor fixes (have more time for this now that responsive work is wrapping up). And this project will help give even more of an internal push for this. But we will try to keep an eye on this as well.

Comment: Personally, I share your belief that onboarding is a large gap here (in fact, I daresay that may be the understatement of the year so far), and I am looking forward to seeing how this - in conjunction with some other ideas - will move the needle here. Great job, Yaakov.

Answer (score 14):

In the tags I frequent, duplicate questions are, to my mind, a big problem.

Using the title only, when doing a duplicate search, means it tries to find duplicates of, for instance, [Does anybody know the source of this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71311531/215552) or [Bad layout with js filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71311789/215552) which are question titles with nary a clue as to what's actually happening in the question (the second one at least hints it's about JavaScript, if the duplicate finder is smart enough to equate `js` and `javascript`)

I'm hopeful that a later iteration of this effort, when the body and tags of the question are used, will alleviate my concern. Until then, I will resign myself to the ongoing stream of useless duplicates in the question list.

Answer (score 8):

> 3. Describe the **details of the problem.**
> 4. Describe what **was tried and what results were expected.**

I often see like 90% of new questions without any (re)search. Having that would improve the question quality and maybe even make some questions unnecessary. I really like the step-wise approach. Could there maybe be another such step, something like:

5. Describe **relevant search results for the problem and why they did not already solve it**.

Answer (score 7):

As a meta comment I want to point out that the example presented in this question for step 4 (what did you try, which results did you get, which results did you want/expect) is not accurate.

It does not state what was tried, it does not state what the result was, it only states what the desired result is.

What was tried would be an actual regular expression substitution, in some kind of dialect, *not* some isolated pieces of it as they are presented now. What the result was would be a list of actual substitutions for which the first two are incorrectly substituted. Both pieces of information are very important to make the problem reproducible, complete and verifiable.

This may seem like nitpicking for an example that is just shown in a meta question and not presented anywhere for askers in the actual interface. However, it might indicate that SE staff is unclear on what a MCVE is and why it is important, and/or that they are sloppy with their examples in meta questions. Both of these are reasons to worry, although the first more than the second. So please fix the example and make sure everybody is on board with the actually desired behavior from new users.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. The text here comes [from a question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4081294/51) in 2010, and I mainly wanted to find one that put in some non-standard (not just _Lorem Ipsum_) formatting into the Stacks Editor. Your point is taken, but I am not changing the screenshots right now, my time can be spent in better ways. But I do know what a MCVE is.

Answer (score 7):

Would it be possible to implement some intelligence when it comes to tag suggestions? Specifically a warning if any of these common tag combinations are attempted:

- Mixing [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and/or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) in the same question.
- Mixing [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) in the same question.

(There are probably other common mistagging cases as well.)

There are valid scenarios when these tags should be combined, but most often they shouldn't be used together. An "are you sure?" question/warning upon attempting to combine them would be nice.

Comment: those are interesting ideas, but beyond the scope of the current project

Comment: @YaakovEllis "5. Tag Entry" is beyond the scope of the project?

Comment: Currently we are reusing the existing tag entry tool. And overhaul of this aspect of question asking is not something that we are going to do at this stage.

Comment: Also, mixing PHP and Android, Android and Android-Studio. web & service with web-services. flutter & web with flutter-web... there are a lot more

Comment: Experienced users venturing into new (to them) tags can make similar mistakes (although they're more likely to read tag mouseovers); tag-entry in general should check and prompt about likely-invalid combinations as I suggested in [Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150) .  But that would take some kind of back-end support which apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: [Henry's idea here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416332/5211833) is better I think, because rather than attempting to make a complete list of all abusive tag combinations, you can add an often misused combination to the tag wiki and simply display those for confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a good enhancement, but it doesn't address one of the biggest issues I face as a compulsive editor: **snippet creation and editing**. See [Should the snippet edit link be more conspicuous?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415935/should-the-snippet-edit-link-be-more-conspicuous) for my recent gripe.

Removing redundant tags from titles and fixing poor spelling and grammar is minor and quick. Building snippets and explaining how to revise them is not. It's a real chore. Having a snippet showing a problem greases many wheels. It's important.

Please consider adding some instruction on snippets, even if it's only a link to more information. I recognize concerns of firehose syndrome, but many users don't even see that this is a tool available to them.

Answer (score 2):

Minor point: the links shown in the image aren't very clear to me. I assume that the "ask" link links to "How to Ask" and "programming-related question" links to the on-topic guide, but it's not very clear what the links are or why I'm supposed to read them. It would be helpful to be more explicit about exactly what these pages are and that reading them will help them get answers to their question.

Comment: If we write too many things about a link and why we should click on it, people will just don't read text. Explain why people should read the explaination of how write good question is not very necessary. Just something like "Learn [ask]" should be fine IMO

Comment: @Elikill58 True - still, it seems like there should be *some* clarity around why I should click on those links. As written, it's not clear to me why I would click on them.

Answer (score -4):

I have a point about accepting answers by new users. I am not sure whether this is appropriate to include in the "Ask Wizard". However, most of the new users miss the point that they should accept an answer if that answer solves their problem.  I have seen many new users just ask the question, get the answers and comment "thanks, that solved my issue" in the correct answers and go away.

So, can this be included also in the "Ask Wizard" in any form?

Comment: Like with [Dharman's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/upcoming-feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users/416330#416330) to instruct users to avoid greetings and fluff, adding more instructions that users need to read and follow decreases the chance they're read and follow any of them.  Cognitive load, and patience, are limited resources, as mentioned in comments on that answer.

Comment: However, perhaps there is a way to do *this*: after submitting the question, show the user a "what now" popup over the question page, telling them to stay logged in and respond to comments quickly, and accept an answer if it solves their problem.  (I initially downvoted this answer because I didn't see, and you didn't suggest, a way to add this instruction without distracting from even more important things.  Accepting answers is nice but not essential, compared to the question being not garbage in the first place.)