# Can we have the old editor's GUI in the Ask Wizard?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editor, ask-question-wizard

Can we have a button to switch to the old editor (the question, and I guess, answer editor before introducing the Ask Wizard)'s GUI in the 'What are the details of your problem?' and the 'What did you try and what were you expecting?' sections? Currently, there are only three modes which I don't like, `Rich text mode`, `Markdown mode` and `Markdown with preview mode`:

[image]

The only way to switch back to the old editor is to disable the Ask Wizard, using the button which looks like it'd clear all the input in the various sections of the Ask Wizard when clicked and 'return' to the old editor-GUI with the input-boxes empty:

[image]

Can we please have a button near the three options in the Ask Wizard to just switch to the old editor (the rich-text-like one with preview — which I'm using in MSO to post this question)? The new ones can remain, but I'm just asking for another button to switch to the old one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was answered with "No." on the announcement post for this new wizard.

Comment: @Larnu, is the Stacks editor the new editor (just the GUI)?

Comment: Yes, @TheAmateurCoder ; from the description of [[meta-tag:stacks-editor]]: *"currently used for Teams and the **new Ask Question wizard**"*

Comment: Because I'm asking for just a button to switch to the old one (not completely disable it).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users-trial-has-completed effectively, no, because "the old editor doesn't support multiple editors on the same page" (BS imo., but :shrug:)

Comment: @KevinB, what do you mean by it 'doesn't support multiple editors on the same page'? I'm asking for a button to switch to the old editor (minimized like the other three), just like the other three are in the same page in the two sections...

Comment: i mean, heck, that statement in the linked question is provably false by simply going to any question and clicking edit on an answer.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder the new wizard has two editors on it rather than one, that get merged in step 2 of the wizard. The claim is they needed to use the new editor to support this feature. Note the "I notice that the wizard is using the new Stacks Editor." section of the question.

Comment: @KevinB, yes, I mean that same editor which is hidden everywhere. But which feature? Sorry, I'm not quite understanding the problem. I saw that part, but those sections are just HTML and JS (and CSS) too, right? Why can't it be integrated?

Comment: I *think* they mean "doesn't support multiple editors [for the same post] on the same page", @KevinB . Having a editor open  for an answer and a question are 2 editors on the same page, yes, but not for the same post.

Comment: the editor is just a glorified textarea, i use the same one myself for our own internal systems. There's no reason it couldn't support being used multiple times for the same post if the new one can

Comment: @Larnu, but why is that a problem? The website is built by programmers to help new programmers solve their programming problems, but they can't solve a programming problem on their own website?

Comment: I think the "problem", @TheAmateurCoder , is that they aren't making changes to the old editor; it's still in use while also being deprecated.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, that's another thing. The old editor has many loopholes, but the new ones aren't any better, no?

Comment: I didn't say the (the new editor) *is* better. I'm just giving my hypothesis on why [so] has chosen to take the stance they have.

Comment: This is the quote in particular: "We are splitting the question up over multiple fields. The old editor with the preview beneath it will not work in this context (two active editors on the screen), and we feel that the inclusion of a preview is very important for new users." and yet... i have another tab open with two old editors active each having their own preview.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Unfortunately, asking us "why" about issues surrounding the Stacks Editor really isn't going to be productive, not because we don't want to explain, but because all we have is what SE has told us. Nothing SE has told us about the use of the Stacks Editor on the public sites boils down to, really, anything other than "we, the company, have a corporate direction to be using the Stacks Editor, so we're going to force its use, regardless of the feedback we have received or will receive, or if its use substantially increases the amount of work for our volunteers who do curation".

Comment: @KevinB, yes, seems like they just don't want to improve the site, LOL.

Comment: @Makyen, okay, thank you for clarifying that this is caused by another random stupid thing in the world.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder To give you some context, the community has been giving negative feedback about the usability of the Stacks Editor for about two and a half years now, while the company has, repeatedly, forced its use, without the option to use the old editor, in a variety of situations. While there *have been* improvements, and the company has had some good people actually working on it for about a year now, rather than just letting it languish as they did before that, it's still a quite frustrating situation for *lots* of us.