# Staging Ground Workflow: Canned Comments

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, comments, staging-ground

Throughout this year, we’ve published several posts about different aspects of the Staging Ground. This post will focus specifically on canned comments that Reviewers can provide on the question. We are hoping to gather feedback on what type of canned comments are required, and if we are using the right copy for each reason, as this has not been definitively decided.

Some of the previous posts can be found below:

1. [Staging Ground Workflow: Question Details & Actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416851/staging-ground-workflow-question-details-actions)
2. [Staging Ground Workflow: Listings, Filters, and Notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417271/staging-ground-workflow-listings-filters-quality-control-and-notifications)
3. [Staging Ground Workflow: Question Lifecycle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419746/staging-ground-workflow-question-lifecycle)

### Canned Comments

We are planning on implementing canned comments in order to help cut down on the time required to review a question, while also providing useful feedback to the Author.

Reviewers can compose their own comment or will be able to select from some pre-written canned responses to use as starting points for their feedback. Once selected, any canned responses will be editable. There is no requirement for Reviewers to use the canned comment if they would prefer not to.

While Reviewers can leave comments as part of any review, some Review Actions will require a comment. This was mentioned in a previous post.

> - *Approve pending Minor edits*: The question looks good, but requires small changes to be made before it can be published. This moves the post to the *Minor edits* status. The UI will require that a comment be left by the Reviewer to explain what edits are needed) when selecting this Action (canned comments can be used here).
> - *Require Major changes*: This action is for on-topic questions that require significant edits and reworking to improve question quality before they can be published, but are still salvageable. The UI will require that a comment be left by the Reviewer to explain what edits are needed when selecting this Action. Canned comments will be provided here for reviewers to choose from as a starting point for their comment.

### Types of Canned Comments

One of the aims of the Staging Ground is to lower the closed question rate for questions by new authors. Authors can be coached to update their questions based on the feedback. Keeping that in mind, we’d like to make sure that the canned comments cover the common types of feedback and can be widely used.

The proposed canned comments below are  inspired by the [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance). Here are the canned comments that we have so far.

| Comment Type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Needs detail or clarity** | The question doesn’t have enough detail or clarity to be answered. Please provide additional information such as examples, code, or any errors you’ve encountered to help others answer your question. |
| **Needs focus** | This question is too broad or has multiple parts and it will be difficult to get a good answer. Try focusing on one aspect you’d like answered, or split this up into multiple questions. |
| **Needs debugging details** | There isn’t enough information to reproduce the described issue. Update the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code in an accessible format necessary to reproduce the problem. |
| **Custom** | If none of these are the feedback you’d like to give, you can write your own. |

---

The Staging Ground is still under development, and these canned comments can change based on the feedback received from this post. Please let us know if we are missing anything, or if anything needs to be updated. If you have any questions or comments you’d like to share, please do so in an answer below.

Comment: Should we have a few more specific options? A common one, for example, is questions having titles that are not a good fit for the goals of SO. The question very well could have enough details to be answered, but its title is one that would only stand in the way of the question being useful to future visitors.

Comment: @KevinB example "array troubles" or "Help me fix my issue, pleaseeeeee" or "Hope you have a good day, I have a question that needs answering" or a title which is in another language (while the body is in English) or a title which asks for something *completely unrelated*. These are not *real* titles in as much as I didn't copy and paste them. But they are *very* indicative of actual titles I've seen.

Comment: "Approve pending minor edits" seems like a misstep to me. People should just make them. In my mind, the key distinction between minor and major edits is that major ones require information that only OP has.

Comment: @KevinB Shouldn't that just be an edit by a reviewer? And if the question isn't clear enough to be given a title by a reviewer, wouldn't it fall under the needs clarity comment? Maybe the line between comment or edit is really a question for staff here; I have no idea where the line should be, really.

Comment: @zcoop98 i mean, if we're assuming anyone who is using the staging ground is there to provide edits, sure. Though I think it's fair to say experienced users very well can spot an awful title, while also not being able to provide an alternative due to lack of experience with the subject matter. Skipping, when you know the title is a problem, seems like poor design

Comment: I think the canned comments should, where appropriate, include the phrase "please [edit] your question". This should use the`[edit]` link shortcut. It will help people avoid using comments to clarify their questions.

Comment: @O.Jones I think that should actually be made clear in the UI of the staging ground that it's always preferable to edit the question, so one doesn't need to write it in every comment. Like having "[Respond to comments] or [edit your question]" where currently the "add a comment" button is.

Comment: What I often find is the inverse of *Needs debugging details*, i.e. the question contains too much unrelated code and details. Currently only the latter part of the canned comment focuses on: *shortest code [...] to reproduce the problem*.

Comment: "detail" (Singular) in "*Needs detail or clarity*" (x2) sounds "strange" grammatically, especially against "details" (Plural) in "*Needs debugging details*"...

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at [Can we have some site approved canned comments to match the new CoC and welcoming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371410/781723), which has a number of suggestions made in the past.

Comment: @chivracq: I agree, especially since the corresponding close reason uses the plural: "Needs details or clarity" (with the description: "This question should include more details and clarify the problem." in the Close menu).

Comment: And hum..., one "stupid" Question, oops...!: What happens if **several** Canned Comments are "*needed*"...? Those Posts from Askers very often need Improvement on several parts: (=> 'Title' + 'English' + 'Formatting' + 'Error as Image' + etc...) // => Will they be "concatenated" in just 1 Comment (probably too short for more than 2 Canned Comments anyway), or will they become 1 Canned Comment per Comment...?

Comment: Is there a clear "Use English only" message, including a link to the other-language SO's? Otherwise that would also be a common response

Comment: @Lino it's the same thing. The question still doesn't provide a *minimal* example. Adding irrelevant details and code, makes it harder to identify the correct problem.

Comment: @chivracq: In that case, I think the best solution is just to write a custom comment that includes all the relevant guidance.

Comment: @V2Blast, yep, sounds "*logical*", except that when mentioning 3 (or more) Items that need *Improvement*, such Users usually will unfortunately only handle 1 or 2 Items, not more, and the Custom Comment cannot be dismissed as NLN. => Delete it and reformulate/reduce it to re-mention the remaining Items until they all get handled/improved by the Asker using the "Shadock" Technique... // And hum, I "thought" you agreed that "*detail*" in "*Needs detail[**s**] or clarity*" could use the Plural Form, but I don't see any change in the Formulation in the Post... :sad:

Comment: @chivracq: I'm not the CM working with the devs on this project – I was just confirming that the usage of the singular "detail" here is inconsistent with other parts of the UI. I'm sure the CM who is working on this project will ensure that the relevant feedback is passed on to the product/design teams.

Comment: Ah...!?, alright, what I thought was "just a Typo", is actually a *Bug*, ... if Devs need to be involved... Hum, OK... (And for me and probably all Users on Meta, `Staff` = `Staff`, we don't know your precise Tasks and Job Attributions..., 3 Staff-Members posted/participated in the Thread, + maybe more incognito as part of the "[2022 Stackathon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383022/642998)", you are all Staff-Members to "us"...) // But don't worry, no big deal...

Comment: The only canned comment I need is one that basically explains what a MVCE is, and to please provide a Codepen or similar.

Comment: It would be nice if the "What Stack Overflow is Not" discussions were referenced here, as they are extremely relevant to this discourse.

Comment: Great idea!  Especially the `custom` canned comments.  Did I miss something, or has this not yet been implemented?  And if not, why not?  And custom links like `[mre]`, `[ask]` etc, would be useful in creating custom comments (even though the links could be embedded in the comments when they are created).

Answer (score 70):

Please use language and links to ensure comments are immediately actionable. New users are often not familiar with the workflow of maintaining content and benefit from being explicitly told which tool/path to use.

---

For example, the **Needs focus** instructions just address the user:

> Try focusing on …

who may fail to find the edit option or mistakenly use comments.

Instead, directly link to the tool and name the content to work on:

> Please [edit] the question to focus on …

Comment: Yes, stating the problem is not sufficient. And as users don't read (far), it should not be at the very end.

Comment: Using immediately actionable phrases is a good idea, and we'll be taking that into consideration to update the copy.

Answer (score 64):

#### Add a comment for links to or images of code/errors/data/etc.

This is a *very* common problem.  While it's generally covered by existing close reasons, it would probably help to explain more specifically, as it currently requires reading some amount of text on the linked pages to find the relevant advice.

I'd propose something like this (feel free to use or modify this wording):

> Instead of posting code, error messages, data, or other text as images or links, please [edit] your post to copy/paste or type the actual text directly into the post (for code, use a [code block](/editing-help#code)). [Text in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue, and error messages in images cannot be searched](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links may become invalid if the linked site changes.  If your code is too long to fit in the post, we have tips on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not only Code, but Errors also... Code and/or Errors as Image are equally problematic and can be "handled" together...

Comment: It might be appropriate for the canned comment to talk about "textual content" or similar instead of "code". Not sure if there is a formulation that is both generic enough *and* well known to beginners.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Don't be mislead by the FAQ question title of [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). The **answer** begins "You should not post code (or error/exception messages, log files, configuration files, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image" and after examples says (original emphasis) "**Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.**"

Comment: @philipxy In my experience, even if there is auxiliary information a comment should stand by itself. *Someone* is going to outright ignore the auxiliary information, and *someone* is going to argue whether the short or long version is authoritative. If a questions provides errors/exceptions/logs/configs/… via images then a canned comment talking only about code adds friction.

Comment: I agree with you, also @chivracq, I think I meant to just comment to this poster. Text, not images/links, should be used for what can be given as text.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't get your point. My point is that people should be told to use text in their post for anything that can be given via text. That is what the FAQ I quote says. Not just code/errors/data. Although it's unfortunate how the FAQ phrased it starting with code then everything else in parentheses. The suggestion in the answer added "or other text" after our comments. Although its headline still hasn't added that. It would best just be "no links/images of what can be given in text".

Comment: @philipxy My goal was to explicitly enumerate the most common misuses of images of text, so as to make it quite clear that those are included, while still making clear that it *also* applies to images of other types of text as well.  It also makes it clearer that links to code are also problematic, I think.

Comment: @philipxy My point is that it is insufficient if *only* the linked meta question or even its answers clarifies that *any* kind of text is inappropriate as images. The canned comment itself has to make that clear from the start (As far as I can tell, it does so now.) Many people just won't look past the comment at the actual meta Q&A, or may even get hung up on inconsistent advice.

Answer (score 38):

> The proposed canned comments below are inspired by the Question Close Reasons

I would suggest you have a look at the [frequently asked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) about asking, formatting and scope of the site. These come up again and again, and the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) pages are often linked from question comments.

In particular:

- [This doesn't look like the actual problem you should be solving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)
- [Tell us about resources you already found and how they didn't solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)
- [Post the entire, exact error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146)
- [Do not link to paintings of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) or [tabular data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403699)
- [Be clear about the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)
- [Read about asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
- [Avoid bad tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427)
- [Do not link the page with your issue, post enough code to allow reproducing it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)
- [Format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)
- [Create a StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992), [with React](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)
- [Create an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) for [SQL questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)
- Use proper indentation for readable code
- [Use code formatting appropriately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990)
- [Do not thank or greet people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379)
- [Format your tables using markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716)
- [Ask only in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673), [it's ok not to be a native speaker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362)
- [Only you know whether your code solves your problem correctly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466)

Comment: I like "[paintings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/painting#Noun)".

Answer (score 21):

Here is a large collection of comments that I've put together, based on [Bergi's helpful dataset](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420938/781723) and [Bergi's outstanding list of links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420916/781723).

**Unclear:**

> As it’s currently written, it is hard to understand your question. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand what you are asking. You can find more information on how to write good questions [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/781723).

**MRE:**

> Please [edit] your question to [include a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the post that everyone can compile and run.  We encourage you to [use code formatting for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/781723).

**Didn't work:**

> Please [edit] your question to elaborate on what were you expecting from your code, and what actually happened. If you got an exception/error, [include a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), post the line it occurred on, and [the entire exception/error message you got](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/). That will help us to understand what the problem is so we can better help you.

**Attribution:**

> Whenever you copy from somewhere else, you must provide credit to the original source. To fix it, you can [edit] your question to include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

**General tips:**

> [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We encourage you to read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.  Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

**Background:**

> We ask that you [research your question before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and tell us what you've found and why it didn't meet your needs. Make your question useful for others by providing relevant background and context. This helps us help you, by clarifying your requirements and helping us avoid suggestions you've already rejected.

**XY problem:**

> I'm wondering if this might be an instance of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  I encourage you to review your post to make sure you have stated your requirements clearly, ensure that you are not prematurely ruling out possible solutions that would solve your actual problem, and share the context and motivation for your question.

**Conciseness:**

> On Stack Overflow, we prefer to [avoid greetings, salutations, thanks, signatures, and similar remarks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/).  Please [edit] your question to remove them.  See our [help/behavior] for more details.

**English:**

> Please [edit] your question to ensure it uses proper grammar and spelling.  It might be helpful to review [the tips we've collected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362/781723) on writing style on Stack Overflow.

**Correctness/debugging:**

> Asking whether your code is correct [is off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466/).  Our mission is to build up a knowledge base that will be useful to others in the future, in the form of high-quality questions and answers, and such yes/no questions are unlikely to be of value to future visitors.  Please review [our guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466/) on this topic and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Regarding **Conciseness**, is the presence of a salutation or tagline ever a valid reason to close a question?  I can't imagine that it is.  Just edit the question to remove it, and move on.

Comment: @dbc, Thank you for the feedback.  I understand your position.  I see it as open to personal preference whether to edit it out and say nothing, or to provide feedback and let the poster edit it out; I see reasonable arguments on both.  The former is quicker; the latter teaches the poster about our expectations, so that they learn for the future.  I agree it's not a basis for closure on its own.

Comment: The fact that we have a dedicated meta question about it notwithstanding, does the "code correctness" thing really pop up that much? Most problem questions I see that have non-working code are presented with either a terse "doesn't work" (with no explanation of what or why, of course) or as just a code dump with nothing at all, while if the code *does* work, the questions become "is this the fastest/best/most maintainable/sparkliest way to do it" which are more appropriate for Code Review. I can't remember the last time I saw a simple "correct y/n" question, or a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 19):

Your post states that "Approve pending minor edits" will require a comment, and that the canned comments will be available. However, none of the three presented canned comments represents a *minor* issue - as you say, they are inspired by the related close reasons, and thus describe *major* issues with posts such as not including enough debugging details.

Thus, it does not make sense to include these canned comments for the "minor issues" flow - if a user feels like any of the three presented comments is appropriate, they should have selected "Require major changes" instead. I would suggest you either simply remove the ability to use a canned comment for the "minor issues" flow, or prepare a separate set of appropriate canned comments for minor problems. Not sure what these comments would look like, however you could always start without any canned comments and then add them after release of the feature based on the most frequent manual comments.

Answer (score 15):

Here are a few that I expect may be useful.

**Images:**

> [Please do not upload images of code, text, data, or errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  This makes your question impossible to search, impossible to edit or copy-paste, and inaccessible to the visually impaired.  Please [edit] your question to transcribe text, [use code formatting for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/781723), and see the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

**Titles:**

> Please [edit] your title to [make it more descriptive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/). A good title should be short, help readers know what to expect, and help others find your page via search.

**Homework**:

> Questions asking for help with homework-style tasks must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. I encourage you to review our [guidance on how to ask questions about homework and exercise-style tasks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/781723) and [edit] your question based on the recommendations there.

**Links:**

> Questions must be self-contained.  Please don't rely only on a link to your code.  Instead, please [review our guidance on posting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/), [construct a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), include it in the question, and [use code formatting for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/781723).

Comment: +2 on the 'Images', better formulated than @Ryan_Mod's Answer (who didn't react on my Feedback btw)... // 'Titles': Yeah, the "Intention" is good, but I don't "like" the wording, "*improve it*" is vague and with only "Help" a Link with a super-long Thread that Users will never read (if they ueberhaupt click on the Link, ah-ah...!), the "magic" Word "**DESCRIPTIVE**" should already be mentioned in the Canned Comment, I would say...

Comment: @chivracq, thank you for the critique.  That's a good point, the canned comment on titles that I've stolen from elsewhere needed improvement.  I've edited it to try to be more specific and use the word descriptive.  Is that better?  I could also remove the canned comment on titles so it doesn't distract from the others, if folks think that is wise.

Comment: Yep, I find this new version much better... ("*Please ]edit[ your title to make it more descriptive [+Link]. A good title should be short, help readers know what to expect, and help others find your page via search.*") // "*I could also remove the canned comment on titles*" => No, not at all...!, a Title is like a "Visit Card" for a Thread, I often already "know" from just the Title if I will "like" (or not!) the Thread/Qt (Question), and "chances" are that from a "bad" Title, I will quickly downvote the Qt from just a "quick look" confirming that "First Impression".

Comment: For the "homework" case, there's also a link to Software Engineering SE that is used a lot in addition to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) -> [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). Maybe this could be incorporated into the comment as well?

Answer (score 13):

> Here are the canned comments that we have so far.

No need to work yourself on writing canned comments - the community has already done this for you! Many users have their own set of canned comments, sometimes adjusted to fit the particular question, sometimes just copy-and-pasted time and again.

You're sitting on this data already - [here is a simple data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1657899/comments-that-ask-to-edit) listing the most common comments that ask to edit a post from the last years. Not all of them are useful, not all of them are up to the current code of conduct, but when sifting through the list you'll be able to identify a theme of pain points.

Comment: I'm not sure why but the `WHERE text LIKE '%[edit]%'` in your query seems to be... ignored?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yeah, I noticed (I guess `[]` marks optional parts), but various other queries I tried just did time out so I just posted a link to a work-in-progress one that at least gave useful results

Comment: Ah, right! How did I not think of that ‍♂️. Anyway, [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1657899/comments-that-ask-to-edit) seems to be working fine.

Comment: *[How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)*

Answer (score 7):

##### Hot take: canned comments about the question's subject are not as helpful as people think they are.

Canned comments about formatting, posting code as images, and altogether off-topic questions: fine. But about these comments from the OP:

> 1. The question doesn’t have enough detail or clarity to be answered. Please provide additional information such as examples, code, or any errors you’ve encountered to help others answer your question.

> 2. This question is too broad or has multiple parts and it will be difficult to get a good answer. Try focusing on one aspect you’d like answered, or split this up into multiple questions.

> 3. There isn’t enough information to reproduce the described issue. Update the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code in an accessible format necessary to reproduce the problem.

Neither of those point the asker to what exactly is wrong with their question.

I'll paraphrase advice that has been posted on Meta many times before: if you don't want to tailor your comment to the question at hand, don't post a comment at all but just downvote and/or closevote.

Comment #1 is okayish, for an actual unclear question. But every generic "your question is too broad" comment is met with "no it isn't, I just want to ask how to build the next Facebook, that is one question" (#2), and every "non-min-reprex" comment (#3) is met with "but all my code is in the question".

Especially in #2: why is it "too broad"? Is the question about writing an entire application? Or are there five follow-up questions that have been asked and answered before, which won't reasonably fit in a single answer? Askers will need specific feedback about that.

And for #3: which is it? Is code missing? Is a compiler/runtime error missing? Is input/expected output missing? All of those? Or something else?

So, responding to:

> We are planning on implementing canned comments in order to help cut down on the time required to review a question, while also providing useful feedback to the [a]uthor.

Canned comments will only make reviewers happy, without any culture change. You won't achieve the second goal from that quote. Canned comments do not provide specific, actionable feedback, when the problem with the question is specific.

Please carefully select which comments should be allowed to stay in their canned format, and which must be tailored to the question.

Comment: Canned comments are as useful as "we rejected your app submission; please read our fourty-two page long design guidelines and go figure out what you missed".

Comment: Yes. Don't make work for readers/reviewers. Send posters back to read the F manual.

Comment: I agree as to the first comment (the one for "Needs detail or clarity").  That's...really not super useful, and it sometimes (often?) might be totally inapplicable. Often the issue is that they haven't actually said what they want.  It might be better to prompt the user for an explanation, or at _least_ have "subreasons" like "it's unclear what you want, please elaborate", "please include an example of the desired input and output", "please write your question in English", "please clarify which SQL dialect you're using" (okay, maybe too specific, but...), etc.

Comment: The one for too broad is fine.  I think that adequately describes the issue for most questions to which it applies.  It generally does not require specific guidance (beyond "you need to pick one specific language/technology/framework/etc." for questions with a clear task but multiple implementation language choices).  For lack of debugging details...it depends.  For "no code whatsoever" or "link to an entire GitHub repo", it's fine.  Linking to the guidance is good.  A lot of questions, though, it's not always clear what exactly it's missing, and so those need more than a canned comment.

Comment: @Ryan no, it's really really not fine. An asker who doesn't know how to produce an MRE, doesn't know what's missing from their question. So we're closing their question and telling them "there's something missing, go read these walls of text to figure out what these closevoters could have meant". That's not helpful, that's only going to cause more frustration. Canned comments are really useless if the goal is to help people. .

Comment: I’ve had very good experience with canned comments for [mre].  For many new people it’s not that they don’t want to, they just haven’t considered that it is needed. The [mre] help page also is rather actionable and like the quoted canned comment 3 have either actionable or itemised advice - it is very much possible to go though them like a checklist.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in my experience, there's a lot of users who don't have the slightest clue what they're doing, and when asked for more code through boilerplate comments or close votes, start adding random code to their question. My point is that if you're reviewing anyway, and you know what's wrong with the question, go spend that tiny bit of effort and tell them what exactly is missing, or go do something else. I hate canned comments with a fiery passion. I even edit auto generated duplicate comments when I can, explaining how the dupe helps.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi tl;dr: the MRE page is a great resource if you know what you're doing; many don't.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think that's what I was getting at with "it's not always clear what exactly it's missing, and so those need more than a canned comment."  Questions with _no_ code probably are fine with a generic canned comment, and having a good pre-written one is better than what people write on the fly.  Questions with _some_ code need more than a generic canned comment.  It's definitely a concern that having a canned comment might lead to overuse of said comment when people should have written a custom comment. I personally _do_ use canned comments, but I have dozens of _very_ specific ones.

Comment: As an example, the most commonly used one is this comment for Android questions about crashes that lack a stack trace: *"It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to."*

Comment: I think my dream would be some sort of system for having canned comments associated with tags, but that's also probably complicated and impractical to maintain to the point of infeasibility.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, seems like we're on the same page after all.

Answer (score 4):

#### Off-Topic Help Requests

Questions from people who ask for help related to using computers, but not for getting help about writing code by themselves.

I think that we have many questions from people having some sort of problem or goal who are looking for help to solve / achieve it, but, for any reason, they are not interested in applying the solution by themselves or learn anything from the site. Usually their "requirements" are "too localized", so nobody who writes code will learn or have benefits from that question.

Sometimes the question blatantly asks for someone to write the code for them, ask "is there code that I can copy-paste", to fix code written by someone else that stopped working, or they are looking for someone to adapt code found in the wild to their specific needs.

The common close reasons for these questions are ask about general computing, ask for recommendations, or not reproducible, but it might use other the closing reasons.

IMHO, it doesn't make sense to provide feedback about how to write the question. The feedback should be about the site scope and what is on-topic or off-topic. Something like

> The question doesn't look to be about writing code or using tools for this task. You still might get help from this site if you are able to make it on topic. Ref. [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1595451). For further details about question that might be asked here see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

### Setting expectations

It's important that new users understand as soon as possible that Stack Overflow won't write code for them, produce an individualized solution, guide them through every subsequent problem they encounter with the same *task*, etc. While the tone of "Stack Overflow is not X" isn't generally appropriate, canned comments **need to reflect that mentality, and they must be firm** in doing so.

Fundamentally, certain questions can't be rescued by editing them. If a question is far too broad, a duplicate, or caused by a typo, then edits that make the question suitable for Stack Overflow... would fundamentally create a different question. It's important to keep this in mind; canned comments **must not falsely suggest that an unsalvageable question could be salvaged**.

### About close reasons

While the reasons to comment should of course be informed by whether the question is suitable for Stack Overflow (and therefore by the standard reasons for closing questions), there is **not a one-to-one mapping** onto things that new users need to be told about the question. There are many conceptual ways, for example, that a question could lack focus or clarity; and some bad question-asking habits could prompt multiple closure reasons.

### About "minor edits"

I touched on this in a comment. "minor" vs. "major" is the wrong distinction here. The real axis of concern is **"can be fixed by others" vs. "requires OP's input"**. If the problems can be fixed by others, then they *should* be fixed by others, unless OP volunteers. It will be much faster and more streamlined that way, trust me.

However, it will be useful to *explain* such edits *after the fact* to OP via canned comments, so that they can improve their posting style and avoid the need for such edits on future questions.

### Tailoring

Many things that one might say to a new user, in order to be useful, **need to be adapted** to refer to specific details of the question. Which is to say, I sympathize with [CodeCaster's view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421183); but canned comments still provide a highly useful *framework* for identifying issues with a question (and reminding oneself of the list of potential issues), and for making it easier to adhere to the Code of Conduct while frustration mounts from repeatedly saying the same things to multiple new users. It also potentially saves a lot of time - both typing, and thinking about the phrasing.

### My proposals

With that in mind, here are some canned comments I propose for a mixed bag of circumstances:

#### Issues requiring OP's input

| Issue | Message |
| --- | --- |
| **Question is not in English** (Ideally, there would also be official translations of this message to commonly spoken languages, with direct links to the localized sites where applicable.) | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions here [must be asked in **English only**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). We [will not translate](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673) the question for you, because we must be sure of your meaning, in your own words. If you can, please [edit] to ask in English instead. The title for your question must also be in English.` |
| **Question is a clear duplicate, at most minimal explanation required** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. The key issue here is <explain briefly>, and this is a common problem. We already have a Q&A about this at [title of page](//stackoverflow.com/q/<id>) - please read it to understand the problem thoroughly. If you have a new, related question after that, please start over and ask it. If the Q&A doesn't help, please see [this post on our Meta site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252).` |
| **Question is potentially a duplicate** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like the key issue here is <explain briefly>, in which case we already have a Q&A about it at [title of page](//stackoverflow.com/q/<id>). If that answers your question, great! We're happy to have helped. Otherwise, please [edit] the question to make it clear [how you think it's different](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252).` |
| **Question is copy-pasted from homework, interview test etc.** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/). We will not solve homework, job interview questions, problems from "puzzle" websites etc. for you - plagiarism is a serious matter. The Stack Overflow format requires a clear **question** that is about **one specific, clearly identified problem**; posts here are *not* simply about getting a piece of code to work. Please study the task on your own first; if you find a question about one specific problem, then start over with a question about that.` |
| **The code clearly works and there is no objective question** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't discuss code here or offer arbitrary suggestions for improvement; this is a **question and answer site** as described on the [tour], which means we need a **specific, objective question** to answer - e.g. "can I make this a one-liner"; "can this be made to run faster/use less memory"; etc. If you want to ask a question like that, please [edit] to do so. If you are looking for a code review, please try [codereview.se] instead.` |
| **The question is confused between "how do I do X" and "what's wrong with code Y"** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you've already tried to complete the task yourself before posting. That's good in general, but right now it means there are really two questions here: one about <problem as described>, and one about <task as described>. We require **one** question per post here, so please choose which one you want to ask, and [edit] accordingly. It could turn out that the right way to solve the problem uses completely different code.` |
| **The (how-to) question lacks a clear specification** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to understand what you want to happen when the code runs. For example, if I input <example>, should the result be <propose some possibilities, or directly ask what should happen>? Please **think about this carefully** instead of just answering me; then [edit] the question so that it's clear how the code should work in every case.` |
| **The code appears to work and it's not clear what's being asked** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. When I try this code <insert background assumptions and input here>, it seems to work - I get <result>. If that's the wrong result, or there's something else you want to ask about, please [edit] to make it clearer. You may also be interested in [codereview.se].` |
| **There is not enough code for an MRE** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to understand the question, because this code does not enable me to reproduce the problem. Please read [mre] and then [edit] the question to make sure that it showcases what is wrong - **try using the code yourself** from the question, instead of your original code. Ideally, we should be able to *copy and paste* the code *without adding or changing anything*, run it, and see the *exact problem, directly*.` |
| **There is way too much code for an MRE** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that we don't write answers here to "find the bug" for you; we require a **specific** question about a problem that you have already [identified](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [located](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem. That is: make sure you have already figured out a **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*); then [edit] the question to include a [mre] and ask about the unexpected result.` |
| **An error message is needed, but is missing or incomplete** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to diagnose the problem properly, we need a [complete](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146) error message that is **copied and pasted** (don't try to retype or describe it) - if at all possible, this should be [text, not an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please <environment or language-specific instructions>, then [edit] the question to include this information.` |
| **Inappropriate use of images for code, errors etc.** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. **[Please do not use an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) to show us <description> - instead, *copy and paste the text*, with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This will help us to write answers and do any needed additional research. We [will not transcribe](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415040) images for you.` |
| **Severe formatting issues (not fixable by others)** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [formatting help](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and then [edit] your question so that everything shows up properly. If you need more help, [try looking on the Meta site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+formatting+%5Bfaq%5D). I would fix it for you, but I wasn't sure how you intended it to look.` |

#### Feedback for edits already made

| Issue | Message |
| --- | --- |
| **Fixable formatting issues** If the change was minor and it seems likely that OP simply made a typo in the formatting, don't leave a comment. | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. We've edited your post so that it appears properly formatted: <describe specific issues, if appropriate>. Before your next question, please read the [formatting help](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to see how to do it properly. If you need more help, [try looking on the Meta site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+formatting+%5Bfaq%5D).` |
| **Noise removed from the question: "please", "thank you", signatures etc.** If multiple kinds of noise were removed, use your judgement or write a custom comment. | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, please keep in mind that this is a **Q&A site, not** a discussion forum, help desk or anything else like that - because of that, we want question posts to contain [**only the question, not**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/) <describe what was removed>. (We've already fixed this for you; you don't need to do anything and are not in trouble.)` |
| **Noise removed from the question: "I'm a beginner" or other personal commentary** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, please keep in mind that we want question posts here to contain [**only the question, not**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/) anything to do with you, your level of skill as a programmer, or anything else like that. We will automatically adjust how we write answers, according to the complexity of the problem and who we think is likely to have the same issue. (We've already fixed this for you; you don't need to do anything and are not in trouble.)` |
| **Noise removed from the question: commentary about urgency** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, please keep in mind that questions posted here are for *everyone who has the same issue, not just you*; we [are not interested](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) in your personal deadlines and will volunteer answers on our own schedule. Some of the best answers on the site were written many years after the question was asked. (The question [has been edited](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/) to remove this commentary; you don't need to do anything and are not in trouble.)` |
| **Noise removed from the question: meta commentary** Hopefully, the Staging Ground will make this sort of problem much less common! | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't include anything in questions here that asks about the site's policy or which is "meta" - such content [will be - and has been in this case - promptly removed](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/). Instead, please use [the meta site](//meta.stackoverflow.com), after first reading the [guide to Meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917)`. |
| **Editing for clarity and/or focus** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. We've edited the question for you to make sure it's *clear* and *focused* enough for the site standards, by <give details>. Please have a look; if we misunderstood something, feel free to [edit] again and fix anything that's wrong. **Editing posts is a community effort**; questions here are for everyone, as described in the [tour], and we want them to be as high quality as possible.` |
| **Copyediting, grammar fixes etc.** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. We've edited the question for you to make it clearer and easier to read, by <give details>. Please have a look; if we misunderstood something, feel free to [edit] again and fix it to make sure the question is accurate. **Editing posts is a community effort**; questions here are for everyone, as described in the [tour], and we want them to be as high quality as possible.` |
| **OP is objecting to edits (especially noise edits)** | `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that when you post here, you [grant a license](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) to your content, to both the community and to the site itself, which **cannot be revoked**. We retain the right to edit questions [in accordance with policy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/). Questions posted here are not like posts on a discussion forum; they are helping to build a searchable library for everyone, as described in the [tour].` |

Ideally, the system for canned comments will *fill the text into a comment field, but not actually submit it*; this way, we can do whatever customization is necessary first. Again, the goal is not to ensure that everyone communicates in this exact, rigid way; **the goal is to save time by providing a useful framework** for describing problems with questions.

Comment: re: "_The question is confused between "how do I do X" and "what's wrong with code Y"_" - **YES** please and thank you. the amount of grief such questions cause to searchers is immeasurable.

Answer (score -10):

Here are few that I use frequently:

| Comment Type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **When user posts comment as answer** | This is not an answer. Soon with enough SO reputation you'll be able to add comments. Until then, avoid posting comments as answers. |
| **When user copy/pastes homework problem** | Stack Overflow is not a coding service for ordering code. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Show us what you've tried so far and what problem you're facing with that so that we can find out the problem and suggest a correction(if any) and maybe even provide a better solution. |
| **User copy/pastes random online puzzle type question(say about C++)** | C++ must be learnt using a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by solving random online puzzles. |
| **When user asks question (say about C++) that is in any beginner book** | Stack Overflow is not an introduction to C++. For learning the basics, a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be used. After learning the basics, you'll automatically be able to diagnose the problem for yourself. |
| **When there is nothing wrong with user's code and they just want to improve it** | If there is nothing wrong with your program and it compiles and gives the correct/expected output and you just want to improve it(performance-wise etc) you may want to ask it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) |

Comment: These are not good comments. The one about homework is just a longer version of "what have you tried" that was banned long time ago for being rude. It still is... just not as harsh as it was before. But it doesn't help much. The second-last one is pointless. Why add such a comment at all? It doesn't help Stack Overflow one bit. It just tells people not to ask questions. We want people to ask questions so this comment doesn't help the site fulfil its goal.