# How to retrieve a question in which I only know an image posted in the question

Tags: support, images

I am trying to retrieve a specific question probably posted on *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *Stack Overflow*, or *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)*. I don't know the title, nor the content of the question. I only know the name of the link to a specific image: 4Wmdc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wmdc.png works fine and I get the image itself. But that is not what I am looking for.

I failed to find the question or discussion to which the image is coming from. That's the problem.

Trying to understand how proceed in reading several resources such as for example *[Any details about stack.imgur.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com)*, this had achieved nothing for my search.

Comment: This is why we don't like images in questions.  They're impossible to search for.

Comment: @Makoto The issue isn't that the image can't be found when searching for the filename used in the image's URL. The issue is that the *contents* of the image, or what the image represents, can't be searched for ([among other issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), of course).

Comment: @Makoto how else can one represent a graph in a post? I'd like to see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wmdc.png) in a post without an image.

Comment: @10Rep: Software problems tend not to need graphs. (Might be a hint that this question isn't related to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @Makoto What if one was modeling Big O Notation of multiple sorting alogorithms? That's on-topic as far as I know.

Comment: @10Rep:  If they were talking about an issue with their code, sure.  But that would be explainable without the graph.  I'm struggling to find a rationale in that context where a graph would be appropriate/valuable.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. In fact I was not looking for the graph. I had already the graph with its reference. I was looking for the question itself. Thanks to the information given by Makyen I got the link and could edit my answer to the question. This has been an opportunity to learn some properties of stack ingur and URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can [search on all of Stack Exchange for "224Wmdc.png" in URLs](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%224Wmdc.png%22) (i.e. using the search term `url:"4Wmdc.png"`), which results in [logistic like curve fitting using machine learning](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45831/logistic-like-curve-fitting-using-machine-learning) as the question on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) which uses that image.