# What can I improve about my question to ensure it is on-topic and meets the guidelines?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I created [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058969/gas-test-environment-only-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-present) that was closed and downvoted. The closure reason states:

> This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers
> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.*

I edited the question by adding a screenshot of the final Google message and a video of how it works (does not work). Other projects work; a new project works too. I have no idea what other information I can provide. What other useful information could improve my question?

How can I improve the question so it is accepted and it could be answered?

I created a simple web application and shared it from my [G Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Workspace) account to my Gmail account to simulate the current setup and was able to access `/dev` path from there. Therefore, I do not know how to provide exact steps how to reproduce the issue.

---

**Author's Comment:**

This question was posted on Stack Overflow because I was seeking help on how to DEBUG the issue. As a side benefit I wanted to improve my original question that was closed. I can see that this question was edited and even the title was changed. It is now completely something else.

Comment: I placed tis queston on SO not on Meta because  I primarily need technical advice how to debug. Not only how to improve my original question. I thought that SO is better place than Meta. For SO is of technical people ...

Comment: It lacks a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you cannot provide the source code that reproduces the problem seen in that project, how is anyone going to provide an answer?

Comment: Your question mainly focussed on improving your question. It's better to split the question then. If you need debug help, only ask about debugging in SO and question improvement in meta.  Personally, I don't find anything wrong with your original question. Furthermore, you have better chance of improving your question and getting your question reopened, if it is in meta.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce the problem. Do you? It is specific to this Google. project this and only this one. I do understand that for some it is hard to grasp but maybe someone experienced the same and might help.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Image was added already. I thought the the text of the error message is good enough. The text was there from the beginning.

Comment: Point being, I'm not sure whether a problem that can only be described using a video is appropriate for the site. (For the record, I did not actually look at the video.)

Comment: The problem is that I am not able access the `test environment`. I get the error. I really do not know how to describe it better. When I try to access url of Google script environment I get this error. What else could be improved to make it acceptable?

Comment: A gif uploaded here would be better than a external link video.

Comment: @Radek It is possible that this answer cannot be improved to make it acceptable on SO. That is one of traps of such environments - when things go wrong in mysterious ways others are less likely to be able to help than with standalone code.

Comment: @reducing questions about project deployment are par for the course in Apps Script. There is little mysterious about it, there are just many "moving parts" and conditions. Sometimes I think we need a template for these types of questions.

Comment: @Radek  Just for info, We also have a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community). If your issue is not exactly reproducible, you may ask there first.

Comment: Related (cross): *[What is the purpose of Stack Exchange? Help each other?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372136/)*

Comment: The MSE question is deleted now.

Comment: @PeterMortensen  I can still see [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058969/gas-test-environment-only-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-present)

Answer (score 6):

You can try providing a script that sets up a new [GAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script) project from scratch and exhibits this error.

Though at this point you may first try recreating this project (or more specifically, getting whoever controls this script to do this, given "I am not the owner of the script. My role is editor.")

It is possible that this post will be really hard to improve to make it acceptable on Stack Overflow. That is one of the traps of such environments - when things go wrong in mysterious ways, others are less likely to be able to help than with stand-alone code.

Comment: The script is irrelevant. It can contain anything. The issue seems to be missing access permissions when deployed.

Comment: That should simplify making reproducible example.

Comment: I created simple web application. Shared it from my Gsuite account to my gmail account to simulate current set up and was able to access /dev from there. Therefore I do not know how to provide exact steps how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: it worked before as it is for months. Nobody to my awareness changed anything. Maybe Google did.

Comment: @reducingactivity. I agree that it would be one of the mysterious errors. That way I am so puzzled how come soooo many users just turned me down. Just like nothing.

Comment: @Radek How do you expect anyone to help you? If the problem is related to Google Apps, why are you expecting rapid, detailed support from a site unaffiliated with Google (except for their Collective™ and branded tags). Maybe it's me, but if I have a problem with Azure, I expect support from Microsoft. Likewise, if I was using Google App Script, and something went wrong, I'd hit up Google.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey. There is a Google App Script support from Google? I am not aware of that. Could you please give me the url? Also where did you get that I expect rapid support? Under the original question I got "support" from two SO members. That is what I expecting - willingness to help. That is all expect.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support seems to be the obvious source. You do need to read more than a few words; There is a section labeled Bugs that indicates how to search for existing bugs and log new ones. Note that I've never used Google App Script; I merely, and perhaps ironically, googled that phrase, clicked on the first result. Then I clicked on Get Started, and then on Support. Not a terribly difficult or time-consuming search.

Comment: thank you for the time you spent on that. In the url you provided the very first link is to SO. Then Google community group and Google issue tracker did not return any relevant items. SO is quite often use as the mean of support. For  example my favourite tabulator http://tabulator.info/community

Comment: @HereticMonkey as one of the SMEs I have to note that, unfortunately, Google explicitly does not provide customer support for the platform. The only two channels available are the issue tracker and, well, us here. The type of issues the author faces is a particularly nasty type too - I can attest that I've spent a ridiculous amount of time on similar issues. There are a lot of combinations of config options that directly how projects behave, and the process is, frankly, poorly documented. The resource you linked to is, indeed, our go-to source, but with this particular type of [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] problems it does not help much, as the documentation of various cases is sketchy at best.

Comment: another quite explanatory example is that my customer reported that the application I provided stopped working. To make is simple I found a bug that Google introduces in some of updates. I created new issue in their tracker but first I discussed it here. I do not find myself GAS guru so I always seek help here. 
I do understand that SO do not have to like my questions but I really do not understand that it was closed and down voted without one single comment.

Comment: @Radek Providing feedback alongside a downvote is never required. For what it's worth, you've had some good feedback here anyway: as it stands, the question as posed does not provide enough details to reproduce the problem, which is a standard reason to close a question. This platform is not very suitable for one-on-one guidance or iterative troubleshooting, which would likely be needed here.