# What are the rules regarding what a new asker can post?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm referring specifically to somebody with very low rep, say 1, 2, or 3.

- How much code can they post, and how big can a question be? If too big, is it OK to post a link to the code somewhere? If so, what 'snippet' sites do we recommend for C, C++, etc?
- How often can they edit their question?
- How soon can they post another question? (A common occurrence is that they post without enough info, the question gets closed before they can add the requested file or whatever, so they have to re-ask.)

I'm interested in what sorts of advice I can give low rep users? I don't want to give them bad advice.

Comment: To your third point, if a question is closed because there's not enough information in it, they can (and should) edit the question to add the missing information, nominating it for reopening.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas and what about answers to the first two questions I asked? They are not answered by the dup (I now know how a new rep 1 questioner feels)

Comment: “If too big, is it OK to post a link to the code somewhere?” - No; We don’t want to debug thousands or hundreds of lines of code we want a minimal example that recreates the problem. If you cannot fit your example code and a clear explanation of your problem in 5,000 something words (or whatever is the limit) then your not submitting a good question

Comment: See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/566903) on MSE for answers to some of your questions.

Comment: @pppery thank you for this - is exactly what I was looking for - shame you cannot post this as an answer since the question is closed

Comment: @SecurityHound I am still trying to find out the limit to the amount of code allowed in a question, I though the answer linked by pppery would say, but it does not. I had a rep1 user who had posted images of code but could not upload the text because he was told it was too big, it was probably 300 lines. I was happy to help him but could not work out how to. I am happy to debug that much

Comment: @pm100 - The limit is a minimal example that reproduces the problem, if you have to provide your entire GitHub repository to reproduce the problem, then your problem is beyond the scope of a single scoped question. Remember, we are not a help desk, so the question must be focused. Submitting screenshots of code is almost never acceptable, since it cannot be copied into a text editor, so somebody can answer the question.  The character limit to a question is 5,000 characters, that is more than enough, to ask a focused question.

Comment: @SecurityHound well, I am happy to help those people. I guess I need to find a different way to help them

Answer (score 4):

Most of what I'm about to say applies to everyone, not just those of low rep.

- Your question should always be self-contained and [minimal but reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Remember that volunteers are reading and devoting time to your question, so it should be short and to the point. If the SO interface is flagging you for posting too much code, then that's a good sign that there's too much code and you need to trim it down. *Never* rely on a link to an external site for details integral to your question. Your code should also be posted directly in the question as text. [Do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). The first thing I do when endeavoring to answer a question is copy and paste the code into my editor and run it. If it's an image, then I can't do that. Again, it's all about making it as easy as possible for us to help you.
- You can edit your question as often as necessary, and you absolutely *should* do so to clarify details or add information if someone makes a good point in the comment section. The question should include all of the details necessary to reproduce the problem, and we strongly encourage you to improve it as things come up. You should *not* sabotage your own question once you have an answer; this isn't a forum, so you shouldn't replace the question with "solved kthx"; you should leave it there for future readers to benefit from. If you manage to solve the problem you were asking about on your own, post an answer to your own question. [We encourage self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but it should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to the question.
- You should not ask the same question again. If a question gets closed, you should edit it to include the details asked for. It may not look like it, but when you edit a closed question, it goes into a special queue that Stack Overflow members with 3000+ rep can see. Volunteers regularly go through that queue and review closed questions that have been edited to see if they should be reopened, so the mere act of editing gives your question a second chance. If you post the same question again, it'll get marked as a duplicate of the original and likely deleted.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that for new users, re-asking the same question leads to a poorly received question being left on their record, which can affect q-bans, which is another reason to edit the original question.

Comment: I am not asking because I am having issues, I am asking because I kinda specialize in helping floundering rep 1 posters (I am 40k) and I want to know what to tell them. I know all the spiel about MRE, being clear etc. But I dont want to tell them to do something they are not allowed to do as it only frustrates them

Comment: Text (e.g., code or error messages) [as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) could be mentioned as well in the answer (even if not explicitly called for).