# Table formatted correctly in preview, but not when question is posted

Tags: bug, markdown, formatting, tables

There appears to be a slight inconsistency in the rendering of tables in Markdown. If a table isn't preceded by an empty line, then the table is rendered properly in the draft editor, but not when the question/answer is published. As a result, it seems that questions are being published with broken tables despite the best efforts of editors.

As an example, this line of text is followed immediately by a table. It looks fine in the editor, but I expect it won't appear properly after I post this question.
| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| four | five | six |

And here's a screenshot taken directly from the editor page:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: The table probably needs a new line for the actual view

Comment: @SurajRao I'm aware of that

Comment: Cross-site duplicates on MSE: [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359192/348196), [Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358999/348196).

Comment: This seems to have been an issue forever and nothing has been done about it.

Comment: @user438383: Yes, it is another excuse (and reason) to [post as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) instead of text. Using text ought to be the easier choice (so it will actually happen). The software ought to help with that.

Comment: Same happened to me right now, so that bug is probably still alive, and I should stop trying table edits for a while?