# Can I upload videos when I upload posts in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I would like to upload a recorded video about the my problem coding when I upload the question post. How do I upload an video in this post?

Should I upload the video to another site and bring its link?

Comment: Almost all content for us to be able to answer your question should be in the question itself. There are very few exception to this, and videos aren't one of them. It is very unlikely people will want to watch a video to be able to begin to assist you.

Comment: I think a lot of people are not going to want to spend time watch a video to understand someone's problem. There as so many questions posted on Stack Overflow that you really only have a few seconds to grab someone's attention before they decide to look at another question.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? How do you expect the video to help make the question clearer? Posting images [is already far inferior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) to showing code, errors, etc. as properly formatted text. A video seems like going even further in the wrong direction.

Comment: Videos are good for tutoring, not for asking questions.

Comment: What kind of content? The same rules as for screenshots apply: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*

Comment: "Videos are good for tutoring"... if you like video for tutoring. Personally I always prefer text @Gimby.

Comment: @TGrif Luckily we live in a world where you can have both, since the two mediums complement each other rather than compete.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Directly, there isn’t any way to upload videos directly to Stack Exchange. They must be uploaded to external sites first, and there are plenty that offer this (such as [Imgur](https://imgur.com/upload) and even [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software))). *However, for almost all contexts, a video should not be necessary.*

Most videos can instead have all relevant information shown in a couple of screenshots, say if an interaction is being recorded, a before and after screenshot could be shown instead. However, if this doesn't work, capturing an animated GIF should do the trick (see tools like [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) to do so) assuming the audio itself is not required/cannot be transcribed.