# What flag should I use for questions having a link to a photo of the real question?

Tags: discussion, flags, images

Time and again, I come across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72839772/downloaded-the-github-user-card-project-from-online-but-iam-unable-to-start-the).

[image: screenshot of deleted question]

What I do not understand is which flag am I supposed to use. I usually go with very low quality, and at times it gets accepted too (I guess that makes it okay-ish).

I'd like to know which flag is usually suggested for such questions.

Comment: "needs details or clarity" is more appropriate. Basically, the goal here is to get those questions closed as soon as possible to prevent "shot-in-the-dark" answers and NAAs ("please post your code" "answers") until the OP edits their question in shape.

Comment: Posting a link to [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) in the comments can also be helpful, as it explains to the OP why their question is very likely be very poorly received.

Comment: Hum, @Oleg, there is no `needs details or clarity` Flag on Questions, only `needs improvement` or `very low quality` (+ `spam` + `rude or abusive` + `a duplicate` + `in need of moderator intervention`)... (At least for 0.3k-0.5k-Users..., maybe you get different Flags with more Rep...)

Comment: @chivracq "needs improvement" opens another dialog with "Needs details or clarity" and other reasons to close, it's not a "real" option.

Comment: Oh, LOL, ah-ah-ah...! Okay, indeed-indeed...! But hum, the "GUI" is really not "intuitive" I would say, the "Flag question" on all Screens/Dialogs looks very "*definitive*", I would never expect  a Follow-up Dialog to come up... There should be 3 Dots on Options that open a Follow-up Dialog...

Comment: @chivracq yes, this behavior is definitely counter-intuitive (especially given that options duplicate each other). I don't remember whether it came with the redesigns or not, though. A better UX would be to have them all top level or at least not duplicate...

Comment: Okay, I've "navigated" through all Screens/Dialogs/Options, now I understand why (in the past => maybe 6 months ago), I've had "Custom" Flags declined, because I had never "discovered" the Sub-Dialogs/Options... // Funny indeed to see that `Duplicate` (2nd Level) is a *Duplicate* (sic...!) of `a duplicate` (1st Level), ah-ah...! (Casing not even consistent...)

Comment: @chivracq - yes, the "duplicate" duplication is one of the most baffling parts of the UX the flagging dialog provides. I am sure we requested SE to flatten the structure before, and I am also sure it got ignored...

Comment: The reputation threshold for voting to close questions is way too high IMO.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel would be even better if it was meaningfully tied to successful actions like flagging for closure (when the question stays closed for a set period of time or something), but oh well, it's just passive income accumulation that counts as "experience" around here.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posts that require the OP to provide some more context or explain more of what they are trying to do or address some of the questions in the comments, you can flag it as **"Needs details or clarity"**. It is a subcategory/sub-menu of the "**needs improvement**" flag option as listed in the [What is flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) guidance.

> - **needs improvement (questions only)**
>
>   - Duplicate
>   - A community-specific reason (i.e. the question is off-topic or otherwise disallowed by the community)
>   - **Needs detail or clarity**
>   - Needs more focus
>   - Opinion-based

Selecting the  "**needs improvement**" flag option opens up another dialog of flag options):

[image: screenshot of flagging dialog]

For that particular post though, I wouldn't even call the linked photo a "real question" as it's basically a blurred and misaligned camera photo of a portion of their code and terminal. It's missing details to help in debugging the problem, such as, for example, the contents of package.json.

For that particular case, it's also appropriate to flag as "**needs improvement**" -> "**A community-specific reason**" -> "**Needs debugging details**". The OP needs to provide the necessary details to help others reproduce the problem, instead of letting the community guess what's wrong. Posting a link to a photo of code and errors also goes against our [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidance to:

> **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).