# Enhancement request: better reveal on flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-dialog

I wanted to flag a question as being off topic but since I don't flag very often I forgot which of the options allows you, in a subsequent dialog, to indicate it's off topic and that it might be on topic at another SE site. So I chose "very low quality" and I guessed wrong. I didn't get a dialog. It just went ahead and flagged it with a momentary "we'll look at it" overlay. I'm not overly concerned with having a flag rejected (which I'm sure it will be) but I think any dialog should be more helpful, especially to people who don't use a thing frequently. I think UI should be more intuitive and not require someone read another page.

This is a partial mock of the radio button dialog that I see when I click [flag]:

```
o  spam
o  rude or abusive
o  needs improvement
o  a duplicate
o  very low quality
o  in need of moderator intervention
```

Using the application menu paradigm that I often see on multiple platforms, I think there should be an ellipsis at the end of the text for options that require further user involvement. Something like the following:

```
o  spam
o  rude or abusive
o  needs improvement
o  a duplicate...
o  very low quality
o  in need of moderator intervention
```

In this example, the only difference is the ellipsis I added for the option that I know requires (or at least required) some further input from the flagger.

Comment: If the paradigm should be uniformly applied there should also be breadcrumbs after "needs improvement..." which contains a follow up flag dialogue page and "in need of moderator intervention..." which contains follow up textarea. There is [at least one CM](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54758467) who also prefers breadcrumbs on things with follow up actions (like in review queue).

Comment: You can retract the flag by going to the flag menu again. Significantly, pressing the button always submits the flag so you should make sure you have the right reason before that. As for adding ellipses, I don't think that I would understand the significance just by looking at it.

Comment: Yep, massive Support, ... and welcome to "the Club" but your Sugg/EnhReq is exactly what I mentioned recently in [this Comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419067/#comment917294_419067): "*But hum, the "GUI" is really not "intuitive" I would say, the "Flag question" on all Screens/Dialogs looks very "definitive", I would never expect a Follow-up Dialog to come up... **There should be 3 Dots on Options that open a Follow-up Dialog...***"

Comment: Very low quality on questions is the most useless flag ever. Almost all of them are declined unless they are automatically approved. Sorry that you had fallen victim to this flag type.

Comment: There used to be an ellipse after these options. Unfortunately, SE specifically removed them when the dialog and the main close reasons were last revamped.

Comment: I couldn't find the right keywords in search to locate this so I created a similar question (now closed).  I have exactly the same problem.  I suggested something like [ more ] or [ see choices ] as the indicator for the flag choices that have sub-choices instead of "..."