# Is there something wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, bounty

I recently reached out on Stack Overflow to get help with an issue. I provided detailed screenshots and the specific part of the code where I'm getting the answer, but it keeps getting downvoted and no one answers it. Is this a bad question?

[Firebase Web Read from Real-Time Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901052/firebase-web-read-from-real-time-database)

Comment: Keeps getting downvoted? It's got 1 downvote and 1 upvote, that's not most people's definition of something that keeps happening, since it happened only once.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as the linked duplicate is not appropriate at all. The linked question on main included screenshots, but it also included the code. The guidance about not uploading images of code/data/errors is intended to be for questions that *only* show the code/data/errors, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: NOTE: The OP even offered a bounty... the question in focus has a negative score at this time.

Comment: Related (posted 20 minutes later): *[How do I get unbanned from asking questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420646/)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue here (which is fairly common on sites such as this) is that you're providing screenshots, and only provide your real code much further down in the post. You write

> I'm trying to display the user's price that they entered in the database, but I'm getting "undefined' back instead of the value that was entered. I didn't get any errors in the console either. How can I fix this?

but don't even say what language you're using. I see that you use Java below, but this should be stated up front as well as likely a little more context about what the issue is.

I want to emphasize how unhelpful screenshots are—and note this isn't personal. Screenshots and images are pretty much never helpful in my history of giving help with technical answers. We're writing on computers—we need text to work with, more specifically, *code* that's presented in a clear manner. The reason for this is that it allows us to better reproduce your error, so we can get to the bottom of what the real issue is. When the question begins in a sort of vague manner, no context is given, and only later on do you get to the code, it makes it more difficult for people who want to help you. And the only way to do that is with code, not images.

I don't think the question is bad at all, since there's likely a very legitimate answer. Rather, I think that it is poorly posed, and can be improved by clear explanations and the general context of your query.

Comment: *"but don't even say what language you're using."* You don't need to tell us what language you are asking about, that's what tags are for. "I am using Java" is actually just noise, as if they are using Java then it should be tagged with Java, and this we already know what language is being asked about

Comment: I don't agree that it's just noise. But you are right, java was in the tags of the OP (at least as of now), so it was stated to begin with.

Comment: [[tag:java]] *isn't* in the tags in the linked question, [[tag:javascript]] is, which isn't the same.

Answer (score 13):

### Don't use screenshots to convey textual information

Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). The reasoning applies very broadly.

### This is not a discussion forum

Questions should be clear, explicit and **direct**. Don't tell us things that are obvious. We can see the screenshot and the code. We can see that some of the code is HTML, some is JavaScript and some is CSS; and it's normal for these things to be combined.

### Try to find problems yourself first

Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Study the behaviour of the code by yourself. Examine what happens, step by step. Make sure you have some idea of what you expect to happen at each step (in order for your logic to work as intended), and then see exactly where something different happens. When you find something specific, use a search engine to look for existing explanations - on or off Stack Overflow.

If you use `console.log` to check what the code is doing, make 100% sure you know which `console.log` call is producing what output. What does "I'm getting 'undefined' back" actually mean? What is giving you that result? What do you think the results should look like instead? Why?

If you are still stuck, create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If the problem is that the code does not successfully retrieve the price information, **why do we need to see** code that retrieves (or attempts to retrieve) several **other** pieces of information? If you remove that part of the logic, **does the error still occur**? If the problem is that reading the data does not work, why do we need to see code to set the data? **Does the code seem to behave differently** when getting data that was already in the database, vs. data that was just set by that method? Exactly what steps are required to cause the problem?

Comment: If you're using `console.log`, make sure you know about [browsers' lazy evaluation of what is being logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects) so that you are not confused about asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Examples for the last part are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863661/how-can-i-get-my-buttons-to-hide-display-properly-when-i-click-them) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841591/how-can-i-get-my-cards-to-display-and-function-properly) (about 400 lines of "code", and 700 lines of "code", respectively). References or similar could be incorporated in the answer.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861244/how-can-i-get-my-vertical-tab-button-to-switch-tabs-properly#comment130421260_73861244) it was claimed nearly 1,700 lines of "code" was the minimum.