# How can you help to improve Stack Overflow questions while you’re looking for an answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I joined Stack Overflow like one year ago and I'm sure that I'm still lacking knowledge of how to properly use it. I've read several posts from the help center and came to meta to find more information about it.  But one thing that I would like to know is which ways there are to make improvements to Stack Overflow questions while looking for an answer.

For instance, in this post that I've made, I found several related questions that have almost the same question/answer (see the last list at the end of the post). What can I do to clean them? Should I mark all of them as duplicated or try to edit them?

[How to use PostgreSQL offline local storage on a React-Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738347/how-to-use-postgresql-offline-local-storage-on-a-react-native-app#comment130232401_73738347)

On the other hand, I've asked wrong as well and I'd like to improve or delete them if it's adding noise to the search and then I found a lot of "Is there something wrong with my question?" and then I think if I ask for further explanation for my own questions being downgraded maybe I'll be adding more noise, but at the same time maybe it's something specific related to that questions.

For instance, this question has a lot of several negative votes, but it has a lot of positive votes on answers. What should I do? Edit the title? If I was the author and considering it has answers that could be resolving a problem and it'll go against the rules, I must request for a deletion?

*[Is there something wrong with my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420633/is-there-something-wrong-with-my-question)*

I just found this about [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info) (SG) and hope it works to improve this classification.

Comment: "What can I do to clean them?" - What do you mean "clean them:, if you know the answer you answer them, if you don't you do nothing.

Comment: "A lot of question about local storage and almost all answers saying to use AsyncStorage: 
    How to store data in local storage with react native?
    How do i use localstorage in React native?
    Local Storage - React Native
    React Native Local Storage Best Practice
"

I should mark all of them as duplicated. If it there are a nuance variation between questions I should edit the titles?

Comment: If an existing question, answers a question, then you should flag as a duplicate.  As somebody with 41 reputation, you can't actually cast a vote, it only throws the question into a queue so the community can vote.  I would caution flagging tons of questions all at once.

Comment: If these questions have the same answers then flag them as duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to ask multiple questions in one post. I am going to focus on one specifically here. It is not illegal on meta, but it remains a practice which causes crossed wires and asks too much of potential answerers.

> For instance, this question has a lot of several negative votes, but
> it has a lot of positive votes on answers

Caution: that's a meta post you linked to. Voting on meta works very differently because "disagree" is part of the options here. Many people choose to cast a downvote on something they disagree with on meta, rather than a post receiving dozens of comments stating as much and triggering a lot of unnecessary noise. A downvoted meta question can still have great value to it, and nothing needs to be done about it.

Now if it were a question on the main site, then editing might be required. If there is something to improve of course. When we are talking about low quality questions that may be more up to the original author though, you don't turn around a question which has reached -17 by fixing a title or improving spelling; there is something more fundamentally wrong with it.