# Add "Contains image of code" feedback in First Questions Queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-questions

A common mistake by new users is to include links to images of code or error messages, and I often see other comments with the canonical link "[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)"

This is almost exclusively a problem with new users' questions, so I feel the canonical link should be a feedback option on the First Questions Queue. Right now, I just have the canonical link bookmarked so I can quickly copy and paste it for when I need it, but it'd be much better if I could just do it from the queue.

Can/should this be added as an option for feedback?

Comment: Not only new users made this mistake. Theoretically the [meta-tag:ask-question-form] should prevent this mistake but, AFAIK, it still relies on the asker attitudes and skills.

Comment: Eh, while it would be a useful canned comment, you should be closing those questions instead

Comment: Don't the canned comments include an option to flag/vote to close?

Comment: Related: [Resolving Community user and "share feedback" issues in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272/241919), especially this part: "*We're specifically not addressing these issues right now: **Creating blanket community-specific feedback options** - this is a fairly large undertaking that we're not flat-out declining, we just don't have the resources to get to it right now.*"

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Does it? AFAIK on the First Questions Review Queue, no it doesn't. I've always had to VTC _and_ select the "Share Feedback" option to select one of the canned comments.

Comment: The question was not rhetorical. If it doesn't, IMO it should.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be included in the "**Question needs some code**" option.

As of now, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the "Question needs some code" option of the First Questions Review Queue]

Literally, an image of code is *not* code, so I usually select this option if the question is lacking the proper copy-paste-able and runnable code, then optionally add a more expanded comment explaining what *specifically* they need to add, then link to either the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help page or that [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) meta FAQ page.

I mention the "**Minimal, Reproducible Example**" page because that page already tells users not to post images of code:

> **DO NOT** use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). This helps others more easily read and test your code.

I think that the "**Question needs some code**" option can just be updated to include a link to either of those 2 help/FAQ pages. I prefer the help page because it's more related to *how* to post codes properly, as opposed to the meta FAQ page which is more of *why* someone can't post images of code (although some answers do mention the same guidance on how to format code as code).

As a side note, notice that the other option "**Question has too much code**" already has a link to the "**Minimal, Reproducible Example**" page, so, I think it's not a big leap to add it to the other one as well.

Comment: Simply adding the link requires too many logical leaps, I think.  The asker already thinks they provided the code; they're not going to read a help article and find one sentence in the middle of it that explains why someone thinks they didn't.  They'll just assume the bot is being dumb.  Perhaps if it said "Don't post links or images: include the code in the post itself." or something.