# Is it ok for a user to reject an edit and then edit on their own, but just add a few words to the edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rejected-edits

I suggested edits to a couple of questions today, mainly adding the missing images to the posts. I noticed that they were rejected by the same user, claiming that:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.
> and then went on to add a few words and post the edit...

Did I miss something? Is my edit wrong, or did I miss something based on this user's opinion?

[Reject 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33210520)

[Their addition 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74480055/revisions)

[Reject 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33210815)

[Their addition 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74480775/revisions)

I know that in the second edit I didn't really change much, but please, check what they added afterward...

Comment: "Is my edit wrong if I did miss something based on this user's opinion?" - If the edit was incomplete, then choosing, "Reject and Edit" is the correct action. I would agree with the reviewer in question decision in their selection of reject and edit.

Comment: Number 1 IMO was rightfully rejected due to the poor code formatting left in. Number 2, both yours and their edits were meh.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I knew I accidentally deleted the "addition 1" as soon as I submitted the edit and was in the process of amending that, don't be too hasty to rollback :) The rest of the edit stands in line with editing guidelines: bold formatting is excessive; gender-neutral language is preferred; proper English is an improvement.

Comment: @SecurityHound not sure what you mean. The first revision of the OP's post only contains links to questions themselves - I asked for the links to suggested edits themselves. Anyways, they are added now, so all good.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Gender neutral language is only preferred if we don't know the users actual gender (and even then preferred is a stretch), they've identified themselves as male on the account linked in their profile. The English in the last sentence was barely improved and is still poor, indeed leaving that sentence at all is worthless as it adds nothing to the question. The second actual question in the post (*"Is my edit wrong if I did miss something based on this user's opinion?"*) is also poorly phrased. Also the rollback IMO was worth it just to add the link back in.

Comment: Don't be so hasty to submit your edit without reviewing what changes you made next time /shrug

Comment: Ok thanks! Hopefully I learned something new!

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine you made the rollback less than a minute after the initial edit. I do peruse the advantage of the grace period sometimes when I accidentally miss something in the edit (no need for the snark remark, btw - there was no same intention in mine, I *was* in the process of editing it back).

Comment: To be fair, *neither* of you should have been attempting to add a screenshot of text in the first question. OP needs to copy/paste the actual text of the output into the question. They also missed a couple of the correct changes you made in the second edit (Python should be capitalized according to the official site and that package name shouldn't be formatted as code).

Comment: *"adding the missing images"*: But they are [not supposed to use images for that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). At all. Never ever. Though I am not sure how that would affect reviewing edit suggestions. Also, [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480055/) was in dire need of [articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) (some, but not all, have been added by now). The *"How to ...?"* form is broken English (it should be [QUASM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s). It has been fixed by now.).

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for the reference to the images post!

Comment: @BSMP You are right, but if a user only provides this. The only thing I could do is flag the question and at least add the screenshot so people who are atempting to anwser should at least see it, no?

Comment: @BeeFriedman downvote, VTC as "need debugging details" (missing MRE), or just skip are good options for a post with required information shown as images. If only output is in an image you can run their MRE and paste the output as text (do not transcribe images).

Answer (score 20):

Absolutely yes.

The reviewer did the right thing by rejecting these edits and making their own. An alternative would be to approve and then edit, but these edits weren't very good to be approved.

Edit no. 1 didn't remove redundant code fences and didn't indent code properly.

Edit no. 2 didn't remove "thanks", unnecessarily removed code block language and added capitalized word "Using".

There would be nothing wrong with approving these edits either, but I understand why the reviewer made the decision that they did.