# Images as overlay

Tags: feature-request, design, user-experience, images

It bothers me that, whenever I click on an image inside a post, I get redirected to the site where the image is hosted ([Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) in this case). Can we make it so images are shown as an overlay in the existing page? So I can easily go back to the post by closing the image or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

If you are familiar with [Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)) that's the exact same feature I'm after.

EDIT: For clarification I mean bigger res images, like screenshots

Comment: Images shown here as link rarely contribute for question quality, so no.

Comment: Why would pressing esc be more convenient than pressing backspace to get back to the previous page?

Comment: Lots of even low-end mice (including non-gaming mice) also have buttons that happen to be intercepted as back/forward by browsers. I fail to see why it's a problem

Comment: Images are commonly, but not always, written in Markdown such that the image is also a link. Thus, clicking on the image will typically navigate the page, or you can open a new tab with just the image. While I can understand wanting a popup with just the image, there are numerous options as to how that could be made to work. Not everyone will want such a popup. This seems like it's something that's better handled by the user installing one of at least several different available browser extensions which provide such popups for images.

Answer (score 9):

Images can be inlined in posts:

[image]

The syntax for this is to put an exclamation mark (`!`) before an ordinary Markdown link:

```
![](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/unifiedmeta/sprites.svg)
```

This is explained in the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). HTML `<img>` tags should also work.

To my understanding, new users have this functionality **deliberately** disabled, although other users can edit it back in to the post. This is because [very few things should be images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) in Stack Overflow posts, and new users are prone to misusing images. We generally want text, because we are programmers doing programming, not discussion-forum users having a discussion.

Having images show up in an overlay (a JavaScript-powered image viewer that disappears on click) or while mousing over the link, etc. etc. would be the worst of all possible worlds. For the few cases where images are appropriate, I see no good reason not to include them inline.

Comment: Inline images are disabled for low rep users primarily to prevent their use in spam and abusive posts.

Answer (score 5):

There's a userscript that accomplishes what you appear to be after, written by [@Samuel Liew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew), called [Lightbox Images](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LightboxImages.user.js).

As the name implies, it lightboxes (most) images on click, and then closes the lightbox on either click or <kbd>esc</kbd> press.

Demo:

> [image: Lightbox image behavior demo]