# How can one upload an image file larger than 2MB in size to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, images, image-upload

I am not able to upload an image file larger than 2MB in size. How can that be done?

Comment: You don't, and that you're asking this suggests that you may not be clear on how this site works and what it is for. Consider reviewing the [ask], [tour] and [help] links for information on this, but I honestly don't see how a file of that size would be 1) required to ask a focused on-topic question, or 2) small enough to expect a volunteer to review in order to answer a question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How else would I upload my super awesome screenshots of code in their full 64-bit-depth, 4K 
resolution glory?

Comment: The maximum image upload size is 2 MiB as [indicated in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jImE.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can work around the restriction by using image manipulation tools to resize the image and lower its resolution so that it becomes smaller in size, or if the image is in a format that doesn't heavily emphasize compression (Ex. PNG, TIFF), convert it to one that does (Ex. JPEG). Most OSes / OS distributions come with image manipulation tools that allow one to do those things.

As a friendly reminder, only use images when the image is *better* than text at conveying information, and where possible, add transcriptions or descriptions of information in images. For the reason why, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11107541)