# How do you make your answer stand out from the influx of generative AI content?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, new-users

I've had a few years hiatus and could not find any article that underscores this question, so please go easy on me. I also just got somewhat up to speed about the strike as [posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), so I know this impacts my Problem Statement as moderation itself has been highly impacted. My thoughts and reflections are with you.

**How does a beginner amplify a legit answer when questionable answers from other contributors are more easily upvoted, and how does a beginner go about proving their work in a way that substantiates that their work is not Generative AI Content?**

1. Throwing screenshots of your work in your favorite IDE at the server can be costly, and I've seen some threads where it seemed ill-received.
2. Using bad grammar and/or shorthand is discouraged, as it can be distracting from the flow of the answer and is viewed as non-professional.
3. "Proper" ways of answering questions have developed in the community over time and the internalization thereof can be daunting to beginners.

I'm sure this question could have been asked more succinctly, but I feel topic might help others to overcome the paralysis I've felt about contributing.

Comment: Just... write good answers and don't worry about it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Throwing screenshots of your work in your favorite IDE at the server"*?

Comment: Possibly related: *[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*

Comment: 99% of my identification of AI answers is: are they weirdly wrong (use of non existent functions or arguments, code unrelated to the question, that kind of stuff). If you make sure you properly answer a non duplicate question, your odds of being flagged as AI is low, since AI generally can't do that

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, holy smokes! Thank you for that link, it presented a couple of things I hadn't thought of such as mobile devices or images being blocked by corporate proxies. The other stuff? yeah. I've had to type character for character what's in a screenshot/snip to replicate the problem in VSCode. Sometimes a pain when you instinctively put a semicolon on the end, but they left it out...

Comment: The current crop of Artificial Intelligence certainly are artificial.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> How does a beginner amplify a legit answer

You don't. Write good answers and they'll gather upvotes.

> when questionable answers from other contributors are more easily upvoted

That's a fact of life. An upvote does not stand for *"this is a correct approach, it is maintainable, secure, tested, well-documented"*. People treat the upvote button as a button that says *"thanks"*, or *"A for effort"*, or *"I copied your code and now my compiler doesn't complain anymore"*, or *"it looks like this does something"*.

This is not at all related to generative AI. Sure, we might be on a ratio of 1 in 100 answers by now (this may be off, but not by an order of magnitude), but voting has been less than perfect since the dawn of the site.

> and how does a beginner go about proving their work in a way that substantiates that their work is not Generative AI Content?

Just don't write like a robot and you'll be fine.

> "Proper" ways of answering questions have developed in the community over time and the internalization thereof can be daunting to beginners.

I know this comes as a shock to the company and to the web at large, but getting into a community *ought* to be hard.

You can't just barge into a site where millions of people have been talking for collective aeons, shaping the way they interact by communicating, setting examples and discussing, and then act like you're [t3h PeNgU1N oF d00m](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/katy-t3h-pengu1n-of-d00m) and expect acceptance.

Take your time, [lurk](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lurker) for however long you think is appropriate, test the waters by posting an answer or two, and expect feedback and act upon it. But not always, because just like voting, giving and receiving feedback too is an art that seems to be getting lost in the sands of time...

Comment: +100 for "I know this comes as a shock to the company and to the web at large, but getting into a community *ought* to be hard.". It's unpopular, and it's the sort of thing that leads people to make unsavoury political assumptions about the speaker; but it's demonstrably correct, and countless places in "cyberspace" have paid a heavy price for supposing (or pretending) otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this candidly. I have benefitted in the past a few times when looking up solutions here, and started to contribute for the time recently. I've been ignored or downvoted, probably because I choose the KISS method rather than being overly elaborate. When I got downvoted I started to read up on how to draft a better answer, but I also found out about the strike and worried people might think a simple approach came from ChatGPT or some other clone. What you wrote on upvotes and feedback makes sense, as does community acceptance.

Comment: Bonus points for the "take your time" statement. IMO that is where Stack Overflow and modern times kind of went out of sync. Stack Overflow demands that you take your time for everything, which bites when everyone has put themselves in an artificial hurry.