# Questions not getting any responses

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Godot 3.5 adding line to PNG used as sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77191542/godot-3-5-adding-line-to-png-used-as-sprite)

I've asked two questions about something I haven't found any solution to a while ago. Despite them getting views I've had zero replies that could lead me in a good direction let alone an answer.
Any advice on how to make it more likely they will be answered?

Comment: First suggestion: improve the question as much as possible, making it as easy to answer as possible. The [ask] and [tour] links can help with this. Also, add pertinent code as code-formatted text.

Comment: Your [main] main site question *is* about a problem with your code, right?

Comment: @Programz - If your question is a programming question, then we need a MRE, but your question doesn’t have one. All your questions are similar the entire tag has that problem, except for one question, the only question with an answer. That question of course has a MRE Godot script

Comment: The problem doesn't sound like a programming problem. It's a problem of using the Godot Engine, but seems to be just about using the editor, not about the programming aspects of it. Even if it would be about programming, you would at least have to provide an image showing what is actually happening.

Comment: To make it more attractive to being responsed you allways can get some reputation by answering other questions, or post questions that world need to hear

Then you can spare some your reputation as bounty for question so more people will be interested to deep down into problem

Comment: @DamianChudobiński: that won't help if the question is off-topic as it will still likely be closed and deleted.

Comment: In my experience, game development questions are notoriously hard to put into a Stack Overflow compatible Q&A format. Especially because the source of the problem is usually unknown, game development questions asked in a discussion forum can take several pages of back and forth trying to root out the cause and then a workable solution. The fact that your title contains the words "for unknown reason" is an immediate giveaway that it is not going to be a question suitable for Stack Overflow. Maybe try finding a discussion forum, Subreddit or Discord channel dedicated to Godot.

Answer (score 11):

From your comment:

> And I provided all the relevant info I could think of that could help

Here is a short list of possibly relevant info which you have not mentioned. There might be more that I haven't thought of.

- Do you need to write any code to demonstrate the problem? If you do: are you using GDScript, C#, C++ or something else? Or is this question only about the Godot editor itself? (In the latter case, it is more likely a tech support question that is off topic for the site.)
- What exactly does this "grey line" look like? (This is one of the few cases where it is appropriate to [include an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) in a question.)
- Does the line show up **in the game** while testing it, or only in the editor and inspector?
- What changes did you try making to the "compression mode"? How exactly does this "make the problem worse"?
- How did you verify, outside of Godot, what the image is supposed to look like?
- Does the problem affect every image that you try? Just this one specific image that you've encountered? Only some images? If it's some images and not others, what else do the problematic images seem to have in common? Can you create an image from scratch that causes the problem? If so, what steps do you take to do that?

> If I still somehow have yet to meet the criteria for a question on this website please tell me. Otherwise reconsider having this question closed.

Please don't comment like this.

First off, it comes across as accusatory. People know what they're doing here, and the standards for questions are high, by design. We do need to consider the possibility that the [library](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is missing questions, because the programming world is constantly changing. But *even if we stopped allowing any new questions immediately*, we would have our hands more than full just cleaning up the mess that already exists.

Second, it's how the system works anyway. Closing a question **is injunctive, not punitive**. We are not trying to cause problems for you, we are only holding up the site's standards. Closing a question prevents people from trying to write answers, until the question is in a state where answers would be useful and beneficial to the site. When you edit a question, there is a checkbox you can use to indicate that you believe that the problem is resolved now and the question should be considered for reopening. This fast-tracks the question for consideration by those who have the privilege of voting to reopen questions, so they don't have to stumble across your question by themselves.

Sorry that your question was ignored initially. It should have been closed immediately instead, but there simply aren't a lot of people paying attention to the tags you're using. (This should be a hint that your question might be off topic.) The primary business of Stack Overflow is questions about code written in general-purpose programming languages, like C# or Python or JavaScript. By contrast, GDScript can meaningfully *only* be used within Godot, and it isn't clear that you're writing code at all. We *do* take questions that are about "visual" languages that are primarily edited in a GUI without typing out code (like LabView, Scratch etc.); and we *do* take questions about [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) and [IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) rather than the actual programming language; but there is [only so far afield](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) you can get while still being [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

If you *are* doing something that's on topic, making it clear how the question relates to a more popular tag is often the best way to make sure it gets seen by people who can answer (or who can point out other issues with the question that should prevent it from being answered).

Comment: I just added what you suggested anything else?

Comment: @Programz - The only thing you added was the image to your question.  What about the other 5+ suggestions? Your question still does not include a MRE. In any event you indicated your edits, address the reason the question was closed, and it's currently being reviewed by the community for the potential of being reopened. In other words all you can do is wait until that review happens.  A single unified would have increased the chances of the question be reopened.

Comment: What do you mean by "MRE" please tell me so I could Include it.

Comment: @Programz, MRE = Minimum Reproducible Example. That is, some snippet of source code that another anonymous user, with basically the same setup as you have, could reasonably quickly test on their own system or online. You may need to provide background details of your setup such as necessary libraries, compilers, compile/run-time switches, operating system, etc....