# What are the Stack Overflow rules for the number, type, and size of photo attachments accompanying questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, images

I am preparing to submit a question with photo attachments.

What are the Stack Overflow rules for:

1. The number of attachments that can accompany each member question
2. The types of files acceptable
3. The maximum file size for each file type

Comment: If the images just contains text, then you should include the text/code instead.

Comment: Is this a question about *Stack Overflow* (i.e. related to programming), or other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: If you have to worry about hitting a limit for image volume (size and/or amount) then very likely it is too much for Stack *Overflow*. [**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doesn't leave all that much that is appropriate to post as an image and on-topic, and even if an image is needed then often one suffices and any more just make the question harder to follow.

Comment: Note that attempting to upload an image will show the limit per file: "Max size 2 MiB"

Comment: Please before considering posting: Google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at https://meta.stackoverflow.com & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [Help] [Meta-help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: I edited "Stack Exchange" to say Stack Overflow because you posted this at SO (then it got migrated here). If you want to ask about the SE policy then post a question there. But this already has a reasonable answer post so this variant should stay here. Although it is presumably a duplicate at both sites.

Comment: Please explain *why* your question *needs* photo attachments. It is very rare for SO questions to need an image, unless (for example) it's sample data for an image processing algorithm. Another possibility is when you're doing GUI layout.

Comment: Being a new member to SE and SO, I thought these were like most other forums, where you can ask a question, get helpful replies,  and then post photos of of the completed project to let the members share in the satisfaction of accomplishment. But now that I see how SE and SO actually operates, I'll be withholding my inclination to share photos and/or comments of completed projects in the future. Sorry if this , sounds like "sour grapes", but I spent considerable time creating informative photos and wanted to share them with members, along with my thanks for the helps given.

Comment: @ToddB73 What was your project? Notice that [SO] operates in a rather different manner than other sites on the network, like [Electronics.SE]. The former deals in code, where photos are discouraged, whereas the latter requires visual information. Most users won't mind if you post an update to your question as an edit or even [as an answer](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, that Stack Overflow is not a forum, it is a Question & Answer site. That means, ask a question, get answers (or post your own answer). It is not intended for back & forths, reply threads or followups.

Answer (score 20):

On Stack Overflow you shouldn't have to worry about sizes of images because the advice to users new to the site is to not post images at all: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If you ignore that advice or you're not planning to post on Stack Overflow these are the answers to your question, [quoting Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447/158100):

> The maximum length of a post, question or answer, on Stack Overflow is 30,000 characters. This includes markdown and any other formatting. The limit on the question title is 150 characters.
>
> I don't believe there are any upper limits on the number of links and images.

The size limit for a single image is 2MB: [Image size limit: Why it is set to 2 MiB?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308507/image-size-limit-why-it-is-set-to-2-mib)