# Highlight Specific Lines of Code Snippet

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

I found a few questions that address a similar idea of code highlighting but nothing that really hits on the area that I'm referring to. Is there a use case for wanting to highlight specific lines of code similar to how GitHub does in their formatter (i.e. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L5-L7). I came across these two questions:

- [Highlighting parts of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/highlighting-parts-of-code)
- [Highlight Line of Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294592/highlight-line-of-code)

which are similar in nature but still don't quite target what I'm after, as they emphasis highlighting or noting a particular part of a line as oppose to the entire line.

The idea for doing this came to me after visiting this question: [Missed var before "I" in cycle or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280368/get-an-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined). The OP in the question posted:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` I've found that when I comment 'isEnd(bigArray[i][j]);' in the end of the code, it works.

When reviewing the code snippet though, the line `isEnd(bigArray[i][j])` is not the last line but rather nested in the last double `for` loop. It may help make questions like this a little more clear if either the OP or the answerer could highlight a particular line of a snippet to help give the reader some direction as to where the relevant portion of a particular problem (in the case of OP) or answer (in the case of the answerer) begins. Even better if we could highlight a range as in the GitHub link example that I posted above. Food for thought.

Comment: While code highlighting would be handy, most of the time (including your example) the "need" for it is actually due to poor MCVE construction (or none at all). Your request would be more compelling if you could find an example where a long body of coded was actually necessary and where one particular line was more important than the rest. I think that scenario is rare, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing stopping people (in JS anyway) from putting inline comments in their code `isEnd(bigArray[i][j]); // Here's where the error occurs`.

Comment: @JDB This is true. I'll have to do some digging and see if I can find one of those gems that would demonstrate that. If I have to dig too much though, I have a feeling that that is the answer, nice to have but unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan True but not as clean or intuitive from a quick glance as the GitHub version of highlighting.

Comment: @JDB I think the this is more common than it seems
In a question [like this][1], was necessary to copying code from snippet to demonstrate the problem and added comments to the code, which is not very didactic because it forces the user to read the code to understand the problem.


[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871074/decoupled-components-with-centralized-states-in-vuex-vue-router

Comment: It could simply be reference them by line. This would make it easier on two occasions

1. Exemplify the problem by reference codesnippet lines
2. When replying, citing as possible lines to chage or with errors

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica Most likely scenario is when you have to include lots of boilerplate code due to using a front-end framework like `angularjs`. Even if your question is about 5 lines of code that would be sufficient for the readers to help, you often need to add a lot of more code to make a working snippet.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Adding comments to JSON and HTML is often quite inconvenient, ugly and can break the code.