# CommonMark support on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, markdown

Is there any kind of "report" on what features Stack Exchange currently supports from the new [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) standard?

I'd like to know if I can use [the specification](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html) as a guideline for all Stack Exchange posts, or if there are features that are currently absent.

Comment: CommonMark is *brand new* and there is no such list at the moment. There are plans to support it *eventually*, see [Will CommonMark be adopted for SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238959)

Comment: That said, Stack Exchange does a very decent job of implementing Markdown and the differences between CommonMark and the implementation here are limited to the nitty gritty details.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link, i searched for CommonMark and got no results, guess I should've search on meta StackExchange instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The difference between SE markdown and CommonMark might not be big.. but the way you have to indent code drives me nuts.

Comment: @Unidan? Reddit Unidan?

Comment: @Unidan: meh, `⌘-K` works fine for me there (`CTRL-K` when not on Mac).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Had no idea that existed.. Thanks! Also, Reddit yes. But I'm not the real one (see my avatar - he got banned because of a comment about jackdaws).

Comment: @Unidan: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Are there any news of support for GitHub-style code quoting? http://spec.commonmark.org/0.24/#example-106

Answer (score 3):

This month, [the Stack Exchange network will migrate to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232). This very site, Meta Stack Overflow, [has already been migrated this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348750/295232) and Stack Overflow itself will follow later.