# Code Sample doesn't display when it starts with a <I

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521019/227436):

It has this code snippet:

```
< Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Workflow.Targets" />
```

If you attempt to edit the question, and remove the space between the `<` and `Import`, the code snippet disappears completely from the answer in the preview window, as well as when you actually post it, since I didn't see it when I first read the answer, and had to edit it.

Funny thing though, is it works fine here?

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Workflow.Targets" />
```

I'm running Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 m, which is currently the up-to-date version.

Comment: Fixed it for you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an indentation issue. While four spaces normally mean "treat this paragraph as a code block," it happens in a list that four spaces mean "keep this paragraph under the same list item as above".

Because you're not actually in a code block, the Markdown interpreter tries to render your `<...>` element as HTML, as it would with `<i>some text</i>`, etc. If you don't include an HTML-like tag (as you do when you separate the leading `<` with a space), you see that the text is formatted as plain text, instead of as a code block.

Indent your in-list code with eight spaces instead.

This behavior is addressed in [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) under "*Code within a blockquote or list*".

Comment: Add indentation, indeed. But another option people often don't think about, is to just add a HTML comment above it: `<!---->`, [as I've done to that answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26521019/5)

Comment: @Cerbrus That solution works but is subtly different: in that case, the code block will be rendered outside the list instead of as a follow-on paragraph under the preceding list item.

Comment: True that. Depends on what you want :)