# Backslash inside backquotes in a comment

Tags: bug, comments

I recently [posted a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691043/haskell-getting-parse-error-on-input#comment41979199_26691043) where I wanted to present =\ inside backquotes. However, the backslash escapes the final backquote (which makes some sense). I tried using double backslashes, but this still didn't get the effect I wanted. How do I put a backslash inside backquotes? (Or is this a bug in the comment parser?)

Comment: Maybe this `=\ ` (space after `\ `)

Comment: "_Note that `=\ ` is an operator in and of itself. Since you want to assign a lambda expression to the name add, you need a space: `= \ `_"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/backslash-escaped-with-backticks-rendered-incorrectly-in-comments

Comment: @Mat okay...adding a space kind of works.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use double backticks like this:

```
``=\``
```

## Why?

In standard Markdown syntax, you include a literal backtick inside a code span by using multiple backticks to delimit the span, e.g.

```
``There is a literal backtick (`) here.``
```

produces

```
There is a literal backtick (`) here.
```

This doesn't work, however, for strings that begin or end with a literal backtick. To include a literal backtick at the beginning or end of a code span in standard Markdown, you need to separate the double backticks from the string with a space, e.g.

```
`` CREATE TABLE `foo` ``
```

produces

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`
```

Comments only support a subset of Markdown, though, and [the additional space in the delimiter is not supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Instead, Stack Exchange's Markdown parser allows you to escape a single backtick in a code span inside a comment by using a backslash, e.g.

```
`There is a literal backtick (\`) here.`
```

This means that you can't end the string with a backslash, or you will be escaping the closing backtick in the code span, e.g.

```
`C:\`
```

in a comment produces

```
`C:`
```

If the delimiter is a *pair* of backticks, on the other hand, the backslash no longer acts as an escape, so you can put it at the end of the code span:

```
``C:\``
```

Comment: See? It works: ``=\``

Comment: Yay, this works too: ``\\``.

Comment: ``\`` this is new to me