# Why is not all the code formatted as code in my comment?

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

I've added a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176327/create-a-bat-file-to-copy-a-database-from-a-network-server-to-local-pc-c-users), but as you can see there's something wrong in the formatting: I've used backticks on two places, and it works on the first, but not on the second place, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What's wrong?

Comment: This happened because you put a backslash before the closing backtick (see the Markdown by entering your comment link [here](https://tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment)). In these cases, enclose the code in two backticks. `\`\`stuff\`\``

Comment: Did you already try putting a backslash after the username ( `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` )?

Comment: @double-beep: That's weird: here I'm not able to reproduce it.

Comment: Why not? `\`\`stuff\\`\`` renders as ``stuff\``

Comment: @Dominique You wrote `⟨backtick⟩C:\Users\%USERNAME%\⟨backtick⟩`, right? Then you need to type `⟨backtick⟩⟨backtick⟩C:\Users\%USERNAME%\⟨backtick⟩⟨backtick⟩`.

Comment: @user4642212: I understand what I should do in such a case, but what I don't understand is that, when I copy/paste the comment here, the problem seems not to occur.

Comment: Well, if you type `\`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\\``, you get `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\`. The backslash at the end is key.

Comment: Ah. Now I understand it. Sorry. (I had tried to edit the original comment in order to see the original one, but it didn't work (after a while you can't edit (or view original) comments anymore)).

Comment: @user4642212: please mention your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Why me? @double-beep suggested the solution.

Comment: This can likely be closed as a duplicate of [Backslash at end of backtick-enclosed code span escapes last backtick in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275886/4642212) anyway.