# Code formatting results in post body and comments becoming different

Tags: bug

Literal code: `` `\` ``

What you see in the post body: `\`

---

**Update**: Your vote made me wonder if it was a problem with my browser. Isn't that what you see? The same code, but a different display.

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Update 2**: I have a comment underneath, and it used the same code above, but I can only see two backticks abreast. I suppose to see the same as in this article (a slash with gray background), just like other characters.

Can anyone leave a comment to tell me where the problem lies? Is it not clear enough or do you think this is not a bug at all?

Comment: What you see in the comment: `\`

Comment: how many "\" characters did you intend to show? one or two?

Comment: I intend to show one slash.

Comment: Then we are looking at the same thing. If you intend to show two then it gets tricky due to the escaping

Comment: Do you mean that you can see one in my first comment?

Comment: Comment, no. Due to the escaping. You can put two `\\` (you will see one) between the backticks, or just leave it as \\

Comment: If I use two slashes I just see "backtick slash backtick" in the comment, I suppose to see the same as in the article (a slash with a gray background).

Comment: Comments and posts aren't intended to be formatted the same - hence https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: The highest scored (second-order) duplicate is *[Backslash inside backquotes in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275886/backslash-inside-backquotes-in-a-comment)*.

Answer (score -1):

There is some inconsistency with the escaping that happens in the post body (what you described as article) vs comments, but not sure if this a bug.

Comment: For comparison, as a comment: ` \` (one slash but you see nothing) `\\` (two slashes but you see one)