# Space after ` not counting as code

Tags: support, markdown

I was making a comment on a post (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590894/4141219), and I discovered that `` ` = 1` `` (mind the space after the first `` ` `` ) isn't transformed into code. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: Like this: ` = 1`

Comment: Spaces around backticks is not supported in comments. See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/168244)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Markdown has to walk a fine line between a `` ` `` backtick is just a backtick or part of the mark-up. As such whitespace around a backtick means it is not part of the mark-up.

The [Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) says this about using markup for italics and bold:

> But if you surround an `*` or `_` with spaces, it’ll be treated as a literal asterisk or underscore.

The same applies to backticks. If you *have* to include a space, use the `<code>` tag and a `&nbsp;` HTML entity:

```
<code>&nbsp;= 1</code>
```

becomes  `= 1` when used inline.

Comment: "whitespace around a backtick means it is not part of the mark-up." Not exactly true, since the spec treats balanced pairs of backticks with a leading/trailing space as code spans, e.g. `\` foo \``, `\`\`\` foo \`\`\``. Stack Exchange's Markdown parser doesn't follow the spec for comments, so even though `\` foo \`` in a question or answer produces the highlighted code span `foo` (with no spaces), in a comment it produces two literal backticks, i.e. ` foo `. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/176646

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: eventually, Stack Exchange will move to Common Mark (which is far better worked out as a specification) and hopefully that'll mean backtick support will be more consistent between comments and body text as well.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: note that in my edit to the question, I already used the multiple-backticks trick to mark up the markdown source.

Comment: I see that. Just pointing out that your wording in that sentence isn't totally accurate. Consistent handling between comments and regular posts would be great; there are a fair number of questions about it on Meta.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: but I am talking about a *single* backtick. I didn't think that muddling the waters some more about multiple backticks on either side was going to help here, especially since you still cannot use those to include leading or trailing whitespace.