# Writing a code sample is ugly

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Is SO against including code samples with questions or answers.

Because

1. The answer input box is *very small*. It doesn't auto expand to fit it's contents when editing a question/answer. And doesn't remember that you've expanded it before either.
2. Pasting in code samples results in a jumble of words. The answer window is about 630px wide, despite having over 1200px of screen space available to it on my device.

With code samples we have to contend with:

1. Line wrapping breaks the layout of the code (when writing the code)
2. The invisible whitespacing becomes significant for formatting, making correcting said layout harder.

   3. Re-indenting code is hard because you can't use the tab key, nor see the whitespace. Trying to re-indent code with line wrapping is a nightmare.

I'd love SO to implement some pop-out modal where code can be pasted in and edited in something code friendly. Then the modal will just insert the correctly formatted code sample into the question/answer text. *A popup that can handle langauges other than JavaScript and CSS.*  The current modal also only allows you to edit code that was created with that modal in the first place.

I could edit my code in a code editor and then paste that. But generally when I see something I can answer I paste in some code I've used before and then edit out the bits that are not relevant to craft my answer within the site, otherwise the UX is just a barrier to writing good answers.

**I guess what I am asking for is a JavaScript IDE like [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or equivalent to pop out where I can edit my code sample nicely in a bunch of different languages. Then insert the correctly indented code sample giving my answer a nice organised layout, and readers an improved reading experience.**

Comment: There already is such a pop-out modal available, just click the "code snippet" button ?

Comment: There is a resizing bar at the bottom of the answer window, you can drag that down if you don't like the default size..

Comment: @adeneo: but that's only for HTML, CSS and JS code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: You can use the CTRL-K (CMD-K) or toolbar button to handle the indentation. The answer box is *not* meant to be a code editor. Use a code editor if you need to format the code some more before pasting.

Comment: Okay fair play I had *never* noticed that 'code snippet' till you pointed it out. So thanks for that. But yes, it's also just for JS. I pasted in some code to test and it still got the indentation all wrong and it adds a 'run' button even if you paste in another programming language like C#.  Hadn't heard of CTRL+K either, but that still didn't get the indentation correct (wobbly lines), although it did improve it. I know the answer window can be expanded, but the preference is not stored. Nor does it auto-expand to fit contents on entry when editing. Still doesn't solve significant whitespace

Comment: Have to agree, it is a pain to format copy&paste code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is not a 'how do I' - it's a 'the current system has poor UX'.

Comment: @simbolo: if the lines go 'wobbly' you are probably mixing tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Those must be the spaces added by the answer window itself when trying to formatting the code into a block.  In either case, tabs vs spaces isn't something I should have to care about when writing my answer when some JS running on the textarea can just figure it out for me. CodeMirror for example is able to format loads of different languages.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the default layout is a bit restrictive, however there are a couple of issues to consider when debating how big it should be.

First, you cannot change the width. This is actually a good thing because it forces you to consider the same width that will be applied once the answer is posted, and ultimately the end display is more important.

Then we have the height. It would be nice for it to be larger by default, however you need to consider that the answer box is always visible. This would be a long answer box would by a bit of an eyesore if you didn't want to use it at all. It always make it more annoying to scroll to anything below the answer box. Keeping it relatively small, makes the page simpler to navigate.

Having said that, a potential solution might be to not show the answer box by default. Instead you have a button called "Answer Question", which when clicked will show the answer box, which can be larger than the current default size without having to worry about the initial page layout. This could also open the doors for providing a more dedicated "answer dialog" which can be more feature rich without having to worry about fitting in nicely. Just thinking out loud at this point.

Comment: I agree with the column width in the final answer, but when editing, it's useful to have the extra space available to edit in, with a column guide to help you. After all SO doesn't truncate lines of code and instead has a horizontal scroll bar on the block. Also the answer window can auto-expand to fit content, and have the window scroll instead, this would eliminate having to have a large answer window to start with. If I write a long answer, I should have a long growing box to type into.

Comment: @simbolo: That is true, and I am pretty sure it used to have a guideline a while back. Obviously the decision makers didn't like that