# format text using blockquotes

Tags: support, editor

There is something with stackoverflow editor that's making me crazy.

I use block quotes to quote a text (obvious), to print an output or, in java, to print an stacktrace. However, it doesn't respect end of lines or indentation, which makes text unreadable.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdf"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
>       at test.StackOverflow.main(StackOverflow.java:15)

So, I have to put a `<br/>` tag after each line, which is tedious and I didn't find any solution with indentation.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdf" 
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48) 
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449) 
>                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499) 
>       at test.StackOverflow.main(StackOverflow.java:15)

I know I could use `code`, `4 spaces` or `{}` tags, but I usually use it for code, and not for quoting.

I took a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), but it uses `{}` for quoting.

Is there a way to make this kind of things more readable with block quotes?

Comment: Sure, you can make it more readable with `<br>`.  If you don't want to take the time then simply format it as a code block, nobody will hold it against you.

Comment: That's not the answer is expected. To make good questions and get or give good answers, it's important that questions/answers would be readable. That was the point of my question. An stacktrace could be very large and I thought there was a way to format it appropriately. I'll use `code` tags. Thanks.

Comment: Two spaces at the end of the line is equivalent to a line break.