# Should a stack trace be formatted as code or as a blockquote?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question [How to find an (informative) stack trace of unknown exception thrown by Swing components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524138/how-to-find-an-informative-stack-trace-of-unknown-exception-thrown-by-swing-co?noredirect=1#comment51009532_31524138) about 10 minutes ago, and it was immediately edited because the stack trace I posted was formatted as **code** and not as a **blockquote** (and, worth noting: edited BACK about 5 minutes later by someone else). I didn't disagree with the edit (because stack traces are not technically code), but it did make the stack trace virtually unreadable. I'll post it here for the sake of illustration:

**Code format**:

```
Thread : AWT-EventQueue-2
   Thread[AWT-EventQueue-2,6,javawsApplicationThreadGroup]

Error Message:
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Error String:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

StackTrace: class java.lang.ClassCastException
   java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter$ComparableComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.compare(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.access$100(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(Unknown Source)
   java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(Unknown Source)
   java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
   java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sortExistingData(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.toggleSortOrder(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Blockquote format**:

> Thread : AWT-EventQueue-2
>          Thread[AWT-EventQueue-2,6,javawsApplicationThreadGroup]
>       Error Message:
>       java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>       Error String:
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>       StackTrace: class java.lang.ClassCastException
>          java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter$ComparableComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.compare(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.access$100(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(Unknown Source)
>          java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(Unknown Source)
>          java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
>          java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sortExistingData(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.toggleSortOrder(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>          javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>          java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>          java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>          java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>          java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>          java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>          java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Some related meta posts:

- This meta post addresses the same problem: [format text using blockquotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290949/format-text-using-blockquotes)
- This meta post is a larger discussion about block quotes and readability (should blockquotes be used when practical [readable] or principally [on everything that is not code]): [Was I wrong to make this edit adding blockquotes to external content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297578/was-i-wrong-to-make-this-edit-adding-blockquotes-to-external-content/297585#297585)

So, the question: should a stack trace be formatted as code or as block quote?

Comment: I know Martijn recommended code formatting without syntax highlighting (using `<!-- language: lang-none -->`)

Comment: It just depends on preference.