# Highlight the preview on the Ask Question page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users, question-quality

I can't count the number of simple errors in questions that a *glance* at the preview would highlight for the person posting them, such as

- HTML not showing up because it hasn't been marked up
- Code not marked up and so shown as word-wrapped text
- [`enter code here`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295509/beware-all-ye-who-enter-code-here)

And yet, even though they have to scroll past it to click the [Post Your Question] button, new users don't seem to look at the preview *at all*. I suspect it's partially because the preview isn't called out in any way, it just looks like text on the Ask Question page, and as we know People Don't Read, they just scan for the nice button.

For instance, right now, this what the page is showing me:

[image: Standard Ask Question page]

But this is what I see:

[image: Ask Question page with everything but the question and the Post Your Question button greyed out and blurry]

Perhaps we could highlight and identify the preview, to at least increase the odds of the user taking notice of it before they click? Something like:

[image: Ask Question page with preview area colored and labelled, with a "Read the Preview before posting" list above the Post Your Question button]

Changes:

- Label the preview "Preview - This is what your question is going to look like" *(excellent wording improvement from [deceze](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze))*.
- Set it off from other text with a background (or something).
- Add "Read the Preview above before posting" with a list of things to check. **Most people won't read this**, but hey, we can hope for some.

Obviously that's just an initial draft, we'd want design it properly and road-test it.

---

And a follow-on specific to new users: [*Require new users to check the preview before posting*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295683/require-new-users-to-check-the-preview-before-posting)

Comment: *Read the Question* Oh yes I want that! (Maybe if it gets implemented it should be checkboxes, so that the asker actually have to active do something to click on the boxes)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process

Comment: @Rizier123: :-) It's ***really tempting*** to make them checkboxes, isn't it? Perhaps just for new users. But probably overkill. We don't want *barriers* to questions, just encouragement of properly-asked questions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah it is :) I think otherwise it won't help much, since the people still just can click "post". (But every improvement is an improvement, so I would also be happy with this change). Another thing would also be maybe to put the "edit"  button for new users in bigger font, since I have this situation very often, that they don't know how to edit their question (.. and ending up posting additional question stuff as answers (Since the answer button is bigger and more shiny than the little edit button)).

Comment: I've thought about this, recently, and the best compromise I could think of was – as you suggest – a highlight on the preview to distinguish it, with a checkbox ("yes, this is what I want") as suggested, if the checkbox is not ticked then hotting the "Post your question" link should bring up a light box with an obvious "this what your question looks like; are you sure it's ready and presentable?" with buttons to post the question or to go back and edit further. Which seems porous enough to not be too much of a hindrance, but I've not really dwelt on it.

Comment: @DavidThomas: +1 to that, contingent on it going away once you hit the "remove new user restrictions" rep level.

Comment: Bonus: this might even prevent some questions which exist only because OP's text editor doesn't have a proper syntactic coloring making the error obvious.

Comment: Related: users too often don't look at similar answers. I have no proposal for that, just pointing it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please can we also make the edit button for new users in **bold**, just happened as usual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572027/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bindparam-on-a-non-object-registration#comment49214966_30572027 I mean not much, but just a little bit: http://imgur.com/PfFnCOD :)

Comment: @Rizier123 You should post that as a separate feature request - although related, it's completely distinct from this one.

Comment: I don't think we should have a different colored background for the preview, because then someone will complain that the actual question **does not** have the colored background they saw in the preview.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: LOL! Fair point. We want *something* to call it out.

Answer (score 6):

> (Maybe if it gets implemented it should be checkboxes, so that the asker actually have to active do something to click on the boxes) –  Rizier123
>
> @Rizier123: :-) It's really tempting to make them checkboxes, isn't it? Perhaps just for new users. But probably overkill. We don't want barriers to questions, just encouragement of properly-asked questions. –  T.J. Crowder

Wait, we don't want barriers to questions?

I would support making them checkboxes, and don't let the user post until they're all checked.

Yes, some people will just automatically check them without going over their post. Those people are hopeless. But for the people who do want to do things right but don't know how, this can be very helpful.

Comment: *"Wait, we don't want barriers to questions?"* Well, it's the classic thing, isn't it? We want barriers to *bad* questions, but we don't want barriers to *good* questions. [Podcast #23](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W25450) flags up that being really "low friction" was an important aspect of the site early on. We've compromised on that a couple of ways since (requiring registration, for instance), and that's natural, and maybe we need to compromise that further here, but *in general*, we want to increase friction only to the degree it improves quality, and not one bit more.

Answer (score 2):

> - Set it off from other text with a background (or something).
> - Add "Read the Question Preview above before posting" with a list of things to check. Most people won't read this, but hey, we can hope for
>     some.

I don't think those points would help in the least. You can highlight things all you want and point big fat arrows to it, people who do not want to see won't see it either way. What colour the "yadayadayada" between the textarea and the submit button has is pretty irrelevant for someone scrolling right over it.

It is telling that often questions which are clearly missing their HTML stay that way *forever*. Even after posting the question the OP does not notice! Or if they notice, they don't know how to fix it. Or perhaps they believe that *"it's a problem with my browser and others must surely see it okay because I've pasted it into the textbox after all, right?"*

Nothing will help those people, we do not need to clutter up the UI even further.

> - Label the preview "Question Preview".

That I can get on board with. The preview should clearly be labeled as *"This is what your question is going to look like: ..."* – It will clarify things for the few people who *do* pay attention. To help those along further, you should add a *"...doesn't look like you expected? Read the [Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295449/476)."*

Beyond this, adding more text and having people jump through more hoops and checkboxes probably won't do much. People are great at ignoring messages and clicking the buttons.

---

If anything, presenting an entirely different UI *may* do something. I can imagine this scenario is somewhat common:

- user's screen is not tall enough to show the textbox *and* preview on the same screen
- user doesn't know there is a preview
- user pastes a bunch of HTML into the textbox
- user scrolls down to look for the submit button
- user scrolls past a mostly empty preview and/or ignores the bit of text which may be in there, shrugging
- user clicks submit

The problem here may be that there's no mental connection or expectation between the text input and a live preview, because the preview is not seen during text input. If you'd put both **side by side**, that connection would be a lot harder to miss. That may be a UI change which would reach many more users.

Comment: So in summary: There's no point in UI design at all. I can't agree. :-) There entire field of user interface design is predicated on the demonstrated fact that yes, the UI can influence the behavior of the person using it.

Comment: Sounds like I'm saying that, doesn't it? :o) I don't really mean it that extreme. What I would agree with is that the preview should clearly be labeled as *"This is what your question will look like:"*... This might remove some confusion for some users who do pay attention. However, I don't think you can get a user to pay attention who doesn't pay any right now.

Comment: :-) There are users we will never reach, no question about that. And we've all interacted with them. (You fix their question, they say thanks, and then just keep posting rubbish.) If we reach *some*, and we've probably interacted with them too, that's an improvement. I think we would.

Comment: Amended to be a bit more constructive... :)

Comment: Just to flag it up: You've mentioned checkboxes and hoops. I'm not suggesting any checkboxes. Nor any further hoops (in *this* feature request; [the other one I marked related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295683/require-new-users-to-check-the-preview-before-posting) could be called a hoop.)

Comment: I really like *"This is what your question is going to look like"*, stealing that. :-)