# It should be made more clear for the new users, that they can preview the post

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

So that we don't get such questions:

> [image]

I propose to add the "**Preview**" header above the preview...

> [image]

... and take the user to the confirmation page upon clicking "post question"...

> [image]

..., both until the user reaches 100 rep.

This could lessen the amount of lazily-formatted questions from the new users.

As [Josh suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310578/it-should-be-made-more-clear-for-the-new-users-that-they-can-preview-the-post#comment272688_310578), there needs to be "some indication that formatting is available". I think that the formatting-help sidebar which appears while you're typing your post would suffice in the confirmation too:

> [image]

(Something similar would not harm to be made with the answers)

Comment: Wow! Great idea! :D

Comment: The confirmation page would need some indication that formatting is available and should be applied; otherwise why would the user say anything other than "okay, looks great, why are you telling me this"?

Comment: @Josh Agree; edited. On "should be applied" - I believe that user can decide themselves, whether they like the look of their questions or not.

Comment: Maybe do it like apple with their conformation dialog and let the sidebar shake a little to catch the users attention :)

Comment: I'd prefer a modal that pops up on the Submit button showing what the post looks like, asking for confirmation. Or if that's too much, a line somewhere that says in bold **"If your question has code, please put the code on a new line and indent by four spaces"**

Comment: Rather than a second "Post Your Question" button, how about changing the text to "Formatting Is Good" or similar. That way the user knows that they are agreeing that the post aesthetically goods lood, rather than asking about the content.

Comment: How about two buttons? *Formatting is good* and *Nah, Give me down vote already*

Comment: Similar things have been asked for in the past, including http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295683/215552 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295682/215552... Not sure that this is necessarily a duplicate of either of those though...

Comment: I know a while back Tim Post was saying he was working on a very very long term new ask page.

Comment: Wonderful proposal.  Well-thought out, and almost surely would help curb the current editing situation, which is really getting to be a mess. It seems like at least 60% of newbies don't know that they can/should format code to look like code.  I'd venture that this could easily \reduce at least 25% of the unformatted-code-posts.  Maybe even better, it'd make it easier to downvote the ones who are too hard-headed about it

Comment: I'd love to see the markup and formatted stuff side by side. Nothing grates on me more than having to scroll up and down to see if what I'm typing in looks like crap. But since I'd like to see that for me (somewhat more than 100 rep), I guess that's a totally *different* proposal to this one :-)

Comment: Is 100 rep high enough? You can get straight to 101 just by linking your new SO account with an equally new one on `medievaltortureimplements.stackexchange.com`, so 100 does not *necessarily* indicate that you have any idea how to format posts.

Comment: I don't see the portion on possible duplicate questions.. which takes precedence over formatting and previewing panel of a dupe. imo, confirmation page is unnecessary; either way, formatting syntax on a confirmation page (post/question confirmation/pending state) doesn't seem sensible.  you don't want to introduce concepts and features down the line...

Comment: @paxdiablo, you gain that 100 rep from trust... do you not share in that trust :P

Comment: Actually, just qualify - if you can, please - **more clear**.. to make it clearer to me o_0

Comment: @Brett, I trust users with rep yes, since they've earned it. Well, as far as I trust *anyone* :-) But, to get 101, isn't all you need to do is create two new accounts and link them together? How would that be trustworthy? Actually, I might just go check my facts, yes, that would be a good idea on my part.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I thought that 100 rep was because I was already a member for 1 year (earning that 100 rep).. I didn't scrutinize it (nor your claim that is all it takes to get it), to be honest...

Comment: Hmm, http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation doesn't seem to be clear as to whether the site association bonus and the +100 for a 200-rep user joining another site are the same thing so I'm not sure. Still, it's a configuration item and doesn't affect the proposal itself.

Comment: @paxdiablo .. indeed, it should explicitly qualify the term 'site association' there, but it seems 200 rep designates one as an experience Stack Exchange user, and 100 rep will 'get you past basic new user restrictions'..  in that case, 100 rep for this confirmation page concept seems well termed.

Comment: How about instead of the confirmation being rep-tied, make it just option-tied? Like, `"Don't show me again"`. I personally wouldn't mind the confirmation and might find it welcome as just kind of way to get me into the rhythm of double-checking (occasionally I make the embarrassing mistake of hastily editing with a rogue copy/paste redundant text, and then have to edit again after posting). This way we don't have to worry how many points a user has -- it can show up until they opt out (but on by default for new people so that they're typically made to go through that motion at least once).