# Why *do* people post code as images?

Tags: discussion

After seeing many posts that contain code as images, I start to wonder exactly why do people do this. I myself have never thought about posting code as images. "code is text, and I can insert text in the question editor, so it is only natural to add code as text" is my thought process.

What are some possible reasons why people post code as images?

Why I asked this question:

If we figure this out, we might be able to stop more people from posting code as images before the question is posted, might we not? Say for example that actually users don't think of code as text. Then we should add an "add my code" button that shows a text box for you to put your code in. This can make it very clear that "code is text and not images".

Comment: We can only guess why people do this. Maybe to preserve code formatting and syntax highlighting, because they are not familiar with SO's formatting options?

Comment: Because they hate me, specifically. But I think honk is right for most cases. If the question is homework, it could be that they posted an images specifically to prevent it from being searchable. And I once saw a question with a bunch of screenshots of code and the OP said it was because the site was preventing them from posting a question that was mostly code.

Comment: @honk we are not limited to guessing. There’s gotta be some people who used to post code as images and then got corrected. They can share why they did it.

Comment: A lack of most basic programming skills,  I suspect.

Comment: With an image you can skip the "select" step and you don't have to worry about how this markdown stuff works, in the image it already looks fabulous. Laziness could be a driver. Maybe we should also answer with an image, blurred.

Comment: So are you hoping that someone who does this sort of thing comes along and answers this?

Comment: @rene: Maybe images posted by new users should be blurred automatically: "Welcome, we smoothed your image for you to give it a cosy touch..." ;)

Comment: Something I'd like to add is that I've seen lots of screenshots of browsers' DOM inspectors, and while many people insist that those DOMs be represented as plain-text markup, most browsers don't accurately represent the DOM in the first place, so providing a markup-serialized version of the DOM is unlikely to be useful in most non-trivial scenarios, and at worst can be misleading.

Comment: Honestly, giving the benefit of the doubt, I believe most think that there's more information to be gleaned from a screenshot of their environment than the plaintext extracted therefrom. I mean, it takes more effort to do a screenshot than a simple copy/paste, doesn't it?

Comment: @BoltClock Usually in those cases, just add the source HTML/JS/CSS instead. Then everyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MikeM. Assuming the problem can be reproduced with a single source file (that is, it's a MCVE)

Comment: @user202729: Yeah, optimally the source markup + its DOM representation (either a description or a screenshot if it defies description).

Comment: @user202729 Even with multiple files (and, trust me, we get a _lot_ of those in [android]), I think that users just believe (incorrectly) that screenshots are more informative, more helpful, in solving the issue at hand. I'm just speculating, here, though.

Comment: These are not experienced programmers.  They use the same way they asked for help with their computer before, the Print Screen key is a tempting solution to all those problems.  Another standard problem they have is confusing the name of their IDE with the name of the language they use.

Comment: Another possible reason is feeling they have no alternatives because the usual ways of copying and pasting do not work (I'm looking at you, cmd.exe).

Comment: @duplode: You are using an outdated version of CMD. In Windows 10, Ctrl + A, Ctrl + C works just fine ([introduced with conhost.exe](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)). Yes, not like the first 30 years, but better late than never.

Comment: Mark and copy text in cmd.exe was already possible in win95 and earlier.

Comment: Just an anecdote: in my former job customers sent error messages of our OS as screenshots of the debugger... Embedded in a Word or Powerpoint document! A plain screenshot would have been an improvement already.

Comment: Those are programmers that actually care about immutability.

Comment: If you click the **Ask Question** button, the page displayed says nothing about posting code as text rather than as an image. Is there a good reason for not simply stating _"Please post code as text, not as an image."_ on that page? It can't hurt, and it may be helpful. There is plenty of unused space available to add that, plus other suggestions that might be helpful for new posters. Such messages could even be shown or hidden based on the poster's level of experience on SO.

Comment: A gentle nudge can work wonders.

Comment: Because, frankly, the code handling in the editor is garbage. It just never comes out right the first time. And I know my way around MD. Indenting is a pain (no smart tabs) and the editor is horizontally too small to handle longer lines or anything indented more than 2 levels. I usually first paste my code in Npp or Code, format it there and then post.

Comment: I've used a clunky workflow similar to @Lennart for my answers, there's always at least two levels of indentation to undo, so it looks like (e.g., for C#) 1) copy / paste into npp, 2) undo the `namespace` and `class` indentation, 3) paste into the answer box, 4) apply any syntax highlighting if the page can't figure it out by pasting a hint line from the Meta.SE (I usually forget which SE the FAQ is on) post, 5) hit the "code" button to re-indent it (which feels a bit weird), 6) mess with any formatting issues with bulleted lists, etc. I think this workflow could use some improvement.

Comment: Something as simple as adding support for the triple backtick (```) like Gitlab has instead of using indents for code could help a lot, IMO.

Comment: We could **try** to [cut them off at source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475)

Comment: @jrh You can hold down Alt while selecting to get the block select function in VS.

Comment: Oh also, FWIW, issues with code formatting is a very common issue I see in posts, it's something very easy to fix when you know how but I I've had to coach even high rep users through this sort of thing. Maybe this is worth making a FAQ post I can link saying "Your post has indentation problems / [syntax highlighting problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26013972/4975230) / doesn't jive with the bulleted lists / [didn't appease the markdown spirits in some other way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322252/4975230)". Right now IIRC it's split between 2-3 places.

Comment: As you can see from [my edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4975230/jrh?tab=activity&sort=revisions), especially VB.NET has problems with syntax highlighting, if any of you high rep users are bored look on the [.net] tag for questions that are about the framework but have sample code in answers or questions that are in a specific language. Questions tagged both [C#] and [VB.NET] tend to be hit hard by incorrect syntax highlighting too.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As one of many reasons I'd guess a number of people struggle with copy and pasting the code and eventually give up and take a screenshot instead. Reasons for struggling include:

- Using tabs which messes up indentation when pasted here.

  - Evidence: Every time a post has messed up indentation, it often contains tabs.
  - Possible solution: Improve editor support for handling/converting tabs.
- No understanding of Markdown and no idea how to get their code formatted nicely. If you have absolutely no idea and no expectation that various plaintext conventions will actually *do* something, Markdown can be quite flabbergasting for newbies.

  - Evidence:

    - People leaving their code in a messy state, probably thinking it's just on their machine for whatever reason, hoping for something or someone to fix it, or just having given up.
    - People adding `<br>` tags on every line manually.
    - People using `inline code` for multiline pastes, likely because they clicked the <kbd>{}</kbd> button and it told them to `enter code here`.
    - People manually adding `<pre>` and/or `<code>` tags.
    - People posting non-JavaScript/HTML code as code snippets.
  - Possible solutions:

    - [Make the tutorial/cheatsheet clearer and consolidate all help into one concise place.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295526/476) Currently there's an extremely terse, easy to misunderstand short help, and various verbose posts strewn across the help centre and Meta.
    - [Tweak the usability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254638/476) and [discoverability of the editor buttons.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374718/476)
    - Some form of [wizard UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/476) or WYSIWYG editor.
    - [Support the by now better known GitHub-flavored-Markdown with triple-backtick delimited code blocks.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288374/476)
    - Support all those common hacks and convert them automagically into proper Markdown.

Comment: Handle tabs: `:se et`, `:%retab!`

Comment: @iBug: What is that? [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)?

Comment: Re *"... GitHub-flavored-Markdown..."*: And we will get tables!(?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen right, I am a Vim user :)

Comment: I particularly like the idea of WYSIWYG editor. Somehow this idea has never occurred to me. It'll be cool to make it work similarly to Reddit's editor, where you can switch between markdown and WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Sweeper We already can see the rendered test below the question/answer when editing, so there is no need to switch between markdown and WYSIWYG.

Comment: @David There's a difference between having to figure out what syntax incantation you have to do and seeing a preview of the result, and a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @deceze Having a WYSIWYG editor doesn't help you to figure out the unknown systex ...

Comment: @David Right, because in a WYSIWYG editor, you highlight text and you click a button and that text turns into whatever that button promised to do. In the Markdown editor, you highlight text and you click a button, and now you have *more* text which you delete again in your confusion, or mess up while editing further, or misuse to begin with (`enter code here`). The difference between *direct manipulation* and *indirect conversion* can make or break it for some people.

Comment: I would personally _love_ to see the triple-backtick delimiter for code blocks implemented here. Having to indent all code by four spaces is a huge pain for me, so I can't imagine what it's like for a programming newbie.

Comment: @Adam Pressing Ctrl+K is not that much work, honestly.

Comment: _Pressing Ctrl+K is not that much work,_ Indeed. Especially __now that I learned__ about it. (And the other shortcuts) :-)

Comment: FWIW, there's a 4 year old meta post about [improving the make code sample button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254638/misunderstanding-how-the-make-code-sample-button-works) that has been thoroughly ignored all this time.

Comment: The mere suggestion of a WYSIWYG editor gets my downvote. Those things are always a nightmare to format with. They always get it wrong somehow and get in your way. So tired of software trying to shove them down my throat and making my life harder.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not a particular fan of WYSIWYG editors either, but they do solve such problems for _some_ people…

Comment: @deceze If someone can't be bothered to either skim the formatting help or figure out Markdown after their first two posts, they're not qualified to be on SO yet. They won't have the mindset or ability to write anything of quality. It is just not that hard. The one thing I do agree with is fenced code blocks. It's mind-boggling to me that SO doesn't support these yet.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not necessarily disagreeing with that; to some degree that's a quick first indicator for quality. But, there are _so_ many things and technologies to learn these days when you're a developer, having to learn yet another markup language (however simple it is) to be able to post here when your head is swimming with some problem you're stuck on anyways can arguably lead to some frustration. At the very least we [can improve the help and discoverability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295526/476) of *what you're supposed to do.*

Comment: +1 for “Markdown can be quite flabbergasting for newbies”. I remember the first time I encountered markdown; it seemed the text editor had gone insane; italicizing and underlining my code at random, nothing I did would fix it so I eventually gave up. I did not realize that “markdown” meant I had to learn an idiosyncratic symbol-based markup language with no preview or feedback. Calling it “markdown” is just pernicious; like adding a Save button that deletes your post.

Comment: @Sweeper Oh God no, Reddit's WYSIWYG has increased the number of formatting errors by probably 10x. Not just the obvious, but also bizarre things like italics being applied in the middle of words, etc.

Comment: @DourHighArch Question: you did not notice the preview below the editor…?

Comment: You could add [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475) to your possible solutions :-)

Comment: I might have a solution: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375361/1739000

Answer (score 16):

Well, when I was new to the site I also posted my first question as an image.
So, In my opinion, the reason *why* people post code as images when they are new because they *don't really* know how to put the whole code in question and when they see a text editor while posting the question then they think they have to type it all again! but they soon realise this is *highly impractical*. And *then* they think a screenshot would be good idea to post the whole code. So that's why..

**UPDATE**

So let me elaborate more *Why do people post code as images*?

- First of all, the question title should be "Why *new* users post code as images"? Of course, a experienced user would never do this.
- It is not *really* the case that new users like or prefer to post code as images they *simply* don't aware or didn't read "how to post good questions" before posting the question.
- And once they posted code as image, it is very likely that a community member will comment "Please don't post code as image and copy/paste the code and format it using `ctrl+k`.
- After this they will post code as code in their future questions and answers because they now know how site works.

**WHY I POSTED MY FIRST QUESTION AS IMAGE**?

- So, firstly I was in the same situation I described above.
- And after that, when I was writing my next question it was of about 5-6 lines of code so I decided to write directly in text editor of question area and don't formatted code(just wrote the code) because I was *really* not aware of formatting using `ctrl+k` or backticks.
- And after few minutes, the code was magically formatted! I was really surprised and have no clue how it happened and then I thought there may be a automatic system of code formatting on SO.
- But on the same day, I saw a question(unformatted code) in a user has commented "Please format your code using `ctrl+k`. So from where I came to know *how* code formatting works.And then I realised my code might be formatted by a community member.

**MY SUGGESTION**

Since In the text editor all the options to write question are clearly visible and If a new user carefully observe this and read help center before actually posting the question then he/she will certainly not post image instead of code.

So, In my opinion, On the "Ask a question page" slightly up before the "Title". We should include two little lines:

- You can copy/paste your code as it is here and no need to post image of your code.
- And you can then format your code using `ctrl+k` or backticks.

Because these are the two common mistakes new users generally do.
I am suggesting this because most people *don't really* read "How to format" and the help center before asking the question for the first time and they just post the question. And if those two lines would be just above the "Title" users will *definitely* read this.

**PS**: So I shared my personal experience and that was all and by these suggestions I didn't *really* mean that site already has not those features. And *if* a new user just read "How to ask" and maybe help center *carefully* then he would definitely post a good question even at first time.

But... As you know

*There is no solution of Human stupidity*

Comment: But why not simply copy/paste (ctrl+c then ctrl+v) it textually? That doesn’t entail typing it again. People copy and paste stuff all the time, so they know about that functionality, it’s not obscure.

Comment: @DanBron Yeah, it's not obscure but there is possibility that the poster has never been a member of a Q&A site so they don't really got the idea of copy/paste. I am *explicitly* talking about some people not all.

Comment: Huh? People use copy/paste all the time for almost everything in computers. It’s certainly not specific to Q&A sites! Especially if someone is coding, they must copy and paste code all the time! But even just eg writing a term paper in Word as an undergraduate, they use it. If someone is savvy enough to screenshot, they are surely savvy enough to be using copy/paste regularly. Did you not know about copy/paste when you were first here?

Comment: @DanBron I know about copy/paste when I was new here lol. But I just wrote what I think and *might* be new users.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. Can you maybe elaborate how you could have been helped on that first question so you didn't choose to post an image of code? Is there maybe a text we could put somewhere? Or is the fact that we have so many options? Should we maybe remove the option to insert an image for new users? Idea's are welcome that could prevent future users make that same mistake. If there is a flaw in how this site present its features we should try to fix that. Your insight could be valuable for that. Don't feel discouraged by the down votes here. On meta those are cast frivolous.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you specifically posted an image that first time, not what you think people might think?

Comment: @rene I updated my answer.

Comment: So, to clarify, you posted code as an image the first time because you had no expectation that you *could* in fact easily copy and paste code as text…?

Comment: @deceze Yes! Indeed or maybe thought of copy/paste just didn't come to my mind

Comment: @dave Sorry to keep pushing that point, but do you have a specific reason why you didn’t think code == text == can post?

Comment: @deceze No problem! But I never said I *didn't think code == text== can post* what I said is this thought just doesn't come into my mind first (I don't know why) or might be new users who posts images instead of code

Comment: @dave Hmm, interesting. Guess we all have our blackout moments, but this is particularly bizarre to me. Cheers anyways. 

Comment: I wonder if in other contexts of asking for help people use images.  But it seems to me this is a good situation to do user research and actually ask them.

Comment: We are the magic that auto format code. Sometime we also type code from picture.

Comment: While this is reasonable, I find it surprising that new users don't look at other questions and notice that everyone else is 'somehow' applying code formatting. Isn't it customary to take a quick peek around when you're joining a new site, just to see what people are up to? And after that, almost every post on SO contains a few code snippets which clearly don't look like pictures.

Comment: @Chair the fact that you and I are surprised is exactly why we need to be receptive for these signals and try to learn from them as most of us are blind for the obvious/trivial issues that apparently are keeping new users from participating effectively. And I agree with OP that there is no solution for human stupidity but we can try to prevent that new users fallback to common mistakes.

Comment: curious what you mean by "code must be formatted by a community member"...

Comment: @NH. Well, I mean the code was *surely* not formatted magically so there *might* be a community member who did this. So that was little typo ;)

Answer (score 13):

One more consideration, beginners will often share their code in unspecialized social networks, which vastly more often than not, do not support even the barest of formatting options, and pasting code often trims all leading spaces, causing them to get scolded.

Those users then eventually learn of SO, and their preconceived notion of free-form text boxes not supporting proper formatting is transferred, which leads them to post code as images.

Answer (score 5):

> Why *do* people post code as images?
>   What are some possible reasons why people post code as images?

One unfortunately reason, **sometimes** it seems code is posted as text to avoid search detection as it is from a test or an assignment (that is supposed to be done without on-line assistance) that the OP is attempting to conceal.

Usually tell tale signs include a sense of urgency, terseness in the question detail and a first (only) time user.

---

**What to do about such pictures of text posts**

If the question is poor, its can be closed/DV, etc.

If the question has some good, then request OP to post text or transcribe it oneself with various on-line image-to-text translators.

---

I VTC as being unclear, unless it contains something else of value.

Comment: *"transcribe it oneself"* - Please don't. Apart from encouraging lazyness, there is a pretty high risk for doing mistakes.

Comment: The issue of avoiding search detection could be mitigated by running the images through an OCR reader and embedding the meta information into a hidden but searchable portion of the question. Then followed by "Beware that any text contained in the screenshot will appear in public question searches such as google". That won't prevent people from uploading but at least prevent them from uploading with that intent.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be topping up the answer/question modal:

[image: Example]

#### Possible linked resources:

- Learn how to use Markdown: [*"How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?
- Markdown cheatsheet: [*"Markdown help"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

**It should not be limited to newly registered users:**

- After the user posts their first 2-3 questions/answers, it should no longer appear.
- If you have never posted a question or an answer, this modal should appear. (regardless of how long a user been registered here)