# Can we simplify the "add snippet" icon for adding Stack Snippets?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When asking someone to create a MVCE, in a comment, it's tough to know the right description of the snippet icon for them to click.

If you wanted to advise someone to format sample code you might say, highlight your code and click the `{}` icon. Because the icon looks like `{}`. However, asking someone to create a snippet is less obvious. You can ask them to click `<>`, but the icon is not just `<>`, the `<>` is tiny and wrapped inside an icon which looks like it's meant to represent a piece of paper with `<>` on it. Which puzzles me anyway, who writes code on paper? What is that supposed to signify?

Have a look at the comments on on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570497/how-do-i-integrate-toggle-with-form-errors?noredirect=1#comment92079925_52570497) - the OP comments `Yes the wrapped in paper thing was what threw me for a loop.`

**My suggestion/feature request:** The Stack Snippet icon is changed to simply `<>`. To mimic the functionality of the `{}` icon. That allows comments to clearly advise the OP how to make the question easier to understand, thus easier for the community to help.

Comment: Very apropos of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374706/476.

Comment: @deceze Actually yes, instead of seeing the `<>` on paper, perhaps users are seeing it as a screenshot. Either way, a change to it would help imho - `apropos` is my new favourite word!

Comment: I usually use "Click the seventh icon from the left"