# Is it ever ok to put an image of code in a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, images, code, downvote-reason

I have been staunch in my opinion of [Posting images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

I will 100% of the time either downvote the question or flag to be closed.

My question is, am I being too rigid?  We've given plenty of examples of when NOT to post images of code ...  Is there **ever** an acceptable time to post an image of an error, or an image of code?  I realize [The reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images) OPs might be tempted to, but I am still of the opinion that the system is the way it is for readability, searchability, achievability and overall ease of use.

Is there **ever** a acceptable usage for images of code / errors that would not require moderation to downvote or close a post?

Comment: There's probably an edge case if you are doing something like writing code that performs syntax highlighting on other code, where the appearance of displayed code is itself what is being worked on. IF it is showing the wrong colour or highlighting the wrong word, a picture could potentially help. But even in this case all code should be posted as code, with the picture being supplemental only, and the question remaining answerable even if the picture does not display.

Comment: Definitely _don't_ downvote or vote to close a question that contains an image of code _if the question also contains the code in text format_, either.

Comment: Or if the code in the image isn't the point of the image

Comment: IMO, images of code should only be posted for two reasons: 1) There is no other way to demonstrate an issue (such as a rendering problem or a tool question; and 2) If you write your code using a graphics editor (and yes, at least one of those languages exists - I can't recall the name of it, but it was pointed out to me once when I commented about the topic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) (Reasons to post images - exceptions to the rule - are, IMO, perfectly well covered by the FAQ answer.)

Comment: It's easier to use screenshots in instant-messaging applications. Some people use them often, and forget how to present code as text. Someone once asked me "which value should I put in this variable here?" (with a screenshot). I answered with a screenshot of several long-winded C enumerators. They didn't get it. I still think we should fight this uphill battle, but I can feel for those who gave up.

Comment: @KenWhite You mean languages like [scratch]?

Comment: @WeijunZhou: Yeah, that's probably the one that was mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sometimes it's irritating to get a post closed when you are asking a *completely different* question than the proposed "duplicate".  I even referenced said "duplicate" in my OP.  I understand "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors" -- The **question** is -- Is there ever an **exception** to that?  ...Which to my knowledge, through searching Meta, has never been asked.

Comment: "The question is -- Is there ever an exception to that? ...Which to my knowledge, through searching Meta, has never been asked." - just because you phrased it that way doesn't make it unique. If you **read the answer** given at the question you referenced, it answers your question - in boldface, even: "**Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.**" That sure sounds to me like it's directly addressing the issue of whether there is an exception!

Comment: @anatolyg things I didn't ever expect that I'd have to tell beginners, when I first started trying to explain programming concepts: "please actually use a computer".

Answer (score 23):

All IMO...

It can be useful if the question is about the meaning of certain icons or other visual aspects of code presentation in an IDE.

If the question is about the code itself, then it should always be present as text even if it's *also* present as a screenshot (e.g. to show debugger information). If there's nothing in the screenshot that isn't clear in the text itself, then the screenshot shouldn't be present.

Comment: I can appreciate this approach --  Whereas if I see that the OP has taken the effort to use SO's built-in formatting, AND decides to share a screen for clarification/highlighting .. I am just trying to be more objective recently, and the influx of low quality questions of late makes it hard to stay objective.